# Exceções consomem muito processamento. Verdade ou lenda?

Tags: c#, .net, desempenho, exceção, clr

Já vi programas assim :

```
if(!clienteExiste(1))
{
    return "Cliente não existe.";
}
```

e outros assim

```
if(!clienteExiste(1))
{
   throw new Exception("Cliente não existe.");
}
```

O segundo código vai consumir mais processamento?

Comment: Apenas para apimentar isso, olha o que o criador do C++ disse sobre exceções: "Exception specifications provide run-time enforcement of which exceptions a function is
allowed to throw. They were added at the energetic initiative of people from Sun Microsystems.
Exception specifications turned out to be worse than useless for improving readability,
reliability, and performance. They are deprecated (scheduled for future removal) in the
2011 standard."

Comment: Vale uma tradução para os não-leitores de inglês.

Comment: Se não por todo o processimento que o `Runtime` tem que realizar, a construção `try-catch` seria mais lenta simplesmente pela construção do objeto da exceção ;)

Comment: Exceções já estiveram mais em moda, veja que a linguagem Go, que é moderna e tem tido boa aceitação, não possui exceções.

Comment: @utluiz Isso refere-se a especificações de exceções, que não são o mesmo que exceções.

Comment: @luiscubal Verdade, a citação não fala sobre Exceções em geral, mas sobre um aspecto. O que eu quis destacar, é que o criador da linguagem mencionou um aspecto que impacta no desempenho. Então, pelo que entendo da frase, usar exceções especificadas pode gerar problemas de desempenho. Pena que o autor não se aprofunda no assunto. A citação foi retirada do livro "The C++ Programming Kanguage", 4ª edição. O autor é nada mais, nada menos, que Bjarne Stroustrup.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi Segue a tradução: "A especificação de exceções provê uma forma de reforçar em tempo de execução quais exceções uma função pode lançar.
Elas foram adicionadas numa iniciativa energética do pessoal da Sun Microsystems.
A especificação de exceções se mostrou pior que inútil para melhorar a legibilidade, a confiabilidade e o desempenho. 
Elas estão depreciadas (agendadas para remoção futura) no padrão de 2011." (Bjarne Stroustrup, sobre o padrão C++ de 98)

Comment: @utluiz Os problemas de desempenho são das especificações de exceções verificadas em tempo de execução, não das exceções em si.

Comment: Note-se que as especificações de exceções em tempo de execução não existem em C#.

Comment: @luiscubal Eu sei. O problema é que não dá pra editar o primeiro comentário. E mesmo que não sejam a mesma coisa o uso de um recurso é diretamente relacionado ao outro, não? Eu não tentei responder a pergunta. Foi apenas um comentário de algo que achei curioso, principalmente pelo fato de que a Sun tentou empurrar algo do Java para o C++.

Comment: @utluiz "uso de um recurso é diretamente relacionado ao outro" Sim, na medida em que não faz sentido ter especificações de exceções sem exceções (exceto talvez `nothrow`), mas faz sentido ter exceções sem especificações de exceções. Em C# os dois não estão relacionados porque um existe e o outro não. As críticas de desempenho e de robustez das especificações não são aplicáveis ao Java, só ao C++. Embora eu pessoalmente as deteste mesmo no Java.

Comment: No Android dão bem jeito para manter a aplicação sempre a funcionar, sem que apareça a mensagem: "a sua aplicação parou" que é muito mau para os utilizadores.

Comment: Negligenciar sua utilização indiscriminada tem consequências futuras. Projetos que abusam de usar a pilha para transitar com exceções por várias camadas trazem sérias consequência no desempenho. Em um momento de crise onde muitas exceções são lançadas ocorrem avalanches de erros que deixam o sistema sem recursos e assim mais exceções são lançadas. Uma bola de neve. Não recomendo como metodologia de programação. O correto é implementar os devidos tratamentos de erro e retornar ao chamador sem lançar exceções. Alterar um sistema que já implementa este tipo de uso é inviável, na maioria das vezes

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Sim.

O .NET usa um modelo de processamento em que o try/catch é uma operação "gratuita" quando não há exceções (o que é o cenário mais comum), e o processamento é movido para o `throw` (que fica mais lento como consequência).

No entanto, o `return` não é substituto para o `throw` porque têm [significados diferentes](https://web.archive.org/web/20160219222750/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/03/16/396787.aspx).

1. O `return` deve ser usado para resultados "normais" (embora possa significar erros, como no caso do `TryParse`: no caso em que os erros são tão comuns e esperados que faz sentido utilizar o `return`);
2. O `throw` deve ser usado para erros possíveis e recuperáveis, mas invulgares. Não deve ser usado para controlo de fluxo;
3. Para erros irrecuperáveis nem `return` nem `throw` devem ser usados (use [System.Environment.FailFast](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.failfast?view=net-6.0)).

Em particular, o `return` pura e simplesmente não é uma opção em construtores.

Para cenários invulgares, as exceções servem perfeitamente. Porque um `throw` não é lento: vários milhões de `throws` é que são.

Adicionalmente, estas recomendações aplicam-se ao C#, mas [não necessariamente a outras linguagens](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/112463/why-do-iterators-in-python-raise-an-exception).

Comment: +1 Em suma... O problema não é o `throw`, mas sim programação orientada a `try/catch`.

Comment: Faço minhas as palavras do @GabrielGartz e acrescento: usem exceções para casos excepcionais, de **erro**! Erros são coisas do tipo dados inválidos, problemas ao conectar a banco de dados, queda de conexão, sistema indisponível, etc. Parece óbvio, mas tem muito código por aí usando exceções para implementar regra de negócio. Aí vemos pérolas tipo `catch ClienteBloqueadoSPCException{}` `catch ClienteBloqueadoSerasaException{}` `catch ClienteDesempregadoException{}` ... não, não e não!

Comment: @NothingsImpossible Para adicionar a' lista de situacoes em que nao devem ser usadas excepcoes: validar input to utilizador.

Answer (score 31):

Sim, **o segundo código vai consumir mais processamento**.

## Situação excepcional

Mas quem se importa? Se realmente aconteceu algo excepcional, algo fora do fluxo normal do programa, este processamento extra, que nem é tão grande assim, dependendo com o que você analisa, não vai degradar a performance geral da aplicação. Pelo menos esse consumo será um problema muito pequeno perto do problema maior que você teve.

## Fluxo normal

Mas analisando o código mais friamente ele parece estar usando uma exceção para controlar fluxo do programa. Está manipulando regra de negócio. Aí pode ser que a exceção esteja consumindo uma quantidade de processamento que afete a performance geral, afinal a aplicação pode ter que lidar com milhares ou milhões de clientes que não existem. Você multiplica algo que era quase imperceptível por esta grandeza e a aplicação fica uma carroça.

Mas aí vem a questão: **porque usar uma exceção para determinar uma regra de negócio?** Isto não faz sentido. Isto não é realmente uma situação excepcional. Você tem apenas um dado inválido. Se você tem uma regra de negócio, suas estruturas devem saber se comunicar com esta regra de uma forma tradicional.

[**Uma exceção só deve ser usada para indicar falha no processamento e não invalidade do dado processado.**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101)

Não vou me aprofundar nisto já que respondi algumas vezes sobre o assunto. Leia mais em [melhor forma de lidar com exceções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101) e [É uma boa prática lançar exceção nesses casos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101) e [Diferenças entre Parse() vs TryParse()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) (bom exemplo de como construir uma API que comunique a invalidade do dado).

## Custo da exceção

Note que no .NET, principalmente na versão 2.0 ou posterior, **o custo da exceção foi todo transferido para o ato de lançar a exceção**. Não há custo significativo (não é zero) para "proteger" uma trecho de código com `try`.

Este é um **recurso tão complexo que é difícil medir sua performance**. Alguns já tentaram, como já foi apontado em outras respostas, e não conseguiram um resultado definitivo e confiável. Apenas dá para dizer em linhas gerais que o lançamento (`throw`) da exceção é bem lenta para o uso normal da aplicação.

Podemos quantificar bem **aproximadamente em alguns poucos microssegundos para executar o lançamento de uma exceção propriamente dito, em pilhas de chamadas curtas**, na maioria dos casos. O que é nada para uma situação de falha mas é muito para o fluxo normal. Claro que você pode ter outras perdas porque o seu uso pode dificultar otimizações, e até uma pior utilização do cache do processador e falhas de páginas em memória. Para dar uma comparação, uma exceção é mais rápida que um acesso ao SSD ou equivale à várias centenas de acessos à memória.

## Uso indevido

Em algum lugar, em algum momento, as pessoas começaram ser induzidas a pensar que você não pode **nunca** se comunicar através de estruturas de dados (que pode ser só uma *string*, um valor numérico como uma enumeração ou mesmo um valor booleano, e que só o uso da exceção é correto. **Isto não é verdade**. Se você precisa comunicar uma invalidade de um dado, uma violação de uma regra, um desvio qualquer, e esta comunicação exija informações mais complexas, crie uma estrutura que consiga guardar todas informações necessárias e entregue de alguma forma esta estrutura para quem precisa ser notificado disto, mas não use o mecanismo da exceção pelos motivos apresentados acima.

## Economia de `try-catch`

Se precisarmos resumir quais são as exceções pertinentes temos apenas **os erros de programação e as falhas de recursos que a aplicação não tem controle**.

Alguns [especialistas acham que as pessoas lançam exceções em demasia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/exception-cost-when-to-throw-and-when-not-to?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e as capturam em demasia também.

Muitas aplicações grandes, robustas sobrevivem bem com apenas um `try-catch` só para tratar os erros de programação. O uso do `using` que na prática é um `try-finally` já é mais necessário. Em alguns casos você pode ter que capturar e tratar uma exceção de forma mais específica, por exemplo um acesso ao banco de dados, mas mesmo nestes casos, dificilmente precisará de mais que um ou dois blocos `try-catch` se souber organizar a aplicação. Utilize métodos auxiliares para centralizar as criações e as manipulações de exceções relacionadas que aceitam a mesma ação ou possa definir ações através de parâmetros.

## E se eu tiver uma situação adequada para a exceção e preciso de performance?

Não use exceções. Eu realmente não consigo ver um caso real assim, mas se existir, você vai medir a situação real da sua aplicação, entenderá que precisa melhorar a performance, observará que o lançamento da exceção está consumindo boa parte deste processamento e vai procurar um meio de usar outra forma de comunicação da falha mesmo que a exceção fosse adequada naquela situação. **Nenhuma regra é tão dourada que não possa ser evitada quando é pertinente**.

[Relacionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: algo que você comentou faz todo sentido, qual a diferença de performance visto que todo um processo será parado por causa de uma excessão, acho que o problema de uma exceção para o cliente é pior que a performance.

Answer (score 20):

Esse assunto é complexo, mas para demonstrar qual caminho eu prefiro seguir, segue um trecho do código fonte do **EntityFramework**:

```
public DbRawSqlQuery<TElement> SqlQuery<TElement>(string sql, params object[] parameters)
{
    Check.NotEmpty(sql, "sql");
    Check.NotNull(parameters, "parameters");

    return
        new DbRawSqlQuery<TElement>(
            new InternalSqlNonSetQuery(_internalContext, typeof(TElement), sql, parameters));
}
```

Esse método usa duas chamadas estáticas de uma classe `Check` que faz o seguinte:

```
internal class Check
{
    public static T NotNull<T>(T value, string parameterName) where T : class
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(parameterName);
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static T? NotNull<T>(T? value, string parameterName) where T : struct
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(parameterName);
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static string NotEmpty(string value, string parameterName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(Strings.ArgumentIsNullOrWhitespace(parameterName));
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Veja como são tratadas simples verificações de parâmetros: com `Exceptions`. Na minha opinião usar `Excpetions` para desviar o código é fundamental, é questão de design e arquitetura, e quando se fala nesse assunto não se deve priorizar quem consome mais ou menos processamento. Se fosse assim, não teríamos linguagens de alto nível, estaríamos escrevendo código em *assembly*.

Devemos priorizar a escrita de código com bons padrões, pois se não fizermos isso, o ganho que parece levarmos em uma única chamada, como o caso dessa pergunta, será perdido com um código mal escrito que em pouco tempo poderá se tornar pesado e lento por razões que não teremos condições de descobrir.

Por último um pequeno [artigo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229009%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) em inglês que cita o seguinte:

> Do not use error codes because of concerns that exceptions might
>   affect performance negatively.
>
> Use design to mitigate performance issues.

Traduzido para:

> Não use códigos de erro por preocupações de que as exceções podem
>   afetar negativamente o desempenho.
>
> Utilize design para investigar problemas de desempenho.

No final o artigo descreve dois padrões para o melhor uso das `Exceptions`.

Comment: Boa! Prefiro um código legível e onde possa facilmente encontrar algum eventual problema do que um código eficientíssimo onde, quando ocorre algum erro, é praticamente impossível descobrir sua origem.

Answer (score 16):

Jon Skeet escreveu ["Exceptions and Performance in .NET"](https://www.developerfusion.com/article/5250/exceptions-and-performance-in-net/) (jan. 2006), atualizado em ["Exceções e desempenho Redux"](https://web.archive.org/web/20190119001938/http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/exceptions2.html) (graças @ Gulzar). Rico Mariani entrou na conversa com [The True Cost of .NET Exceptions -- Solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2006/09/25/771142.aspx).

A conclusão deles é que sim, pois é mais custoso lançar e tratar uma exceção do que puramente tratar o retorno e além disso pode haver perdas ocultas, como partes do contexto não guardado em cache, entre outras.

Answer (score 8):

O tempo "perdido" nas `Exceptions` é muito pequeno se comparado com legibilidade de código. Outros desenvolvedores devem olhar para o seu código e entender claramente que aquilo é um tratamento de erro. Mesmo assim, no .NET, `Exceptions` são gratuitas quando tudo ocorre certo, caso haja uma excepção o tempo perdido não fará diferença já que a execução irá parar de qualquer forma.

Use `if` para tomadas de decisão e `Exceptions` para tratamento de erros.