# Melhor maneira de lidar com Exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, exceção

Durante meus trabalhos eu aprendi uma forma de lidar com `Exceptions`, mas não sei se é muito boa. Aqui vai um exemplo do código:

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Foo();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + (ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.ToString() : String.Empty));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void Foo()
    {
        try
        {
            Bar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Erro no método Foo: " + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message + (ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.ToString() : String.Empty));
        }
    }

    public static void Bar()
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime? data = null;
            int x = data.Value.Day;//forçar uma exception de proposito
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Erro no método Bar:" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message + (ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.ToString() : String.Empty));
        }
    }


}
```

A minha ideia é mapear os erros e jogar a responsabilidade de seu tratamento para o método principal.

Para ser mais objetivo vou direto as perguntas:

1. Gostaria de saber a opnião de vocês. Existe uma forma [melhor | correta] de propagar e exibir as exceções de forma simples? Essa é uma boa forma de lidar com Exceptions?
2. Qual a importância de capturar `Exceptions` mais especificas, por exemplo: [DivideByZeroException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.dividebyzeroexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Achei um tutorial MUITO interessante!!! Aqui: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125470/Exception-Handling-for-C-Beginners

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A pergunta é ótima, mas vou tentar uma resposta que não seja baseada em opiniões, porque o foco do Stack Overflow não é a discussão.

## Existe uma forma [melhor | correta] de propagar e exibir as exceções de forma simples?

Depende da interface da sua aplicação. Por exemplo, em uma aplicação Web, a melhor maneira de lidar com uma exceção é escalando-a, exibindo avisos em tela com a mensagem informativa da exceção ou usando uma lógica que lide com o erro internamente, disparando alguma lógica adicional ou reportando o problema em log.

O que é **errado** é abafar a exceção, impedindo ela do seu comportamento normal, que é interromper a execução do fluxo normal do código para evitar problemas maiores no sistema.

No caso do seu código, se a intenção é registrar as exceções em *Console*, o código está certo e adota boas práticas. No caso, você está acumulando as mensagens das exceções, o que é correto, e exibindo em uma saída que não aparece para o usuário. Neste caso, apenas é importante devolver ao usuário uma mensagem legível e compreensível do problema ocorrido.

## Qual a importância de capturar Exceptions mais especificas, por exemplo: DivideByZeroException?

Uma determinada situação pode gerar erros diferentes, o que exige tratamentos diferentes. Para cada tratamento, a tipificação da exceção é uma boa prática para prover a cada situação de erro o tratamento adequado.

Answer (score 49):

<sub>Atenção, vou fazer algumas simplificações abaixo, o espaço não permite discorrer sobre tudo o que o tema pede. E principalmente vou usar muito as palavras "geralmente" e "provavelmente". Não existem verdades absolutas em desenvolvimento de software. Portanto cuidado com "boas práticas", principalmente se você é como a maioria das pessoas que se esquecem o que isso significa e começam tratar recomendações para grande parte dos casos como verdades absolutas para todos os casos. Boas práticas costumam fazer as pessoas pararem de pensar sobre os problemas, elas viram receita de bolo. Especialmente ocorre no tutorial do comentário na pergunta. Ele parece bom mas não é tanto assim. Na tentativa de simplificar a explicação ele prega coisas normalmente erradas. Talvez a pessoa que escreveu saiba disso, mas quem está lendo provavelmente não.</sub>

> Gostaria de saber a opinião de vocês. Existe uma forma [melhor | correta] de propagar e exibir as exceções de forma simples? Essa é uma boa forma de lidar com Exceptions?

Indo direto ao ponto, essa **NÃO** é uma forma boa de lidar com exceções.

Talvez o exemplo não seja o melhor para indicar sua intenção, mas só posso julgar pelo que você postou. Eu jamais faria um código desse em produção, ele tem alguns problemas:

1. Ele intercepta uma exceção muito genérica. A "boa prática" é só interceptar exceções mais específicas. O quanto elas devem ser específicas depende muito do caso. Mas provavelmente pegar a `Exception` é erro. Pegar a `Exception` pode ser útil em um nível alto do *call stack* (no `Main()` por exemplo).
2. Ele lança uma `Exception`. A classe `Exception` deveria ser abstrata (ok, eu sei que isso criaria alguma limitação não desejável em certos casos) para evitar alguém instanciar e lançar algo que efetivamente foi feito para ser uma abstração.
3. Ele destrói o *stack trace* e fica mais difícil achar informação útil, quando o objetivo parece ser oposto.
4. Ele não provê nenhuma melhoria semântica à exceção original, só coloca um vestidinho e um batom nela (e fica parecendo um travesti :) ). Particularmente não está especializando mais.
5. Ele manipula uma exceção sem saber o que fazer com ela.
6. Ele está deixando uma exceção ocorrer quando ela pode ser prevenida. Eu sei que é só um exemplo, mas estou fazendo a análise do que existe. Exemplos ruins fazem as pessoas entenderem as coisas erroneamente.

**Se você está usando um `throw` sem estar imediatamente seguido de um `;`, provavelmente está fazendo alguma coisa errada**. Preservar o *stack trace* é tão importante que o C# 6 agora tem *filtered exception* sem a qual o novo compilador, parte do compilador Roslyn, não poderia ter sido criado adequadamente.

```
try { … }
catch (MinhaException e) if (meufiltro(e)) {
    …
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/Filtered.cs).

**Capturar `Exception`, `ApplictionException`, `SystemException`, etc. são genéricas demais para conseguir fazer qualquer coisa útil**. São exceções que geralmente só devem ser capturadas como última ação antes da aplicação/*thread* quebrar. Quase sempre a ação executada será *logar* o estado antes do término. Note que tratamento de exceções em aplicações multi-*thread* são ainda mais complicadas. Existem diversas outras preocupações para manipular corretamente em uma ambiente de paralelismo que não vêm ao caso aqui.

**Sem saber com clareza o que fazer com uma exceção**, portanto sem ter uma solução real para o problema, **uma exceção não deve ser capturada**. Tenha em mente que 80% dos programadores erram no tratamento de exceções em 80% das vezes. Ok, os números são chutados, mas até programadores experientes erram porque não entendem profundamente do tópico que gerou a exceção (não só a exceção em si). Algumas pessoas diriam até que exceções são [vazamento de abstração](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction).

**Centralizar a captura das exceções**, especialmente em um nível alto da *call stack* que você tem conhecimento ou capacidade de manipular adequadamente é uma "boa prática". A escrita em *log* e eventualmente o aviso ao desenvolvedor/suporte da aplicação é a ação mais comum nestes casos. Quando se usa *threads*, existe um ponto central para cada *thread*.

**Quando você está criando exceções, pense duas vezes**. Elas são lentas quando lançadas e dificultam o trabalho de depuração de código. E muitas vezes os programadores não sabem bem quando realmente a situação é excepcional ou quando é apenas um fluxo alternativo ao programa. A situação piora quando se tenta escolher a especificidade e a semântica correta para a falha. Por isso, capturar e tentar melhorar exceções bem arquitetadas provavelmente resultará em derrota. Use a exceções existentes a não ser que você agregue algo realmente útil na sua própria exceção. Leia o código fonte do .NET para entender onde e quando lançar as exceções existentes.

**Prefira sempre que possível tratar a falha antes da exceção ocorrer**. Ter uma método `TryAlgumaCoisa()` evita o uso da exceção. Mas claro que nem sempre isso é possível. Não dá para usar esta técnica quando você precisa de mais do que "falhou/funcionou", quando há risco de [*race condition*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101), etc.

**Se *realmente* precisar interceptar uma exceção, tente lança-la de novo integralmente com `throw;`** e se ainda tiver que lançar a mesma exceção melhorada ou outra mais específica, use a versão do *overload* que permite preservar o *stack trace* (Ex.: `Exception(String, Exception)`). Se a exceção que você vai lançar não tem esse *overload*, fuja dela então, foi feita muito porcamente e não vale seu uso.

Se precisar "enfeitar" as mensagens da exceção antes de apresentar ao usuário, faça só quando estiver realmente manipulando a exceção. Varra o *stack trace* e outros membros da exceção e transforme as mensagens imediatamente antes da apresentação. Não faça o enfeite da mensagem antes, ao contrário do que mostra o exemplo.

**Cuidado com o que coloca nas mensagens das exceções**. Eu quase morro de dar risada com algumas aplicações web que só faltam incluir a senha do root para todo mundo ver.

*Logue* `ex.ToString()` e não `ex.Message`.

Alguns erros comuns seu exemplo não comete:

- O código não está engolindo a exceção por completo.
- Não coloca uma lógica muito complicada no `catch`, caso contrário você começa correr risco de ter uma exceção enquanto está manipulando outra exceção. Simplifique! Faça só o necessário.

Nem tudo deve estar em um `catch`, **o `finally` pode ser mais adequado** em algumas situações.

A maioria das exceções no tratamento de exceções (desculpe o trocadilho) vão ocorrer em situações onde você está criando um *framework* ou uma atividade com um nível de menor abstração. Nestes casos ou você sabe bem o que está fazendo, tem que saber, ou merecerá todo sofrimento que terá :)

Existe o evento `Application.ThreadException` que é uma rede de segurança para o caso de todas as tentativas de capturar um erro falharem. É um recurso bem limitado onde basicamente você só vai conseguir *logar* o estado atual. Não tente usar sem ter um profundo entendimento dos seus compromissos.

Compile seu exemplo e compile outro retirando toda manipulação de erros. Depois você me conta qual forneceu informação mais útil. Provavelmente você vai se surpreender. Compile com *debug*.

> Qual a importância de capturar Exceptions mais especificas, por exemplo: `DivideByZeroException`?

Já foi dito antes que quase sempre é melhor capturar exceções mais específicas. Você provavelmente terá melhores condições de manipular a exceção adequadamente.

Especialmente a `DivideByZeroException` não deve ser manipulada, pelo menos não em condições normais. Vou explicar melhor abaixo mas a razão básica que ela não deve ser capturada, salvo algum motivo que determine o contrário, é que ou não há como se recuperar desta falha ou ela pode ser prevenida antes da exceção ocorrer.

Se você pode fazer alguma coisa para salvar um cálculo depois de receber um `DivideByZeroException` então você sabe que o divisor será zero e não deve executar esse cálculo.

**[Exceções não devem ser usadas para controle de fluxo da aplicação ou determinar regras de negócios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101)**.

---

Eu gosto muito do [artigo do Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) sobre o assunto e vou fazer um resumo aqui.

| Tipo | O que fazer | Exemplo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fatal | Nada, a CLR saberá o que fazer melhor que você | OutOfMemoryException |
| Trapalhada | Conserte o bug que está causando isso | ArgumentNullException |
| Ruido | a) Conserte o software/framework mal arquitetado b) Troque de fornecedor de biblioteca mal arquitetada c) Aceite o prejuízo e trate como se fosse Estrangeira | Por sorte conheço nenhum exemplo |
| Estrangeira | Manipule da forma mais adequada possivel | FileNotFoundException |

Existem 2 grupos de exceções: as recuperáveis e as irrecuperáveis.

As **recuperáveis** se dividem em dois tipos. Uma claramente deve ser manipulada sempre que possível e a outra também, porém só se você não puder escapar dela.

O primeiro tipo é representado pelas exceções **estrangeiras** (exogenous). Elas ocorrem por falhas de recursos não gerenciados. São fruto de falhas em tentativa de acesso a recursos externos controlados pelo sistema operacional ou processos que servem sua aplicação. Erros produzidos pela *filesystem*, rede, banco de dados, servidor de aplicação, etc. Em geral você não só pode manipular adequadamente, como provavelmente deve. Provavelmente irá definir se vai retentar, se vai encerrar o recurso em uso, se vai avisar e perguntar o que fazer para o usuário, se vai tentar uma alternativa, enfim, a criatividade pode ser grande aqui. Capturar o mais próximo possível do ponto gerador da exceção costuma ser uma boa ideia, embora em alguns casos dá para generalizar ações.

O segundo tipo é a exceção que existe por **ruído** (vexing). É a exceção que não deveria existir. Existe porque foi mal arquitetada. Se ela foi criada por você ou sua equipe, dê um jeito de fornecer uma forma alternativa de tratar um acontecimento que não é excepcional. Se isso ocorre em uma biblioteca de terceiros, tente que o fornecedor lhe dê uma alternativa; ou pense em abandoná-lo. Além de não entender como exceções devem ser criadas, ele ainda é teimoso? Fuja dele. Não consegue? Bom, então faça o que a documentação manda ou descubra por conta própria o que fazer (ainda falta documentação? fuja mesmo). O próprio .NET já teve alguns exemplos de exceções criadas equivocadamente, mas hoje existem alternativas para evitar o seu uso.

O outro grupo, como o próprio nome diz, são **irrecuperáveis**. Já de cara entenda: não tente recuperar essas exceções! Erro comum de principiante, até dos principiantes com 10 anos de experiência.

O primeiro tipo são as falhas **fatais** ou de ambiente. Não há nada que você possa fazer nestes casos. Sinta-se com sorte se conseguir *logar* o erro, além de deixar a mensagem um pouco mais bonitinha ou palatável para o usuário.

O segundo tipo é onde as pessoas mais erram na manipulação, e deveria ser o mais fácil. São as **trapalhadas** (boneheaded). São erros de programação. É culpa de quem desenvolveu. Mas por alguma razão (talvez Freud explique) os programadores acham que podem e devem resolver o problema na execução (trocar o pneu com o carro andando). Muito raramente podem, mas mesmo quando podem, não devem tentar recuperar-se disso. A única forma de lidar com em erro de programação, é corrigi-lo. Claro que durante o programa você pode fazer alguma coisa e essa coisa é, no máximo, deixar a mensagem mais bonitinha, *logar* e alertar o desenvolvedor. A maneira de tratar essas exceções podem variar se está desenvolvendo ou em produção. Esse tipo de erro nunca deveria chegar em produção, mas chega. Fazer de conta que o erro não ocorreu ou tentar fazer algo para que o programa continue funcionando só pode trazer mais problemas. E o local para fazer isso é no Main() ou próximo dele. Dificilmente uma exceção deste tipo deve ser interceptada antes.

`DivideByZeroException` é um exemplo de erro de programação! E é incrível a quantidade de programadores que acham que não é. Há casos que você tentar verificar o divisor antes e depois fazer o cálculo pode causar uma *race condition*. Nestes casos, comece tudo de novo, você tem algum problema sério na arquitetura da sua aplicação.

---

Algumas linguagens mais modernas estão até usando mecanismos diferentes para tratar falhas. Elas provêm um mecanismo para dar uma saída personalizada e centralizada nos casos irrecuperáveis e outro mecanismo para tratar os casos recuperáveis de uma forma mais simples que um `try catch`. Curiosamente eu conheço uma linguagem bem antiga que já percebia que deveriam ter 2 mecanismos simples ao invés de *exceptions* :)

Veja também [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

Eu percebi que algumas pessoas não concordam com tudo aqui, talvez essas pessoas entendam de C# mais que o Eric Lippert.

Answer (score 14):

A respeito de Exceptions em .Net você precisa entender o seguinte:

**Try/Catch**

Try/Catch significa: Tente, e Trate. Se seu código não tem um tratamento específico para a exceção, não trate-o. Mas isso não significa que sua exceção não deva ser tratada por ninguém, apenas que o método atual (que pode estar numa pilha de chamadas de 10 níveis) só deve ter um try/catch se houver algum sentido para catch.

**Try/Finally**

Try/Finally
Try/Finally significa: Tente, e a final... Se você tem uma operação que precisa ser realizada mesmo que dê erro, use-o.

**IDisposable, Using e Try/Finally**

Quando você implementa IDisposable, você pode usar o **using** para a criação de seu objeto. O que as pessoas não sabem é que o Using é uma implementação de try/finally onde no Finally o método Dispose() é chamado.

**Criando suas próprias exceptions**

Caso você crie exceptions próprias, é recomendado que você segmente suas exceptions usando herança, criando um ramo de herança específico para exceções de negócio. Essa segmentação facilita na hora de tomar a decisão sobre o que deve ser feito com a exception. Por exemplo:

> Exceções de negócio são enviadas para o usuário em forma de um popup,
> ou simplesmente são logadas como Warning e não Error. Em
> contrapartida, as demais exceptions são tratadas como erro, e talvez
> mereça uma mensagem genérica para o usuário.

Crie no mínimo uma exception, que represente a exception de negócio. Use ao máximo as exceptions já contidas no .Net.

> **Atenção** Quando você começa a construir suas exceptions, você naturalmente e inconscientemente começa a olhar para toda reposta
> validação (negativa) como uma potencial exception específica. Na
> prática, não é necessário! Crie tantas exceptions forem necessárias
> para que facilitem o tratamento. Se uma exception específica não tem
> tratamento específico, ou você espera que alguém trate-a
> especificamente um dia (um consumidor qualquer de sua classe) ou você
> está criando exceções demais.
> É comum que tendam a criar exceptions duplicas com as exceptions do
> .Net, como ArgumentException, ArgumentNullException etc. Não
> cometa esse erro. Uma coisa é um programador chamar um método,
> passando um parâmetro inválido, outra coisa é você não poder "salvar
> um objeto" pois ele está em um estado (na visão de negócio) que não
> permita esse tipo de operação.

**Throw e Re-throw**

- Se você precisa lançar uma exception, o faça!
- Se você precisa lançar uma exception a partir de um catch de um try/catch, então coloque a exception original como innerException.
- Se você precisa tratar uma exception e relança-la, use `throw;`

A diferença entre no rethow:

**ERRADO**

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ...
    throw ex;
}
```

**CORRETO**

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ...
    throw;
}
```

A diferença é significativa e não está sujeita a interpretações. O primeiro exemplo, errado, gera uma mudança no StackTrace da exception, fazendo com que você perca a rastreabilidade da exception. No segundo exemplo o comportamento é relançar a mesma exception, da mesma forma que ela chegou até você.

**Tratamentos Globais**

Somente os pontos mais externos de sua API, serviço, etc, devem efetivamente tratar exceções **talvez** omitindo-as para o usuário/consumidor e sempre logando-as.

Soluções para tratamentos globais:

Já foi dito aqui em outra reposta, o tratamento para a thread atual, mas você pode tratar também no AppDomain. Usar aspectos (AOP) também é uma excelente alternativa. O tratamento para WCF precisa ser diferenciado, pois exceptions no WCF são causadoras de quebra de canal, portanto nesse cenário, suas exceptions precisam virar [faltas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942778.aspx).

Answer (score 11):

Complementando boas respostas, mas algo mais avançado abaixo.

O .Net fornece duas subclasses de Exception, pouco conhecidas: ApplicationException e SystemException.

O SystemException já é usado pelo framework para as exceções nativas, os programadores deveriam, principalmente quando usando o DDD, criar suas exceções e derivar do ApplicationException.

O porque é simples, você ganha mais granularidade, pode facilmente discernir se foi uma exceção gerado por usuário programador ou do sistema, escalonar o erro de uma camada de baixo nível para cima de forma controlada.

Capturar apenas Exception é uma técnica ruim, deve-se usá-la como failsafe, o ideal é capturar as exceções específicas e dar o tratamento correto. Um bom programador sabe quais exceções são atiradas do trecho de código protegido, senão nem saberá como tratar.

```
try
{
    // exception code
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) { // tratamento para arquivo não encontrado }
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex) { // tratamento para acesso incorreto de indice }
catch (CustomException ex) { // tratamento para exceção que eu criei }
catch (Exception ex) { // Algo inesperado ocorreu !!!!, log e analise }
```