# Qual exception devo lançar de acordo com cada situação?

Tags: php, exceção, design-pattern

No PHP, temos vários tipos de exceções que podem ser lançadas. Dentre elas:

`BadFunctionCallException`

`BadMethodCallException`

`DomainException`

`InvalidArgumentException`

`LengthException`

`LogicException`

`OutOfBoundsException`

`OutOfRangeException`

`OverflowException`

`RangeException`

`RuntimeException`

`UnderflowException`

`UnexpectedValueException`

A única que eu sei realmente ser diferente é a `ErrorException`, que permite lançar a exceção de acordo com os dados capturados por `set_error_handler`.

Porém, quanto as outras, as vezes me sinto um pouco confuso sobre qual usar.

Por exemplo:

```
function teste($int, array $array){

   if (! is_int($int)) {
     // lanço minha exceção aqui por que o número não é do tipo INT
   }

   array_push($array, $int);
   return $array;

}
```

- Eu deveria lançar qual exceção? `InvalidArgumentException`, `UnexpectedValueException` ou `BadFunctionCallException` ?
- Existe algum padrão definido (um PSR ou algo do tipo) onde explica quando devo usar cada uma delas?

Referência
[Manual do PHP: Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/spl.exceptions.php)

Comment: não entendi o -1 :(

Comment: Se o PHP permitisse *type hinting* com tipos primitivos, você nem precisaria se preocupar com isso `</rant>`. Mas dado o seu exemplo, acho que caberia usar `InvalidArgumentException `.

Comment: Agora vem a questão que formiga o cérebro: E quando devo usar `UnexpcetedValueException` e `BadFunctionCallException` ?

Comment: Estou tentando responder. Não sei se a intenção é ter descrição p/ todas, não sei se isto não deixaria a resposta muito longa, principalmente se levarmos em conta que a documentação é clara em todas elas.

Comment: É importante lembrar que as exceções seguem uma hierarquia: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/spl.exceptions.php#spl.exceptions.tree

Comment: Mas, como você sempre diz, a documentação é um lixo!

Comment: Ser um lixo não significa que ela deva ser ignorada.

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk, ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neste exemplo me parece claro que a exceção correta é `InvalidArgumentException`. A intenção desta exceção é justamente indicar que um [argumento do tipo errado foi passado para o parâmetro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101). A documentação existente no *link* fornecido na pergunta mostra isto.

A `UnexpectedValueException` é usado quando o mesmo problema ocorre no retorno de um tipo quando se chama uma função.

A `BadFunctionCallException` é usada para indicar que a função que o código está chamando não está disponível naquele momento. Como PHP é interpretado e totalmente dinâmico isto é possível.

É importante usar as exceções certas para documentar precisamente o que está acontecendo. Um programador que entende todas as nuances se beneficiará disto. Claro que para muitos programadores não faz muita diferença, ele não entende o erro mesmo que ele esteja claro e vai postar sua dúvida em algum *site* para alguém resolver para ele. Neste caso é ainda mais importante ter uma informação precisa para ajudar melhor quem nem conhece o sistema que ele está tentando resolver o problema.

Todas estas exceções possuem documentação e uma leitura cuidadosa indica onde cada uma deve ser usada.

Em alguns casos a exceção correta é aquela que você cria. Nem sempre deve-se usar uma exceção genérica da linguagem. Nem deve também criar exceções novas se uma existente cabe bem.

Não é fácil dizer objetivamente quando cabe cada uma, é uma questão de analisar a situação e usar o bom senso, a experiência, interpretar a documentação corretamente.

Existem poucas PSRs e até onde eu sei ainda não existe nenhuma. Não sei nem o quanto isto é efetivamente respeitado pela comunidade como algo relevante.

Exceção é um [assunto que me atrai muito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:101%20[exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o]) porque quase todo mundo abusa delas. Eu já escrevi [quando criar e usar exceções em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101). Eu sei que a cultura do PHP é diferente e algumas coisas ali não cabem para outras linguagens, mas acho que ajuda um pouco.

Comment: muito bom. Só gostaria de entender essa questão do _"...A função não está disponível naquele momento... O PHP é interpretado e totalmente dinâmico..."_. A função sempre não fica disponível independente do local onde ela é declarado (antes ou depois do chamamento da mesma, eu digo)?

Comment: Não, em uma linguagem como o PHP tem várias situações em que isto não é verdade. Ou porque falta algum arquivo do projeto ou porque um módulo do próprio PHP não está carregado. Não conheço todos os detalhes porque eu sou do tempo que PHP não tinha exceção :)

Comment: Acabei de fazer um teste. Se você definir uma função que está dentro de um arquivo incluído com `include` e chamar essa função antes desse `include`, ela será tida como não existente!

Comment: Sim, esta é uma situação bastante plausível, o interpretador ainda não a conhece.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme [esta explicação](http://rubsphp.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/exceptions-da-spl-standard-php-library.html), as exceptions derivadas de `LogicException` devem ser utilizados para notificar aos desenvolvedores sobre problemas de lógica na aplicação (por e-mail ou log).

As exceptions derivadas de `RuntimeException` devem ser capturadas para mostrar alguma mensagem apropriada para o usuário ou tentar contornar o problema de alguma forma.