# Quando usar Exceptions no PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, exceção

Cheguei em um módulo da apostila de OOP PHP sobre `Handling Exceptions`, eu pratiquei os exercicios e tal, mas ainda não estou bem certo dobre quando eu devo usa-las, e porquê. Eu dei uma pesquisada e achei este:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935490/why-and-how-would-you-use-exceptions-in-this-sample-php-code

e esse

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.php

a pergunta do S.O me pareceu mais esclarecedora, pois o doc do php fala mais de 'como usar' as Exceptions. A resposta que foi aceita pelo @Tower é explicativa, mas na pergunta ele descreve algumas situações de código onde ele queria saber se deveria ou não usar as exceptions, mas na resposta ele não usa nenhum dos códigos usados na pergunta. Tambem há a resposta do @rball, e lá ele da uma noção diferente das exceptions.
Gostaria de saber de vocês, quando devo usa-las, e se possivel, explicar cada situação proposta pela pergunta citada.

ps.: sei que há uma pergunta idêntica, mas a resposta foi traduzida da pergunta que eu citei ali em cima ^ , e como disse, a resposta que o @Tower aceitou não descreve a utilização das Exceptions nos códigos que ele deu de exemplo.

ps2.: ELI5 (Explain Like I'm Five / Me explica como se eu fosse uma criança de 5 anos)

Comment: [Qual exception devo lançar de acordo com cada situação?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50053/91), [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/91) e [Exceções devem ser usadas para controle de fluxo?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48410/91). Tem mais coisa na tag exceção ou exception

Comment: O que significa ELI5?

Comment: significa explicar de uma forma que até uma criança de 5 anos entenderia (não sei se o assunto permite)

Comment: Resposta sincera até demais: use quando não tiver absolutamente nenhum outro jeito de resolver o problema (o que é raro).

Comment: resposta curta e grossa. gostei. se colocar isso em uma resposta e um exemplo a questão é sua, Bacco ;)

Comment: @wdarking acho que não ia ficar legal, pois não ia ter exception :) - É complicado falar de uma coisa que muitas vezes é usado em PHP simplesmente pelo fato da pessoa ter vindo de outra linguagem e querer usar a mesma cultura. E infelizmente, no PHP isso acontece demais. Exceptions, MVC, OOP, e outros conceitos que quase sempre resultam em desastres no uso prático do dia-a-dia, quando o pessoal aplica no PHP porque alguém disse que era bom. Tem quem use "certo" isso em PHP, mas infelizmente são raras exceções. E a ironia desses casos é que geralmente são os que usam apenas o mínimo necessário.

Comment: PS: De qualquer forma, estou curioso para ler respostas que dêem exemplo(s) legítimo(s) de uso das exceções. Ainda pode sair alguma resposta boa, se alguém que entende bem da "alma" do PHP elaborar uma postagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu costumo usar sempre que um erro de input de dados acontece, ou quando é esperado que exista algo e este algo não existe, sempre que a tua lógica puder ser quebrada, então você gera uma exceção.

Mais importante que usar exceções, acho que é saber posicionar o bloco try-catch, que pode ser usado com diferentes níveis de catch e ou também um bloco try-catch dentro de outro através do encapsulamento de camadas que um pattern estrutural pode gerar.

Uma vantagem de usar blocos try-catch em diferentes camadas é o controle de erros que fica mais eficaz, evitando quebrar em camadas superiores da aplicação(Controllers), evitando erros fatais ou 500.

Alguns frameworks implementam `handlers` de erros e níveis de exceptions diferentes, todas extendem o mesmo objeto `Exception` e são capturados em níveis diferentes também.

Caso você não capture, o framework geralmente tenta identificar o tipo de exception e o código delas para também saber responder a requisição para o usuário.

Alguns tipos de exceção geram erros 500, 404, 401, entre outros.