# Qual é a diferença entre as "Exception" do PHP?

Tags: php, exceção

Tem várias **Exception** definidas no PHP, como `ErrorException` `PDOException` `Error` `ArithmeticError`, etc...

- Mas qual a finalidade de ter tantas exceções assim?
- Tem alguma diferença entre usar uma e outra?

Comment: A diferença principal é semântica. Se os programadores entendessem isso, já ajudaria. Exceção é o recurso da programação mais mal utilizado hoje em dia. A maioria não tem a menor noção de como uma exceção funciona mesmo. Sempre um show de horrores. Mas funciona, né, então parece estar certo.

Comment: Quando a pessoa entende de fato a diferença de lançar a exceção correta, a pessoa provavelmente entenderá a diferença de capturar a exceção correta e nunca mais fará um `catch (Exception ex) {`, a não ser no raro caso quando ela seja a correta.

Comment: Você pode me ajudar, dando pelo menos um dica de quando é correto? Até mesmo algo pra que eu leia ou algo do tipo, para eu entender direitinho, por favor. Obrigado!

Comment: Ô se eu posso, leia tudo, pode cansar, mas se terminar tudo e ainda fizer exceção errada, pode vender cachorro-quente na esquina :D http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a101%20[exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o]. Se ainda tiver dúvidas específicas não respondidas, pode abrir perguntas.

Comment: [Qual exception devo lançar de acordo com cada situação?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50053/91)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A finalidade é você poder capturar uma exceção específica.

Todas as Exceptions em PHP derivam da classe `Exception`.  Quando você captura  `Exception` você está capturando qualquer exceção que ocorra durante a execução do código.

Exemplo:

```
 try{

      throw new InvalidArgumentException('Teste');

  } catch (Exception $e) {
          echo $e->getMessage();
  }
```

Nesse caso, é vantajoso fazer assim se você realmente deseja capturar qualquer exceção que ocorra naquele trecho do `Try/catch`.

## Porque usar uma exceção específica?

Mas nem sempre é o caso. Muitas vezes, você precisa saber exatamente qual foi a exceção ocorrida para executar um determinado tratamento de erro.
Por exemplo, se uma função invoca uma exceção de erro de cálculo matemático e outra aponta que o argumento não é numérico, você pode querer apenas usar a exceção quer informa o erro do cálculo para informar um log ao usuário, ao passo que o erro do argumento você pode querer deixá-lo como erro fatal (pois no PHP, ao lançar uma exceção sem capturada, você gera um erro fatal).

## Capturando exceções específicas

Um ponto que devemos tocar é que as Exceptions são variadas pois os problemas são variados. Então, você utiliza uma Exception específica para cada problema.

Considere por exemplo uma função onde você tenha um argumento que deva ser um `array` e esse `array` deve ter 2 itens. Nesse caso, você terá que usar uma exceção para indicar que não é um array e outra, para indicar tamanho inválido.

Exemplo:

```
  function tem_que_ser_array_com_dois_itens($array) {
       if (! is_array($array)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('O argumento não é array');
       }

       if (count($array) !== 2) {
            throw new \LengthException("Tamanho do array é inválido. Deve ser apenas 2 itens');
       }
  }
```

Sendo assim, para trabalhar com as possíveis exceções lançadas por essa função, você pode especificar qual exceção deseja "capturar" no catch, caso não queria capturar qualquer uma.

Exemplo:

```
    try {

           tem_que_ser_um_array_com_dois_itens(1);
     } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
          $e->getMessage();
     }
```

No exemplo acima, apenas `InvalidArgumentException` é capturada, pois nós queremos tratar uma exceção apenas quadno o argumento não é válido. Caso o tamanho seja inválido, no exemplo acima, a exceção será convertida pelo PHP para um Fatal error, já que a mesma não foi "capturada/tratada".

Se você usasse `Exception` no `catch` acima, você capturaria qualquer exceção gerada pela função - Pois todas as classes de exceção deriva de `Exception`, nas versões do PHP anteriores à versão 7.

## Múltiplas capturas de exceções

Porém ainda assim esse comportamento pode não ser o desejado. Então, você poderá desejar tratar as exceções tanto de argumento inválido quanto de tamanho inválido. Como poderia resolver isso?

A solução é usar múltiplos `catch`. O PHP permite isso.

Exemplo:

```
 try {
       tem_que_ser_array_com_dois_itens([1]);
  } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {

       echo 'Por favor, coloque um array';
  } catch (LengthException $e) {
       echo 'Seu array tá com tamanho errado';
  }
```

Respondendo simplificadamente às suas perguntas:

> Mas qual a finalidade de ter tantas exceções assim?

Cada Exception representa uma exceção que pode ocorrer durante o código. Exceções podem ser tamanhos inválidos, tipos não esperados, erros de tempo de execução. Por isso é preciso que exista uma Exception específica para cada caso, pois se você usasse `throw new Exception` para tudo, você não saberia como tratar uma exceção específica e ia te dar muita dor de cabeça.

Além de usar as próprias exceções do PHP, é possível também você criar as suas próprias.

Exemplo:

```
   class InvalidImageExtension extends \InvalidArgumentException {}

   if (! in_array($extensao, ['png', 'jpg', 'bmp']) {
         throw new InvalidImageExtension('Extensão inválida');
   }
```

> Tem alguma diferença entre usar uma e outra?

Como eu disse é preciso uma Exception para identificar um problema específico. Ou seja, não ficaria organizado lançar a mesma exceção para tratar argumento inválido e para tratar um erro ao abrir um arquivo. Cada caso é um caso.

Exemplo que não seria legal:

```
try {

      if (is_array($array) {
           // Poderia ser UnexpectedValueException 
           // Ou InvalidArgumentException, se isso for argumento de uma função
           throw new Exception('Não é um array');
      }

      if (file_exists($file)) {
          // Poderia ser RunTimeException (erro no tempo de excecução)
          throw new Exception('Arquivo não existe');
      }
} catch (Exception $e) {

      // Se seu chefe pedir para você enviar um e-mail
      // Toda vez que não conseguir abrir um arquivo
      // Como você ia tratar isso? Fazendo IF?
     // Não seria melhor lançar e capturar uma exceção só para o arquivo não existente?

}
```

## Mostre qual Exceção sua função lança

Não sei se você costuma utilizar `PHPDocumentor`, mas é sempre bom reparar que algumas bibliotecas especificam as exceções que podem ser lançadas em seu código através dos comentários como `@throws`. Assim, se você desejar, poderá capturar a exceção específica, ao invés de tentar ficar adivinhando.

Exemplo:

```
 /**
 *
 * @param boolean $motor_ligado
 * @param string $modelo
 * @throws ProblemaNoMotorException
 * @throws VeiculoNaoVoadorException
 */
 function voar($motor_ligado = true, $modelo = 'aviao') 
 {
     if ($motor_ligado === false) {
          throw new ProblemaNoMotorException('Motor não está ligado');
     }

     if (! in_array($modelo, ['aviao', 'helicoptero']) {
        throw new VeiculoNaoVoadorException('Esse veículo não serve');
        // Ou UnexpectedValueException, por exemplo
     }
 }
```

## O que é rethrow?

Já vi esse termo sendo usado em alguns frameworks, o `rethrow`. Ou seja "lançar novamente". As vezes você quer fazer uma operação específica no `catch`, porém você ainda sim precisa do `Fatal Error` gerado por aquela exceção.

Nesse caso, você pode lançar a mesma exceção depois de capturá-la no `catch`.

Veja um exemplo útil onde eu preciso finalizar uma solicitação num webservice de um cliente. Se ocorrer um erro, além de lançar a exceção, eu preciso registrá-la num log.

Então eu posso capturá-la, registrar o log dela e lançá-la de novo:

```
 try {

    $db->finalizarNoWebserviceDoCliente();


 } catch (ServerException $e) {

    $db->logs()->registrarLog($e->getMessage());

    // Você lança a exceção novamente aqui
    throw $e;
 }
```

Comment: O exemplo é bom para mostrar o mecanismo, mas é bom deixar claro que capturar erro de programação e falar para o programador consertar o código não faz muito sentido em código real. Erro de programação não se captura em código real, só em exemplo mesmo.

Comment: @bigown eu ia comentar a questão do rethrow justamente por isso. Pois as vezes que eu precisei capturar uma exceção, ou foi para registrar um log pra eu resolver depois ou foi para enviar um e-mail e depois lançar a mesma exceção para o usuário

Comment: Bom trabalho, digno de +10 :D

Answer (score 2):

Sim, tem diferença. Quando você utiliza Exception em um try catch qualquer tipo de erro vai cair no catch. Caso você especifica outra como PDOException você está definindo um tipo de erro especifico à ser capturado pelo catch. Eu por exemplo utilizo o Laravel em desenvolvimento e quando quero capturar erros provenientes de querys eu utilizo:

```
try{
  //meu código
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

    return $e->getMessages();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tudo depende da `exception` que você quer agarrar.

Por EX:

```
try {
    $PDO = new PDO('...');
}
catch( PDOException $Exception ) {
    echo 'Conexão à base de dados não foi bem sucedida';
}
```

Aqui você quer agarrar somente esta exception, deixando as outras fazerem o throw natural delas, no catch você pode pôr até uma conexão 'Plano B' de outro tipo caso esta falhe. Repare que neste caso só lhe será util agarrar esta (`PDOException`)

Isto é útil para por exemplo dentro do `catch` mandar uma mensagem customizada consoante a excepção, ou fazer outra ação, até definir um novo caminho do seu programa consoante a excepção que quer apanhar num `try catch`.

Answer (score 0):

Eu recentemente tive uma experiência diferente, eu percebi que mesmo usando o try/catch com Exception estava estourando um fatal error na tela. Eu consegui resolver fazendo um outro catch para capturar o Throwable error.

```
    try{        
    } catch(\Throwable $e) {
        ...
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        ...
    }
```