# Erro ao adicionar elementos no Banco MySQL com PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou tendo o seguinte erro durante a inserção no banco de dados:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '(' in /var/www/public/Test/db/add-banco.php on line 18

A linha 18 é: `} catch {`

```
<?php 
$host = "localhost"; 
$dbname = "scotchbox";
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";

try {
    // Abre a conexão com o DB
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host = $host; dbname = $dbname", $user, $pass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    // Faz a operação de INSERT no DB
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, idade) VALUES (:nome, :idade)");
    $stmt = bindParam(":nome", $_POST["nome"]);
    $stmt = bindParam(":idade", $_POST["idade"]);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "Valores inseridos com sucesso!";
} catch {
    echo "ERRO: " . $e->getMessage(); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Onde e a linha 18?

Comment: tenho um erro nesse código aqui `$stmt = bindParam(":nome", $_POST["nome"]);` e `$stmt = bindParam(":idade", $_POST["idade"]);` teriam que ser assim: `$stmt->bindParam(":nome", $_POST["nome"]);` e `$stmt->bindParam(":idade", $_POST["idade"]);`, ou seja, não é igual é o acesso a método da classe, atenção.

Comment: Linha 18: 
    } catch {

Answer (score 2):

Tem um pequeno de sintaxe:

deve ser assim:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, idade) VALUES (:nome, :idade)");
$stmt->bindParam(":nome", $_POST["nome"]);
$stmt->bindParam(":idade", $_POST["idade"]);
$stmt->execute();
```

E na linha do `catch` ponha:

```
...catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "ERRO: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Neste caso imprimimos qualquer excepção que aconteça

Comment: FUNCIONOU!!! VLW!

Comment: De nada @GiovanniCruz

Answer (score 0):

No código faltou especificar qual exception capturar, no caso a PDOException. Prefira capturar a exceção mais especifica para saber onde o código falhou e ter os detalhes necessários, ao deixar a mais genérica `Exception`, qualquer uma lançada desviara o fluxo para o `catch` que nesse caso funciona como um ralo ou seja qualquer coisa pode escoar nele.

mude:

```
} catch {
```

Para:

```
} catch(PDOException $e) {
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Qual exception devo lançar de acordo com cada situação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50053/91)

[Qual é a diferença entre as “Exception” do PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130307/91)