# NullPointerException ocorrendo

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, exceção, nullpointerexception

Meu professor utiliza a tecnologia de `EasyAccept` como validação de erros. Em um dos testes é necessário o uso de `Exception`. No código abaixo, eu consegui tratar de uma forma que EU ACHO ser adequada, mas ele persiste em um mesmo erro.

```java
package maisPop;

import java.util.List;

import easyaccept.EasyAccept;
import usuariosExceptions.EntradaException;

public class Facade {

    private List<Usuario> usuarios;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        args = new String[] {
                "maisPop.Facade",
                "resources/Scripts de Teste/usecase_1.txt"};
        EasyAccept.main(args);
    }

    public void iniciaSistema() {
        //iniciar sistema
    }

    public void cadastraUsuario(String nome, String email, String senha, String dataNasc, String imagem) throws Exception{
        Usuario novoUsuario = new Usuario(nome, email, senha, dataNasc, imagem);
        if (getUsuarios().contains(novoUsuario))
            throw new EntradaException("Usuario ja esta cadastrado no +Pop.");
        usuarios.add(novoUsuario);
    }

    public void cadastraUsuario(String nome, String email, String senha, String dataNasc) throws Exception{
        Usuario novoUsuario = new Usuario(nome, email, senha, dataNasc, "resources/default.png");
        if (getUsuarios().contains(novoUsuario))
            throw new EntradaException("Usuario ja esta cadastrado no +Pop.");
        usuarios.add(novoUsuario);
    }

    public List<Usuario> getUsuarios() {
        return usuarios;
    }
}
```

A seguir a uma outra classe que irá realizar o cadastro de usuários.

```java
package maisPop;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

import usuariosExceptions.AtualizaPerfilException;

public class Usuario {

    private String email, senha, nome;
    private Date dataNasc;
    private String imagem;

    public Usuario(String email, String senha, String nome, String dataNasc, String imagem) throws Exception {
        setEmail(email);
        setSenha(senha);
        setNome(nome);
        this.dataNasc = UtilUsuario.formataData(dataNasc);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail (String email) throws AtualizaPerfilException {
        if (email.equals("") || email == null){
            throw new AtualizaPerfilException("Email nao pode ser nulo ou vazio.");
        }else if (UtilUsuario.validaEmail(email) == false){
            throw new AtualizaPerfilException("Erro na atualizacao de perfil. Formato de e-mail esta invalido.");
        }
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }
    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) throws AtualizaPerfilException {
        if (nome == null || nome.equals(""))
            throw new AtualizaPerfilException(
                    "Erro na atualizacao de perfil. Nome dx usuarix nao pode ser vazio.");
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Date getDataNasc() {
        return dataNasc;
    }

    public void setDataNasc(String novaDataNasc) throws AtualizaPerfilException, ParseException{
        if (UtilUsuario.validaDiaDaData(novaDataNasc) == true
                || UtilUsuario.validaIntervalosDeData(novaDataNasc) == false)
            throw new AtualizaPerfilException(
                    "Erro na atualizacao de perfil. Formato de data esta invalida.");
        if (UtilUsuario.isDateValid(novaDataNasc) == false)
            throw new AtualizaPerfilException(
                    "Erro na atualizacao de perfil. Data nao existe.");
        this.dataNasc = UtilUsuario.formataData(novaDataNasc);
    }

    public String getImagem() {
        return imagem;
    }
    public void setImagem(String imagem) throws AtualizaPerfilException {
        if (nome == null || nome.equals(""))
            throw new AtualizaPerfilException("Imagem nao pode ser nula ou vazia.");
        this.imagem = imagem;
    }
}
```

E também essa classe `UtilUsuario` que realiza as validações para o tratamento do `Exception`:

```java
package maisPop;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import usuariosExceptions.ErroCadastroException;

public class UtilUsuario {

    public UtilUsuario() {

    }

    ArrayList<String> listaDePossiveisEmails = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void validaDataCompleta(String dataNasc) throws ErroCadastroException {
        if (dataNasc == null || dataNasc.equals("")
                || validaIntervalosDeData(dataNasc) == false)
            throw new ErroCadastroException(
                    "Erro no cadastro de Usuarios. Data nao existe.");
    }

    public static void validaDia(String dataNasc) throws ErroCadastroException {
        if (validaDiaDaData(dataNasc) == true)
            throw new ErroCadastroException(
                    "Erro no cadastro de Usuarios. Formato de data esta invalida.");
    }

    public static void validaSenha(String senha) throws ErroCadastroException {
        if (senha == null || senha.equals("") || senha.length() < 3)
            throw new ErroCadastroException(
                    "A senha nao pode ser nula, vazia ou menor que 3 caracteres.");
    }

    public static void validaEmailUsuario(String email) throws ErroCadastroException {
        if (email == null || email.equals("") || validaEmail(email) == false)
            throw new ErroCadastroException(
                    "Erro no cadastro de Usuarios. Formato de e-mail esta invalido.");
    }

    public static void validaNome(String nome) throws ErroCadastroException {
        if (nome == null || nome.equals("") || nome.trim().equals(""))
            throw new ErroCadastroException(
                    "Erro no cadastro de Usuarios. Nome dx usuarix nao pode ser vazio.");
    }

    public static boolean validaIntervalosDeData(String data) {
        String[] valores = data.split("/");

        if (!data.matches("([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})")
                || Integer.parseInt(valores[0]) < 1
                || Integer.parseInt(valores[0]) > 31)
            return false;
        if (!data.matches("([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})")
                || Integer.parseInt(valores[1]) < 1
                || Integer.parseInt(valores[1]) > 12)
            return false;
        if (!data.matches("([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})")
                || Integer.parseInt(valores[2]) < 1)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean validaDiaDaData(String data) {
        String[] dia = data.split("/");
        if (dia[0].length() > 2)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean validaEmail(String email) {
        return true;
    }

    public static Date formataData(String data) throws ParseException {
        if (data == null || data.equals(""))
            return null;

        Date date = null;
        try {
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            date = (java.util.Date) formatter.parse(data);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return date;
    }

    public static boolean isDateValid(String strDate) {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        formatter.setLenient(false);
        try {
            Date date = formatter.parse(strDate);
            return true;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Todos os Exceptions estão corretos, a mensagem que ele retorna é:

```
   At line 15: Expected <Erro no cadastro de Usuarios. Nome dx usuarix nao pode ser vazio.>, but no error occurred.
   At line 16: Expected <Erro no cadastro de Usuarios. Nome dx usuarix nao pode ser vazio.>, but no error occurred.
   At line 17: Expected <Erro no cadastro de Usuarios. Formato de e-mail esta invalido.>, but no error occurred.
   At line 18: Expected <Erro no cadastro de Usuarios. Formato de data esta invalida.>, but no error occurred.
   At line 19: Expected <Erro no cadastro de Usuarios. Data nao existe.>, but no error occurred.
```

Só que todos esses erros já estão tratados como podem ver acima. Mas o problema insiste em continuar.

Segue abaixo as linhas do .txt referentes aos erros acima:

```
15. expectError "Erro no cadastro de Usuarios. Nome dx usuarix nao pode ser vazio." cadastraUsuario nome="" email="alguem@email.com.br" senha="senha_besta" dataNasc="10/10/2010"
16. expectError "Erro no cadastro de Usuarios. Nome dx usuarix nao pode ser vazio."  cadastraUsuario nome="  " email="alguem@email.com.br" senha="senha_besta" dataNasc="10/10/2010"
17. expectError "Erro no cadastro de Usuarios. Formato de e-mail esta invalido."  cadastraUsuario nome="Fulaninho" email="alguem@email" senha="senha_besta" dataNasc="10/10/2010"
18. expectError "Erro no cadastro de Usuarios. Formato de data esta invalida."  cadastraUsuario nome="Fulaninho" email="alguem@email.com" senha="senha_besta" dataNasc="1510/10/2010"
19. expectError "Erro no cadastro de Usuarios. Data nao existe."  cadastraUsuario nome="Fulaninho" email="alguem@email.com" senha="senha_besta" dataNasc="32/10/2010"
```

Comment: Não entendi bem qual é o problema. Você diz que os erros estão tratados. Onde? Não vi tratamento algum para eles. Tem vários erros no código que independem do que você está falando e deveriam, ou pelo menos, poderiam ser melhorados. Um deles vai gerar um `NullPointerException`. Esse é o problema? Tem alguns problemas conceituais, mas o principal eu duvido que seu professor considere um erro. Não gostei da ideia de um curso ficar usando bibliotecas deste tipo.

Comment: Oh meu jovem, é esse problema mesmo. Quando eu trato no Exception para ele retornar sempre true independente da validação, ele da erro de NullPointerException, você poderia me explicar como tratar esse problema de NullPointerException? Esta em qual linha de comando?
Grato desde já!

Comment: Você pode simplificar `Date date = null;
        try {
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            date = (java.util.Date) formatter.parse(data);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return date;` de forma a ficar apenas `return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(data);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Erro de `NullPointerException` não deve ser tratado, ele deve ser resolvido, afinal é um erro de programação. Na verdade boa parte das exceções não devem ser tratadas.

Dentro do `setEmail()` há uma linha:

```
if (email.equals("") || email == null) {
```

Mude ela para:

```
if (email == null || email.equals("")) {
```

No original quando o `email` é `null` ele gera esta exceção tentando acessar `equals("")`, afinal não pode acessar método algum em algo que vale `null`. Nos outros lugares parece estar tudo certo, compara na ordem certa.

A comparação do `null` antes é justamente para não deixar ele tentar fazer uma operação ilegal, já que os operadores relacionais são *short-circuit*, ou seja, eles só avaliam o outro operando quando ele ainda não pode garantir qual será o resultado. No caso  se o primeiro operando valer `true`, não tem porque executar o segundo operando, afinal basta um `true` para todo o `||` valer `true`.

Não sei se tem outros problemas. A pergunta não é muito informativa. Pode ter outros lugares que precise proteger contra `null` e não tenha sido feito. A expressão `dia[0].length()` potencialmente pode dar outro tipo de erro e não foi tratada ou resolvida.

Mas se tiver alguma exceção que deva ser tratada no código, eu não posso ajudar muito porque o código não trata nenhuma delas. Lançar exceção não é o mesmo que tratar exceção. Muito pelo contrário.

Há várias coisas que poderiam ter sido feitas de um jeito melhor. Mas a maior delas é que [exceções não deveriam ser usadas para validar dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101). Nem todo mundo concorda com isto, em Java a cultura é fazer isto, mas é um [abuso do recurso, é espúrio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101). Tem meios melhores de fazer isto.

Se uma expressão pode resultar em `true` ou `false` nunca compare ela com esses valores. Simplifique (a linha de baixo é a simplificada):

```
if (validaDiaDaData(dataNasc) == true)
if (validaDiaDaData(dataNasc)) //melhor assim

if (dataNasc == null || dataNasc.equals("")
        || !validaIntervalosDeData(dataNasc))
```

O mesmo vale para qualquer coisa que espera um valor booliano:

```
String[] dia = data.split("/");
if (dia[0].length() > 2)
    return true;
return false;
```

Fica melhor assim:

```
String[] dia = data.split("/");
return dia[0].length() > 2;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/NullPointerExceptionFix.java).

Fazer um `try-catch` para dar um `throw e;` é um desperdício e causa perda de informação sobre a exceção. Se você não sabe como resolver a exceção, não capture ela.

Capturar uma exceção para retornar `true` ou `false` não é de todo mal, mas tem que saber bem porque está fazendo. Não pode ser uma solução por acidente. Digo que não é de todo mal porque justamente está trocando uma exceção por uma valor normal para tratar a validação. Isto é o jeito coreto. Você está corrigindo um erro que a API do Java cometeu. [Neste caso parece que fez certo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

[Leitura adicional importante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/101).