# Qual a melhor forma de ler um retorno de erro do sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, webforms, exceção, return

Qual a melhor forma de ler um retorno de erro do *sql server* em uma aplicação C# web form?

Tenho o seguinte..

No sql server;

```
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    Raiserror('Erro ao gerar os dados', 18, 1);
      return;
END CATCH;
```

No c#

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "minhapro";
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", rdpDtMedicao.SelectedDate.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Filial", Filial);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", cfg.UserID);
cmd.CommandTimeout = 1800;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
try
{
    conn.Open();
    var teste =  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

já vi que o *ExecuteNonQuery* retorna um *int* , mas quero que seja meu erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está escondendo o seu erro fazendo isso

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

**Não faça isso**. Esconder as exceptions **nunca** é uma boa ideia. Provavelmente só tirar esse bloco `catch` já irá te ajudar bastante.

É muito comum pensar que a "programação orientada a `try-catch`" é uma boa opção, mas na verdade as *exceptions* só devem ser capturadas em casos específicos, quando tu souber o que (e como) fazer depois de capturá-las.

Outra coisa importante, esse código

```
BEGIN CATCH
    Raiserror('Erro ao gerar os dados', 18, 1);
    return;
END CATCH;
```

também não faz nada de muito útil. Você está escondendo o erro real e colocando uma "mensagem bonita". Isso não é o ideal.

Imagine que essa `procedure/function` dê erro no ambiente no produção, o erro que o aplicativo irá receber será `Erro ao gerar os dados`, quando na verdade ele deveria estar lhe informando onde e porquê o erro estourou.

Sobre o seu comentário

> no caso do erro Raiserror('Erro ao gerar os dados', 18, 1); ... isso será mostrado para o usuário quando ele for gerar os dados de um demostrativo em TextBox. não quero explodir uma msg de erro que o cara nem vai sabe o que é.

*Exceptions* não servem para informar alguma coisa para o usuário final. Elas servem para mostrar para o desenvolvedor que algo está errado. Primeiramente não faz diferença se o usuário souber ou não o que a mensagem de erro está dizendo, ela vai continuar sendo uma mensagem de erro e ele não irá conseguir fazer nada sem a ajuda de um suporte ou do desenvolvedor. Outro ponto importante é que se alguma *exception* está sendo lançada é porque há algum erro no código e primeira coisa que você vai querer fazer quando encontrar um erro é consertá-lo, não é?

Eu consigo entender a sua intenção em não assustar o usuário com mensagens de erro gigantes e com código no meio. O mais indicado é você capturar as *exceptions* genéricas no camada "mais de cima" da sua aplicação, algo como, a tela principal, o ponto de entrada ou algo semelhante.

---

Dê uma olhada em [Melhor maneira de lidar com Exceptions](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13303/18246). Ali tem boas respostas sobre este assunto.

Comment: no caso do erro Raiserror('Erro ao gerar os dados', 18, 1); ... isso será mostrado para o usuário quando ele for gerar os dados de um demostrativo em TextBox. não quero explodir uma msg de erro que o cara nem vai sabe o que é.

Comment: Você está confundindo. Esse tipo de informação não serve para o usuário, elas servem para você. Eu vou editar minha resposta para explicar um pouco melhor.

Comment: entendi, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Pronto @MarconcilioSouza =) Se ficar alguma dúvida, me avise

Answer (score 1):

Crie um parâmetro para receber o retorno de seu SQL e adicione aos parâmetros do cmd, algo tipo:

```
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@Nome", DbType.String);
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 

cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
```

E aí no seu código SQL você define o retorno desejado nessa variável. Após o ExecuteNonQuery você apenas pega de volta o conteúdo da variável.