# Usar um catch vazio é uma prática ruim?

Tags: exceção, estilo-de-codificação

Já houve casos onde eu precisei fazer uso de métodos que lançavam exceção caso algum erro ocorresse, porém a exceção iria parar a execução do *script*, o que seria algo indesejado.

Por exemplo, tenho um sistema onde, quando o aluno cadastra a solicitação, é enviado um e-mail. A função que envia o e-mail lança a exceção. Porém, como a exceção pararia o cadastro, eu preferi usar um `catch` vazio. Não era tão importante enviar o e-mail quanto que a solicitação fosse cadastrada.

Então, fiz algo parecido com isso:

```php
try {

    Mail::create('email.aluno')->send($callback);

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Se não enviar o e-mail por conta de um erro
    // continue o script
    // Não vamos interromper esse momento tão importante
}

$usuario->fill($dados)->save();
```

Alguém poderia dizer: é só tirar a exceção de onde ela é lançada. Eu não faço isso, pois alterar o código fonte de terceiro não é uma boa ideia, pois quando fosse atualizar o sistema, teria que editar de novo, e de novo e de novo...

É uma prática ruim utilizar um `catch` vazio para nada acontecer quando ocorre a exceção?

Isso seria um anti-padrão?

Existe um nome específico para esse tipo de operação?

Existe riscos em fazer tal operação?

Comment: Acho que esta resposta mostra que é uma pratica ruim em deixar o catch vazio :) : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23787/27190

Comment: feio pra caramba.....vc pode resolver isso com um if em vez de usar o try.
e um sistema que nao trata excecoes, já é algo ruim, catch vazio entao...

Comment: @RBoschini mas com o if, como você ia "parar" o lançamento da exceção?

Comment: exceções são previsiveis, eu faria os testes, identificaria as exceções e trataria com IF se necessario, nunca com um try vaziu.

Comment: Eu acho complicada a pergunta sem especificar a linguagem. Por exemplo, em Java, grosseiramente falando, tudo é exceção. Em PHP, quase (praticamente) tudo se resolve sem usar exceção. E, como o nome diz, exceção deveria ser tratado como exceção (mas em Java, faça uma exceção ao que eu disse). :)

Comment: Um bug programatico tem que ser previsivel, se vc nao entendo pq a exceção é lancada ou quando ocorre, é pq vc nao fez os testes necessarios para identificar, vc usa o try para se passar algo vc conseguir tratar de forma certa sem estourar na cara do usuario.

Comment: @RBoschini talvez então eu possa pegar a exceção específica e ignorá-la ou outra não ignorar. Por exemplo, a questão do `catch` multiplo.

Comment: catch multiplo esta OK, catch vaziu que não, na minha opinião.
ignorar uma exceção eu vejo como evitar que ela ocorra, nunca ignorar excecao, me de um exemplo de excecoes que vc poderia ignorar.

Comment: Caso o try::catch for obrigatório, você gostaria de algo "fault-tolerant" é isso? Mas entendo que nesse caso só quer saber do catch vazio. É complicado porque o catch pode apenas estar cobrindo um problema de outro lugar. No seu caso poderia ter um verificador para saber se o email de fato foi enviado, caso não tenha sido, poderia ter uma outra thread para tentar um novo reenvio, enquanto isso, o cadastro continua.

Comment: Podemos encarar isso também de maneira inversa. Se você sente como se o catch vazio fosse satisfatório, talvez a exceção específica a ser discutida não deveria nem estar sendo lançada. Não tratar a exceção pode ser um mal sinal de você não entender a exceção ou pode ser um mal sinal de uma exceção errônea sendo lançada. Acho difícil um catch vazio sendo aceitável.

Comment: Eu diria que é uma péssima prática.

Comment: Se tu ta fazendo um `try{}catch(){}`, porque tu não trata? ou ao menos gera um log, para correção futura.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu a exceção vem da biblioteca de terceiro. Não fui eu quem a defini nesse caso.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert daqui a pouco alguém vai dizer: "É melhor sair da profissão",rsrsrsrs.

Comment: @Wallace Maxters desculpa a curiosidade, mas oq faz essa lib que da exceção e qual a exceção que ela estoura? por curiosidade mesmo

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu conheço isso como pattern silenciator, ele tem boa serventia para esconder possiveis falhas .... porém é otimo para que voce demore horas para descobrir os problemas.... sim muito ruim usar

Comment: @RBoschini é o seguinte. Nessa parte do sistema, eu posso enviar um e-mail para o aluno quando suas fotos são aprovadas. O problema é que eu não posso deixar de aprovar essas fotos só porque o e-mail não foi enviado,então por isso usei o catch vazio. Hoje, é claro que eu teria outras formas de resolver isso, já que tenho tempo agora para pensar em algo melhor.Mas o problema é que nesse sistema a aprovação das imagens e o envio do e-mail ocorrem juntos. Como estava dando pau no e-mail de vez enquanto (servidores brasileiros!), tive que botar esse `catch`. A exceção vem do código de terceiro.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

É. Péssimo :)

Primeiro precisaria ver se aquilo realmente é necessário lançar a exceção. Vejo muitos casos onde a exceção não é o mais adequado (ver mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101)).

Talvez seja um caso de exceção vexatória/ruidosa (ver o *link* aí em cima). Talvez seja uma exceção estrangeira, o que aí seria normal.

Se está tudo normal com o lançamento então tem que perguntar-se porque não fazer nada. Esta é a ação esperada? Não vai avisar, não vai *logar*, não vai tomar um rumo diferente, escolher uma alternativa, nada assim? Vai fazer de conta que nada aconteceu?

Se considerou tudo isto e tem certeza que fazer nada é o certo então está tudo ok. Como tudo, regras fixas valem nada, tem que fazer o que é certo naquele caso.

É difícil dizer que exista um caso onde engolir a exceção sem fazer algo seja o certo, mas pode existir. Quando isso é normal talvez a exceção seja o mecanismo errado. O nome exceção não é assim por acaso, deve ser algo excepcional, não normal. Eu já vi gente defendendo que exceção não deve ser usada para situações excepcionais, bota camisa de força em uma pessoa dessas.

Esse caso parece estranho que possa ser ignorado. "Não era tão importante enviar o e-mail quanto que a solicitação fosse cadastrada", jura? Então não mande-o.

Pode ser chamado de anti-padrão, mas eles estão aí para serem usados também. Isto se chama [*exception swallowing* ou *error hiding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding).

Tem o risco de estar fazendo algo errado :P Se for o correto para essa situação não há problema. Tenha certeza que em nenhum momento o fato da falha não ter um tratamento não vai causar um outro problema.

Tem um problema neste caso específico, está [capturando `Exception`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101). Isso é muito errado, porque ele engolirá exceções que precisam ser tratadas, que podem até serem erros de programação (trapalhada), aí é grave. Se é para engoli-la é mais importante ainda que capture uma bem específica.

E se a exceção lançada não for tão específica assim? Ache outro fornecedor. Esse não presta :P

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Com "exceção" do meu caso que ignora a exceção. Foi uma piada :D

Comment: acho que a resp do bigown pode ser considerada a correta, na minha opinião!!!