# Leitura de arquivo no IDE funciona e na hora que gera o .jar não funciona

Tags: java, arquivo, jar

Eu tenho uma aplicação que lê um arquivo texto que está na mesma pasta onde se encontra a aplicação. Quando eu executo o programa no netbeans ele lê o arquivo normal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando eu gero o JAR ele não lê o arquivo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já conferi se quando o JAR é gerado o arquivo texto está no pacote e está. Alguém pode me ajudar??

Código do programa de teste:

```
package NewClass;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    URL url2 = this.getClass().getResource("teste.txt");//RECEBE A URL DO CAMINHO DO ARQUIVO 'Caminhopadrao'
    String path = url2.toString().replace("file:", "");//TRANSFORMA A URL EM STRING E MUDA O TRECHO 'file:' PARA NADA
    try {
        BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));//INSTANCIA UM BUFFER PARA LER O ARQUIVO
        String linha = "";//INICIALIZA A VARIÁVEL QUE RECEBERÁ O QUE LER DO ARQUIVO
        linha = buffRead.readLine();//GRAVA NA VARIAVÉL A LEITURA DO ARQUIVO
        jLabel1.setText(linha);//INSERE NO CAMPO DE TEXTO CDO CAMINHO A LEITURA DO ARQUIVO                
        buffRead.close();//ENCERRA O BUFFER DE LEITURA
    } catch (IOException e2) {
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 264, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: O arquivo está dentro do jar ou fora?

Comment: O arquivo está dentro do jar

Comment: Como está a estrutura do seu projeto?

Comment: Como assim a estrutura?? Você diz a estrutura de pastas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que, dentro do jar, o arquivo de texto deixa de ser considerado um arquivo físico do sistema de arquivos, e os métodos que está usando apenas trazem uma URL baseada neste sistema.

Quando você executa o projeto via IDE, o que ocorre na verdade é a execução do projeto pelo sistema de arquivos local, ela(IDE) não cria um jar para executá-lo, apenas carrega os *bytecodes* já compilados de alguma pasta do sistema operacional, por isso o seu código funciona quando executado direto dela, mas quando gera o jar, não consegue ler o arquivo.

Para acessar o arquivo corretamente, utilize o método [`getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) e para carregar ele propriamente dito, utilize um [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader-java.io.InputStream-):

```
try {
    BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("teste.txt")));//INSTANCIA UM BUFFER PARA LER O ARQUIVO
    String linha = "";//INICIALIZA A VARIÁVEL QUE RECEBERÁ O QUE LER DO ARQUIVO
    linha = buffRead.readLine();//GRAVA NA VARIAVÉL A LEITURA DO ARQUIVO
    jLabel1.setText(linha);//INSERE NO CAMPO DE TEXTO CDO CAMINHO A LEITURA DO ARQUIVO                
    buffRead.close();//ENCERRA O BUFFER DE LEITURA
} catch (IOException e2) {
}
```

Dica: se não for tratar exceçao, [**nao utilize catch vazio.**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107887/usar-um-catch-vazio-%C3%A9-uma-pr%C3%A1tica-ruim)

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção e pela solução, deu certo.

Comment: @PedroAfonso no titulo você diz compilador, mas nao quis dizer IDE? Porque o compilador nao tem nada a ver com o problema.

Comment: Sim, desculpa pela desatenção.

Comment: Como faço pra fazer a escrita no arquivo, eu estava usando o mesmo método pela url, quais classes eu devo usar para fazer a escrita no arquivo com esse método que você mostrou?

Comment: @PedroAfonso nao pode, o arquivo dentro jar é somente para leitura.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado