# atribuir um objeto de uma lista como atributo de outra classe

Tags: java

Estou fazendo a importação de dados através de arquivo txt, e empaquei nessa classe que tem dois atributos do tipo objeto,fornecedor e produto. Quando leio o arquivo txt, passo como parâmetro apenas o código dos mesmos, e tento verificar na lista se existem, e se sim os adiciono como atributo.

Porém, diferentes dos outros métodos de importação que fiz antes, esse nao está adicionando de nenhum jeito.

O Catch da exceção me da o seguinte erro :

```
Excessao : java.lang.NullPointerException

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Sistema.Importa.main(Importa.java:113)  \* obj.getFornecedor().setCodigo(codigoF);  é a linha removida com comentário
```

segue o código do metodo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {         

    File arquivo = new File("C:\\Users\\itach\\Desktop\\RegistroCompras.txt");
    try{

    Scanner  scanner = new Scanner(arquivo);

    DaoContasPagar dao = new DaoContasPagar();
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){

        String s[];

        s=(scanner.nextLine().split(";"));
        CompraDeProdutos obj = new CompraDeProdutos();

        int numeronf = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
        obj.setNotaFiscal(numeronf);
        int codigoF=Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
        obj.getFornecedor().setCodigo(codigoF); \* removi essa linha 
        for(Fornecedor lista : Dados.listaFornecedores){
            if(lista.getCodigo()==codigoF){
                obj.setFornecedor(lista);
           }
            else
                {
                    System.out.println("fornecedor nao existe");

                        } 
        }
        obj.setData(s[2]);
        int codigoP= Integer.parseInt(s[3]);

        for(Produto lista : Dados.listaProdutos){
            if(lista.getCodigo()==codigoP){
                obj.setProduto(lista);

            }
            else
                {
                    System.out.println("fornecedor nao existe");

                        } 
            }

        int quantidade=Integer.parseInt(s[4]);
        obj.setQuantidade(quantidade);
        dao.NovaCompra(obj);

        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

e a classe do qual estou gerando um novo objeto, com os dados importados.

```
public class CompraDeProdutos {
    private int notaFiscal;
    private Produto produto;
    private String data;
    private Fornecedor fornecedor;
    private int quantidade;
    private double totalApagar;

    public List <Produto> getLista(){
        return Dados.listaProdutos;
    }

    public CompraDeProdutos(int notaFiscal, Produto produto, String data, Fornecedor fornecedor, int quantidade, double totalApagar) {
        this.notaFiscal = notaFiscal;
        this.produto = produto;
        this.data = data;
        this.fornecedor = fornecedor;
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
        this.totalApagar = totalApagar;
    }



    public int getNotaFiscal() {
        return notaFiscal;
    }

    public void setNotaFiscal(int notaFiscal) {
        this.notaFiscal = notaFiscal;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public double getTotalApagar() {
        return totalApagar;
    }

    public void setTotalApagar(int totalApagar) {
        this.totalApagar = totalApagar;
    }

    public Produto getProduto() {
        return produto;
    }

    public void setProduto(Produto produto) {
        this.produto = produto;
    }

    public Fornecedor getFornecedor() {
        return fornecedor;
    }

    public void setFornecedor(Fornecedor fornecedor) {
        this.fornecedor =fornecedor;
    }

    public CompraDeProdutos() {
    }



    public int getQuantidade() {
        return quantidade;
    }

    public void setQuantidade(int quantidade) {
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "" + getNotaFiscal() + ";" +getFornecedor().getCodigo()+";" + getData() + ";" + getProduto()+ ";" + getQuantidade() + ";"+getTotalApagar()+";";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 11 * hash + this.notaFiscal;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final CompraDeProdutos other = (CompraDeProdutos) obj;
        if (this.notaFiscal != other.notaFiscal) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }





}
```

Comment: Adiciona a pilha de erros completa, só com essa linha dificulta detectar o problema.

Comment: Dica: se não for tratar exceçao, [**nao utilize catch vazio.**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107887/usar-um-catch-vazio-%C3%A9-uma-pr%C3%A1tica-ruim)

Comment: Editei o código  e removi a linha problemática. agora está adicionando com sucesso :D

Comment: Daniel o erro ficou evidente, voce jamais instancia um objeto `Fornecedor`, logo, está acessando um objeto nulo com essa linha na classe `CompraDeProdutos `

Comment: Remover a linha não conserta o problema, você está apenas adiando ele neste momento.

Comment: Entendi !! desculpe a pergunta mal pensada :s

como eu faço essa verificação então se não posso instanciar esse objeto ?

Comment: A pergunta correta é porque está criando um objeto vazio se fez um construtor passando dados? Não sei a logica aplicada na sua aplicacao, mas criar uma compra de produto vazia não faz muito sentido, olhando pelo lado logico de um programa de compras.

Comment: criei esse objeto vazio para poder setar os seus dados através da leitura do arquivo txt apenas, lendo cada dado do txt separado por ";" e adicionando ao atributo respectivo. 
Nesse método de importação eu iria instanciar um objeto para cada linha lida com os respectivos atributos da compra.

Comment: Então você precisa ficar atento ao tentar acessar Fornecedor e Produto dentro dessa classe, pois como voce cria ela vazia, estes 2 objetos não são instanciados nunca, e sempre que forem acessados, retornaram esse erro. Verifique se é null antes de acessar.

Comment: se eu passar apenas esses dois parâmetros no construtor eles serão instanciados automaticamente ao criar um objeto da classe?

Comment: Não, Voce é quem precisa criar essa instancia. Tem dois loops no código que preenchem estes objetos, ja. Apenas tome cuidado ao acessar eles na classe, checando se nao sao nulos antes.

Comment: Vou pensar aqui como fazer isso da maneira correta. Mas muito obrigado pela ajuda e pelo tempo disposto comigo :D