# Conexão Java + Firebird retornando Nula

Tags: java, eclipse, firebird, firebird-2.5

Minha string de conexão com o banco firebird retorna nula.

Segue abaixo código:

```
public class ModuloConexao {

    public static Connection conector(){
        //criação da varáivel conexao
        Connection conexao = null;

        //chamada do driver do mysql
        String driver = "org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver";

        //Armazenando informações referente ao banco
        String url = "jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:C:/Users/Comercial3/Desktop/SMallDATEL/SMALL.FDB"; //alterar para ip de um servidor local...
        String user = "sysdba";
        String password = "masterkey";

        //Estabelecendo conexão com o banco
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            return conexao;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //retorno ao usuario final

            return null;
        }

    } 
}
```

O problema que o java informa é um NullPointerException:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.datelcontrole.telas.TelaPrincipal.PesquisarProduto(TelaPrincipal.java:212)
    at br.com.datelcontrole.telas.TelaPrincipal$2.keyReleased(TelaPrincipal.java:89)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Segue minha classe que dá o erro:

```
public class TelaPrincipal extends JFrame {

Connection conexao = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;


private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField txtCodProd;
private JTable tblProdutos;
private JTextField txtNomeProduto;
private JTextField txtQtdAtual;
private JTextField txtQtdAtualizada;

//txtCodProd = new JTextField(100);

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                TelaPrincipal frame = new TelaPrincipal();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public TelaPrincipal() {
    setTitle("Controle Estoque - DATEL");

    conexao = ModuloConexao.conector();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 625, 327);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Estoque", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    setContentPane(contentPane);





    JLabel lblCdProduto = new JLabel("C\u00F3d. Produto");

    txtCodProd = new JTextField();
    txtCodProd.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            PesquisarProduto();
        }
    });
    txtCodProd.setColumns(10);

    tblProdutos = new JTable();
    tblProdutos.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
            {null, null, null},
            {null, null, null},
        },
        new String[] {
            "C\u00F3d.", "Descri\u00E7\u00E3o", "Quantidade Atual"
        }
    ) {
        boolean[] columnEditables = new boolean[] {
            true, false, true
        };
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return columnEditables[column];
        }
    });
    tblProdutos.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
    tblProdutos.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(349);
    tblProdutos.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(154);

    JLabel lblProduto = new JLabel("Produto");

    txtNomeProduto = new JTextField();
    txtNomeProduto.setEditable(false);
    txtNomeProduto.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblQuantidadeAtual = new JLabel("Quantidade Atual");

    txtQtdAtual = new JTextField();
    txtQtdAtual.setEditable(false);
    txtQtdAtual.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblQuantidadeAtualizada = new JLabel("Quantidade atualizada");

    txtQtdAtualizada = new JTextField();
    txtQtdAtualizada.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnAlterar = new JButton("Alterar");

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Cancelar");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
    lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Comercial3\\Desktop\\ERP\\meuCantinho\\src\\br\\com\\meucantinho\\icones\\search.png"));
    GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
    gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
        gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lblCdProduto)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(txtCodProd, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(lblNewLabel))
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lblProduto)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(txtNomeProduto, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 532, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(lblQuantidadeAtual)
                                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(txtQtdAtual, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addComponent(btnAlterar, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 215, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 62, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(lblQuantidadeAtualizada)
                                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(txtQtdAtualizada, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(3))
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(btnNewButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 229, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(27))))
                    .addComponent(tblProdutos, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 577, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
    );
    gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
        gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lblCdProduto)
                    .addComponent(txtCodProd, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(lblNewLabel))
                .addGap(18)
                .addComponent(tblProdutos, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(24)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lblProduto)
                    .addComponent(txtNomeProduto, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lblQuantidadeAtual)
                    .addComponent(txtQtdAtual, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(lblQuantidadeAtualizada)
                    .addComponent(txtQtdAtualizada, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(58)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnAlterar)
                    .addComponent(btnNewButton))
                .addContainerGap(13, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
}

public void PesquisarProduto(){

    String sql = "SELECT CODIGO, DESCRICAO FROM ESTOQUE WHERE CODIGO = ?";
    try {
        pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txtCodProd.getText());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        tblProdutos.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Poderiam me dizer o por que ele está retornando nulo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É porque algum erro está estourando e a execução cai no bloco `catch` onde você você simplesmente manda **ignorar** este erro e retornar `null`.

```
try {
    Class.forName(driver);
    conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    return conexao;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // A variável 'e' tem as informações sobre o erro, por favor, não a ignore.
    return null;
}
```

Aconselho fortemente que você dê uma lida nestas publicações:

- [Melhor maneira de lidar com Exceptions](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13303/18246)
- [Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/18246)

Comment: No meu debug, a variável 'e' retorna isso: "java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection rejected: No connection character set specified (property lc_ctype, encoding, charSet or localEncoding). Please specify a connection character set (eg property charSet=utf-8) or consult the Jaybird documentation for more information." Alguma idéia?

Comment: Bá, brother, tenho pouquíssima vivência com firebird. Você pode [abrir uma nova pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) com o seu código e mostrando esta mensagem de erro, certamente alguém vai conseguir te ajudar.

Comment: @D.Custodio não sei se ja achou o que procurava mas na sua url deve conter `...SMALL.FDB?charSet=utf-8`

Comment: @ErickMaia Cara...já tentei assim e não vai...Valeu pela ajuda

Comment: Já tentou `...SMALL.FDB?encoding=UTF8`

Comment: Sim...não vai das duas formas.

Comment: @D.Custodio Mas tá retornando nulo pelo motivo que eu disse na minha resposta, jovem. Você precisa agora saber qual é o motivo do erro.

Comment: private static final String DRIVER = "org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:firebirdsql:192.168.1.158:C:/IBS/Sisfatura/SISFATURA.FDB?lc_ctype=UNICODE_FSS";
    private static final String USER = "SYSDBA";
    private static final String PASS = "masterkey";

Comment: @JonathanCR Hein?

Comment: depois do .FDB tenta isso ?lc_ctype=UNICODE_FSS

Comment: mals nen vi que era de 2 anos atras a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Em um teste aqui consegui simular este erro, e corrigi assim:

```
...SMALL.FDB?encoding=ISO8859_1
```