# Interpretação do Dive into Python sobre exceções

Tags: python, exceção, stack

Segue um trecho da página 47 do livro 'Dive Into Python' sobre *exceptions*:

"...You don’t need to handle an exception in the function that raises it. If one function doesn’t handle it, the exception is passed to the calling function, then that function’s calling function, and so on “up the stack.” If the exception is never handled, your program will crash, Python will print a “traceback” to standard error, and that’s the end of that. Again, maybe that’s what you want; it depends on what your program does."

Eu não entendi exatamente o que ele quer dizer com o *So on, up the Stack* e com o processo que antecede esta afirmação. Como assim a "Exceptions is passed to the called Function..."?

Outra coisa:

Na PEP 20 há a seguinte nota: "Explícito é melhor do implícito". Isto serve na hora de levantarmos as exceções de maneira específica? Usar apenas o except genérico não garante uma maior abrangência do problema? Então por que não usá-lo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você precisa ler: [O que são e onde estão o "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). Portanto as funções vão sendo chamadas e organizadas como uma pilha, e quando uma exceção é lançada, até que ela seja capturada por alguma função, ela vai encerrando as funções que estão na pilha de chamadas, até que se nenhuma função faça nada com ela acaba quebrando a aplicação (o que é bom em muitos casos porque é erro de programação). O que vai acontecendo é o que chamamos de borbulhamento da exceção.

Chamada:

[image: Pilha de chamada de algumas funções]

Se o tratamento só está na `main()`:

[image: Exceção borbulhando até a main]

E se é tratada logo na primeira função em cima da pilha:

[image: Lança a exceção e já pega na função chamadora]

A exceção é uma forma de controle de fluxo que manda buscar o primeiro `except` dentro do escopo dinâmico (diferente do [escopo léxico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) que todo mundo conhece), ou seja, dentro do fluxo de execução que efetivamente ocorreu. Alguma função que está em execução deve ter esse comando que captura a exceção, pode ser até a própria.

O mais comum é que a função que chamou a outra que lançou a exceção é quem vai capturar, pelo menos quando a exceção é usada de forma correta. Em alguns casos acontece corretamente de passar para dois ou três níveis de chamada.

Exceção é um controle de fluxo que você não sabe onde vai parar só olhando o código, somente durante a execução é que acontece conforme ocorrem as chamadas de funções.

Ser explícito nada tem a ver com o assunto, ser explícito não é ser específico, são coisas muito diferentes.

Também é útil ver [como lidar com exceções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101) e [porque deve tratar com exceções específicas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101). Portanto ser o mais específico quanto faça sentido em cada caso é o mais correto.

Answer (score 4):

Respondendo a primeira pergunta, considere que você possui um programa em Python com N funções **F1** até **FN**. Em que **F1** lança um exceção. Suponha também que em seu programa, **F1** é chamada dentro de **F2**, **F2** dentro de **F3** e assim por adiante... E que **FN** é chamada na thread principal. O que o autor está fazendo é referenciar-se [a este conceito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), explicando que todas essas chamadas formam uma [pilha](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-data-structure/) de execução em que a exceção lançada em uma dada função **Fi** e não tratada por ela é automaticamente passada para a função **Fi+1** inserida anteriormente na pilha, até chegar em seu programa principal (*up the stack*), fazendo-o "crashar".

Em relação à segunda pergunta, acho que o Maniero já deu a melhor resposta.