# É uma boa prática lançar exceção nesses casos?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, exceção, regra-de-negócio

Estou resolvendo alguns exercícios de orientação à objetos. Um dos exercícios pede pra escrever uma classe que representa um voo de avião, contendo a data, o número e métodos para verificar status de assentos.

Os requisitos pedem um método `ocupa` que seja responsável por tomar um número de assento entre 1 e 100 e, caso esteja livre, ocupar o assento (basicamente isso seria somente seta-lo como ocupado). O exercício pede pra retornar true se o assento puder ser usado e false caso ele já esteja ocupado.

Não sei se gosto muito dessa abordagem. Na realidade, pensando sobre o método não acho natural ele retornar nada. Por isso implementei diferente. Se o assento pode ser ocupado, tudo correu bem e não precisa se fazer nada. Caso o assento já esteja ocupado estou lançando uma `InvalidOperationException` com uma mensagem apropriada.

O exercício também pede um método `proximoLivre` capaz de encontrar o número do próximo assento livre. Nesse caso o exercício não diz o que fazer se não houver mais assentos livres e então eu também estou lançando uma `InvalidOperationException`.

São boas práticas em casos como esse lançar exceções? Fiquei em dúvida se exceções deveriam ser usadas em casos assim também, ou somente pra lidar com erros mesmo da aplicação.

Comment: Eu penso que retornar TRUE/FALSE é mais para quando você está testando se algo pode ser feito ou não. Nesse seu cenário poderia ser um método `canBeOccupied( $id )` que retornaria TRUE/FALSE. Quem usar esse método para verificar é que lançará a Exception.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### Boas práticas

Primeiro, é uma "boa prática" fazer o que é correto e não porque algo é boa prática. E o que é correto depende da situação. O que as pessoas costumam chamar de boa prática é o que costuma ser correto na maioria das situações. O problema é que elas acabam achando que algo deve ser usado sempre.

## Seu caso

Se é um exercício e ele pede para fazer algo de uma forma, seria bom fazer do jeito que ele pede. Deve ter um motivo para ele pedir assim. Ok, você quer ir além? Vamos lá.

Lançar uma exceção no primeiro caso, até onde pude entender, é um **abuso do recurso**.

**Exceções devem ser usadas para situações excepcionais**. Este é um caso que você está usando para controle de fluxo.

Este método claramente deve dizer se a operação foi bem sucedida ou não. Não há problema de [*race condition*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101). Não há porque preferir o uso da exceção.

Se a operação pudesse criar uma *race condition* (onde o resultado é dependente de uma sequência ou momento de eventos incontroláveis e há um erro se esta ordem não for preservada) então seria diferente.

Neste caso se a operação do método foi mal sucedida (o método não conseguiu a ocupação), você usa essa informação para emitir a mensagem normalmente. Use um `if` para verificar a situação.

Claro que pode ser correto usar uma exceção, mas no que você explicou não parece ser o caso. Se explicar de outra forma, se arrumar um argumento melhor para preferir a exceção, aí eu posso sugerir outra coisa. Por isso iniciei com a questão da boa prática. Só a situação específica, bem definida, pode determinar o caminho **correto** à seguir.

No segundo caso inicialmente fica claro pra mim que o método deve devolver o número do assento livre para que esse número possa ser utilizado em algum lugar. Pode não ser isso porque não estou com todo enunciado.

Você tem três opções para informar que não há assento livre:

- Escolher um [número que indique isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101), zero ou um número negativo por exemplo. Esta forma não é bem vista porque confunde o que está fazendo. Está usando o mesmo retorno para duas coisas (informar uma informação correta e informar um erro). Mas não deixa de ser uma opção (ruim neste caso).
- Já que o método não pede para retornar nada, talvez esteja especificado em algum lugar que este valor está disponível de outra forma. Então retorne um `bool` informando se tem assento livre ou não. Talvez o exercício deixou isso com você para te testar se iria tomar a decisão certa. É exatamente igual ao primeiro caso.
- Usar um duplo retorno também pode ser a solução. Ou seja o retorno de fato é um `bool` e você passa uma variável como referência ([`out`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é suficiente em C# se é a linguagem que você está usando. Se você está usando Java, sinto muito, terá que criar uma classe só para conseguir tratar isso corretamente) para pegar o número do assento. Em C# 7 é possível também usar uma tupla.

  Veja o [`TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) como exemplo. É um método que foi criado nos mesmos moldes justamente para resolver este exato problema. E note que o `TryParse()` foi criado porque os desenvolvedores do .NET perceberam depois que o `Parse` original lançava uma exceção para controlar fluxo, para reger uma regra de negócio. Estava errado.

## Mecanismos X regras de negócio

Normalmente [**exceções devem lidar com mecanismos**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101) e não com [regras de negócio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48576/101). Nem todo mundo consegue perceber a diferença do que é mecanismo e do que é regra de negócio, principalmente quando as regras de negócio não são sobre negócios empresariais e sim negócios mais próximos da tecnologia utilizada.

Posso te garantir que a `InvalidOperationException` não foi criada para o que você deseja. É uma exceção de mecanismo e não de regra de negócio.

Nem é o melhor motivo para evitar uma exceção, mas ela é [**extremamente lenta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5888/101). Nada ruim quando algo excepcional aconteceu. Mas é trágico para o fluxo normal do programa.

Com o perdão do trocadilho, lançar ou capturar uma exceção deve ser uma exceção no código. Use em último caso, tente fazer o fluxo do seu programa funcionar corretamente sem o uso de exceção. Mas também não deixe de usá-la quando o código realmente pode entrar em uma condição excepcional, algo fora do normal, algo que não deveria acontecer (diferente de algo que apenas não é válido).

[Informações adicionais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101) que podem ajudar a entender mais sobre o assunto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).