# Regras de negócio sempre são relacionadas à validação?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, validação, regra-de-negócio

Desde que comecei a estudar orientação a objetos ouço muito sobre as regras de negócio. Basicamente, pelo que entendi até hoje, um objeto deve ter métodos encapsulado as regras de negócio e a modificação do seu estado deve ser feita através desses métodos e não através de acesso direto à seus atributos. Pelo que eu percebi existe tanta ênfase nisso que um objeto sem métodos é até chamado de anêmico.

O problema maior é que eu até hoje não entendi muito bem o que são realmente essas regras de negócio. Todos os exemplos que eu vi, as regras de negócio tem a ver com validação. Um desses exemplos é uma classe `Usuario` representando um usuário de um sistema, e as regras de negócio impostas no exemplo tem a ver com validações dos dados (garantir que sejam informados dados requeridos, garantir que o e-mail seja um e-mail válido, etc).

Outro exemplo muito usado é de sistema bancário e aí as regras de negócio são outra vez validações: por exemplo verificar se o saldo da conta é suficiente pra fazer um saque e etc. Dessa forma parece que as regras de negócio *sempre* são validações pra verificar se certa operação pode ou não ser realizada ou verificar se os dados informados são realmente consistentes.

Essa impressão está correta? As tais regras de negócio sempre tem a ver com validações? Se não, o que realmente são as regras de negócio?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

De fato, é muito comum que regras de negócio sejam validações, mas não necessariamente.

A interpretação do que é regra de negócio e o que é mecanismo nem sempre é muito clara ([fiz uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/386932/101) e não obtive respostas satisfatórias), e dependendo da metodologia utilizada pode haver a preferência por uma coisa ou outra.

Na verdade, se pensarmos nos tipos de objetos também há divergências sobre o que deve fazer parte do tipo como regra de negócio e o que deve ser algo externo ao tipo ainda sendo uma regra de negócio. Muitas vezes isto é implementado através de regras (*rules*), restrições (*constraints*), políticas (*policies*) ou tratamentos (*traits*). Que nada mais são que outros tipos auxiliares ao tipo principal. Algumas vezes um [mecanismo de regras de negócio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine) é utilizado para isto.

Pegando o exemplo da conta bancária, você já sabe as várias validações que existem. Mas o objeto só valida dados? Ele não pode executar nada?

Vamos dizer que você tenha um método chamado `ObtemContasInativas()`. Isto não seria uma regra de negócio? Não é validação. Nela consta a forma como uma conta é considerada como inativa e como fornecer dados delas. Note que quais informações e em que ordem também são regras de negócio incrustadas dentro deste método hipotético. Na verdade, é possível que este método faça uso de outro para saber se uma conta individual está inativa ou não, provavelmente um `EhInativa()`.

Muito provavelmente o primeiro método não está na classe da conta bancária em si, não faria sentido estar. Mas ainda é uma regra de negócio. Já o segundo método já faz mais sentido estar no tipo da própria conta bancária. Mas não necessariamente. Existem algumas razões para se optar por não estar. Mas isto não vem ao caso aqui.

Outro método poderia ser `EncerrarConta()` que poderia ser chamado automaticamente por algum evento, talvez verificado por um método `InativoMais180Dias()` ou manualmente por alguma função do sistema. E obviamente ela faria uma série de procedimentos para garantir que a conta se encerre. Tudo isto são regras de negócio.

Exatamente como vai acessar o banco de dados para pegar estas informações, para gravar o que for necessário para o encerramento provavelmente faz parte do mecanismo e não entra nestes métodos. Eles devem delegar estas especificidades para outros métodos de mecanismos, muito provavelmente em outras classes.

Então percebe-se que regras de negócio podem sim determinar como informações são obtidas, como executar determinados algoritmos, etc. Não são apenas verificações se o dado que está tentando entrar está certo ou errado.

Até mesmo o que fazer no caso de uma tentativa de entrada de dado inválido pode ser uma regra de negócio por si só. Deve *logar*? Deve chamar algum processamento auxiliar? Deve mudar algum estado de algum objeto?

Regra de negócio é qualquer coisa que determine o que você deve fazer em qualquer situação manipulando (lendo ou escrevendo, total ou parcial) aquela informação em uma forma abstrata. Em uma forma que faça sentido para o usuário.

Quando a manipulação fica mais concreta, como `WriteOnDataBase()` ou `DisplayOnScreen()` provavelmente já fazem parte do mecanismo. Normalmente são coisas que fazem sentido para o desenvolvedor apenas, mas são fundamentais para o sistema funcionar.

Então você pode **validar**, garantir (ligeira diferença semântica), registrar, consultar, classificar, condicionar, relacionar, executar, verificar, permitir/proibir, calcular, delegar, derivar, sinalizar, observar, etc. A quantidade de ações possíveis, mesmo que de forma genérica, como listada, pode continuar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então métodos como, `obterClientesInativos()`  ou `listarContaSalario()`  que obtêm informações especificas de algum objeto pode ser considerados regras de negocio, certo?

Comment: Genericamente falando são sim.

Answer (score 11):

Validações são, sim, regras de negócio. Mas existem outras.

Considere, por exemplo, outras regras de negócio do banco que vão além da verificação de saldo na conta antes de permitir um saque:

**Um banco fornece empréstimos**. Você vai ao banco e pede 100 mil reais para pagar em 10 vezes. O sistema vai automaticamente avaliar se você pode tomar este empréstimo e também a taxa de juros. Para tanto, as regras de negócio de liberação de crédito são acionadas. Elas incluem:

- Uma parcela mensal de 10 mil reais é maior que 30% da sua renda?
- Você tem sido um bom pagador em empréstimos anteriores?
- O montante geral de clientes com perfil parecido com o seu tem quitado suas dívidas?
- Qual é a taxa de juros básica em vigor?
- ...

Um cálculo complexo é feito considerando estas e outras informações e o empréstimo é liberado desde que aprovado por alguém com alçada superior ao gerente da sua conta. Então este gerente encaminha o empréstimo para aprovação, que entra em uma fila e vai ser avaliado por outro gerente, o que também é uma regra de negócio.