# Armazenar propriedades alteradas de uma classe

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, classes-abstratas, propriedade

Preciso ter armazenado na própria classe uma lista com (nome e valor) das propriedades alteradas. Porém não sei se forma que estou utilizando é viável.

Tenho a classe Funcionário abaixo:

```
public class Funcionario
{
    public int IdFuncionario { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Sobrenome { get; set; }

    public string Setor { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataEntrada { get; set; }
}
```

Crie uma classe base para poder identificar a alteração e armazená-la:

```
public abstract class BaseLista
{
    public readonly Dictionary<string, object> Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return false;
        }
        storage = value;
        if (propertyName == null) return true;
        if (!Dictionary.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            Dictionary.Add(propertyName, value);
        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary[propertyName] = value;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

E alterei a classe Funcionário desta forma:

```
public class Funcionario : BaseLista
{
    private int _idFuncionario;
    private string _nome;
    private string _sobrenome;
    private string _setor;
    private DateTime _dataEntrada;

    public int IdFuncionario
    {
        get { return _idFuncionario; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _idFuncionario, value);}
    }

    public string Nome
    {
        get { return _nome; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _nome, value); }
    }

    public string Sobrenome
    {
        get { return _sobrenome; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _sobrenome, value); }
    }

    public string Setor
    {
        get { return _setor; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _setor, value); }
    }

    public DateTime DataEntrada
    {
        get { return _dataEntrada; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _dataEntrada, value); }
    }
}
```

Abaixo o teste realizado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
[TestClass]
public class Testes
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TesteLista()
    {
        var funcionario = new Funcionario
                              {
                                  Nome = "Paulo",
                                  Sobrenome = "Balbino",
                                  Setor = "Desenvolvimento"
                              };


        var listaPropriedadesAlteradas = funcionario.Dictionary;

    }
}
```

Existe alguma outra forma melhor pra se fazer isso?
Preciso desta lista de propriedades alteradas para montar uma instrução de update genérica, não quero passar todos os campos da entidade, pois tenho casos que não terei todos.

Comment: Prefira sempre colocar todo o código em texto. Você pode colocar uma *screenshot* para auxiliar mas garanta que todo o código esteja disponível até para alguém usar para testar. Esta pergunta me parece ser um *code review* mais que qualquer outra coisa, certo? Se der tempo, eu tentarei responder.

Comment: Coloquei a imagem pra poder mostrar o resultado, porém já editei e inseri o código de teste. Então, pode ser uma revisão de código, mas gostaria de saber se existe forma melhor pra se fazer isso...obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Estrutura de dados

Primeiro eu acho estranho uma classe armazenar suas próprias alterações. Mas só você pode dizer se isso realmente é necessário. Eu acho que fere pelo menos o [princípio da responsabilidade única](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), e acho estranho uma classe armazenar coisas que não são próprias dela, esse "histórico" não faz parte de um funcionário. `Funcionário` é apenas um funcionário (melhor dizendo são dados de um funcionário). Histórico de alterações do funcionário deve ser uma classe que armazene isso. Dá até para [compor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101) o "histórico" na classe, ainda que eu também ache uma má ideia.

Outro princípio que está ferido aí é o da [substituição de Liskov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Um `Funcionário` **não é um** `BaseList`. Seria melhor fazer uma interface, quem sabe usando um método utilitário de ajuda (*extension method* talvez?). Mas só faria sentido usar a interface se ainda quiser ferir o princípio anterior. Reafirmo que o certo é fazer isso fora dessa classe.

No máximo eu faria uma [composição em vez de herança](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Então teria um campo que guardaria o estado mas o mecanismo de guardar estaria em outra classe (sei lá, `ClassPropertiesChanges`) - que seria usada neste campo - idêntica à `BaseLista` (acho).

E existem outros princípios feridos que poderiam ser citados, mas também não acho que todos os princípios precisam ser seguidos sempre. E consertando um talvez conserte os demais. Estou citando estes dois porque provavelmente eu os seguiria neste caso. Mas não tenho todas as informações do seu caso. Para mim é a principal mudança que você deveria fazer.

Ainda não sei se não deveria ser algo completamente separado e nem composição usar.

## Algoritmos

`SetProperty()` retorna um booleano que não é usado. Sei lá se precisa retornar algo ou se precisa usar. Pode ser que você vá usar depois. Só não esqueça de avaliar isto.

`Dictionary` além de ser um nome pouco significativo do que ela representa no código (nomes de variáveis não devem dizer de que tipo elas são mas sim o que elas guardam), me parece estranho ela ser pública (poderia encapsular em uma propriedade) e mais estranho ainda ela ser declarada como `readonly`.

Note que você está escrevendo no objeto dela. Talvez o `readonly` funcione de um jeito diferente do que você espera. Só a variável é somente de leitura, o objeto contido nela pode ser escrito, por qualquer parte da aplicação já que é público. [Variável é uma coisa, o valor dela é outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14492/101), pelo menos em tipos de referência

Tenho minhas dúvidas se passar `storage` como `ref` é uma boa ideia. Não vou testar em várias situações mas não sei se funcionaria se usasse ele de outras formas no futuro. No passado eu faria algo assim, hoje eu tomo mais cuidado mesmo que eventualmente tenha que escrever mais código.

Imagino que foi proposital permitir que o campo possa ser alterado sem passar pela propriedade que a encapsula e que feito isto não vá armazenar nesse "histórico". Não querer armazenar em alguma situação pode ser útil - também pode ser mal usado - mas não sei se é uma boa ideia alterar o campo diretamente. Em coisas simples pode não causar problema mas se a propriedade começar ter outros algoritmos, ignorá-lo pode ser problemático.

Você está guardando só o último valor alterado. É isto mesmo? Talvez você esteja querendo fazer outra coisa com isso. Talvez esteja querendo implementar um recurso de desfazer (*undo*) ou algo para comparar se houve alteração em cada campo. Se for isto, definitivamente eu não faria desta forma, faria um mecanismo separado para controlar o que precisa. No fundo cai no que eu falei no início.

Por fim, você sabe que não precisa verificar se uma chave está contida no dicionário para saber se deve alterá-la ou adicioná-la? Quando tenta atribuir um valor para uma chave que não existe a chave é criada automaticamente.

## Conclusão

Se eu gastar mais tempo acho que acharia outras coisas que podem ser melhoradas, mas novamente, poderia não se aplicar ao seu caso específico, mas espero que isto já ajude.

Comment: Bom, vou precisar de um tempo pra estudar os princípios mencionados. Agradeço a ajuda e vou tentar algo com a composição, caso tenha algum link com exemplo ficarei grato, de qualquer forma sua explicação foi muito boa. Vlw!

Comment: O contexto do meu trabalho é um pouco grande pra explicá-lo aqui e talvez passar essa necessidade que tenho, mas pra resumir, essa entidade será alterada em um projeto windows form e vai ser enviada para um wcf service que por sua vez irá chamar o acesso a dados para atualizá-la no banco de dados...daí eu queria usar essa lista de propriedades para atualizar somente quem foi alterado.

Comment: É, me parece que a classe não deva liar com isto mesmo. Você está misturando regras de negócio com mecanismos. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48581/101. Acho até que deveria criar um sistema de [eventos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) para notificar outra classe quando a propriedade for modificada. Neste caso nem a composição eu faria. Pode parecer um pouco mais complicado mas é o mais correto, evite alguns problemas, desorganização e dá uma flexibilidade que pode ser usada em outras coisas. Assim a classe lida só com o funcionário e não com o que pode acontecer com ele

Comment: Nos links passados tem exemplos de composição se for por este caminho. Mas é apenas usar um campo que contém um objeto ao invés de fazer este objeto ser parte da classe. Herança deve ser usado em último caso. Mas eu nem me preocuparia com isto para este caso (talvez para outros). Eu reforço ainda mais depois do seu comentário que esta classe, para fazer mais corretamente, não deveria carregar qualquer informação de alteração de seus dados. Ela deveria notificar que a alteração foi feita para quem assinar estes eventos. tenho minhas dúvidas se você sequer precisa saber o valor antigo.

Comment: Realmente o valor antigo não é necessário, preciso apenas identificar quais propriedades foram alteradas e seus respectivos valores, obrigado pelo voto!

Comment: Irei pesquisar os links e se conseguir algo diferente que me atenda postarei, vlw!

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo os conselhos mencionados na resposta do Maniero, utilizei a interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` na classe `Funcionario`, através do evento `PropertyChangedEventHandler` obtenho as propriedades alteradas e armazeno em outro objeto que irá compor a mensagem a ser enviada para o WCF Service:

Classe `Funcionario`:

```
public class Funcionario : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _idFuncionario;
    private string _nome;
    private string _sobrenome;
    private string _setor;
    private DateTime _dataEntrada;

    public int IdFuncionario
    {
        get { return _idFuncionario; }
        set
        {
            _idFuncionario = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Nome
    {
        get { return _nome; }
        set
        {
            _nome = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Sobrenome
    {
        get { return _sobrenome; }
        set
        {
            _sobrenome = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Setor
    {
        get { return _setor; }
        set
        {
            _setor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DateTime DataEntrada
    {
        get { return _dataEntrada; }
        set
        {
            _dataEntrada = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Método de teste:

```
[TestClass]
public class Testes
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> _listaPropriedadesAlteradas = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    [TestMethod]
    public void Teste1()
    {
        var funcionario = new Funcionario();
        funcionario.PropertyChanged += FuncionarioOnPropertyChanged;
        funcionario.Nome = "Paulo Balbino";
        funcionario.Setor = "Desenvolvimento";

        _listaPropriedadesAlteradas.ToList()
                                   .ForEach(c => Debug.WriteLine("Propriedade: {0} - Valor: {1}", c.Key, c.Value));
    }

    private void FuncionarioOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        _listaPropriedadesAlteradas[propertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName] =
            sender.GetType()
                  .GetProperty(propertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName)
                  .GetValue(sender);
    }
}
```

Agora, utilizo a variável `_listaPropriedadesAlteradas` para compor a mensagem.