# Como implementar um controller "magro"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exceção, design-pattern

Estou trabalhando em um protótipo de uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC, onde quero deixar meu *controller* magro (com a menor quantidade de código possível), para tal, não fazendo lógica de negócio nele, mas sim na camada de negócio.

Tenho a camada de negócio, onde tenho minha classe `Usuario`, e nessa camada tenho interfaces que deverão ser implementadas por outras camadas. Estarei utilizando injeção de dependência.

Minha dúvida é como notificar meu *controller* sobre o que deu certo ou não, para notificar ou redirecionar o usuário, por exemplo, quando meu controller chamar `Usuario.Cadastrar()`, pode haver haver erro no preenchimento dos dados, a senha pode não atender os requisitos de segurança, o e-mail já pode estar cadastrado ou pode haver erro no envio do e-mail de confirmação.

O que o método Cadastrar deveria retornar para o *Controller*? Um enumerador como (`ErroEnviarEmail`, `SenhaFraca`, `EmailCadastrado`), uma `Exception` para cada caminho possível? Uma *string* etc.

```
public class Usuario
{
    public Usuario()
    {

    }

    public Usuario(IUsuarioRepositorio repositorio, ISeguranca seguranca, IEnviaEmail email)
    {
        this.repositorio = repositorio;
        this.seguranca = seguranca;
        this.email = email;
    }

    private IUsuarioRepositorio repositorio;
    private ISeguranca seguranca;
    private IEnviaEmail email;

    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }


    public bool Cadastrar()
    {
        if (this.ValidarPreenchimento())
        {
            if (this.seguranca.ValidarSegurancaSenha(this.Senha))
            {
                if (!this.repositorio.EmailCadastrado(this.Email))
                {
                    this.Senha = seguranca.Criptografar(this.Senha);
                    this.repositorio.Inserir(this);
                    this.email.EnviarEmailCadastro(this);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }       
        return false;
    }

    private bool ValidarPreenchimento()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Email))
            return false;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Senha))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Qual o motivo pra você ter uma "camada de negócios"?

Comment: Vários motivos. Pode chamar essa camada de domínio, serviço, ou mesmo Model, pois não deixa de ser um model. É questão de separação de responsabilidades, e reutilização. Hoje é ASP.NET MVC, mas logo posso criar uma Web API, aproveitando bastante coisa, tendo que reescrever apenas os controllers da API

Comment: Isto não vai ser necessário no ASP.NET 5, até porque o *Controller* MVC6 para Web API e MVC deve ser o mesmo. Sua separação só é pertinente até o MVC5. Ainda assim gostaria de mais uma resposta?

Comment: Interessante. Creio que é isso por hora. Antes meu controller tinha um pouco mais de código, e esse conceito anti "fat controller" me deixou um pouco confuso no quesito das repostas que ele precisa. Mas o material passado por @bigown deu uma direção.Mas ainda estou estudando.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imagino que você terá dificuldades de fazer qualquer coisa que possa ser chamado de "magro" quando você fala em tantas camadas. Lasanha não combina com magreza :). Tirar a regra de negócio do *controller* não é deixá-lo magro, é consertar um erro que havia sido cometido.

O *controller* não tem que ser notificado de nada. Ele invoca o *model*, que deve executar tudo o que precisa e informa o *controller* através do retorno.

Provavelmente vai chamar o `Usario.Cadastrar()` existente no *model* e o retorno booleano deste método deve ser a sua notificação se deu certo ou não. Pelo menos parece ser esta a intenção dele.

## Informação de erro rica

Ok, você quer retornar outros problemas possíveis. [Existem alternativas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

Eu, provavelmente retornaria uma enumeração ou um objeto que dê mais informações que podem ser usadas na *view* e eventualmente algum membro dela no *controller*. Este objeto poderia ser parecido com exceção apesar de não ser uma. Leia mais sobre no *link* acima.

Há quem diga que deveria usar exceção, mas eu não iria por este caminho para indicar problema de lógica de negócio. Principalmente para usar da forma demonstrada na outra resposta. Além de não resolver seu problema causa outros.

Dependendo do contexto poderia até usar a exceção, ou outra solução não descrita aqui, mas sem entender o problema como um todo é difícil afirmar, só posso listar alternativas.

Mas como regra geral [não use exceções para tratar regras de negócio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101), e que portanto não são excepcionais. E [validação é regra de negócio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48576/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: muito bom essas alternativas. agora me deu uma luz pra ajudar decidir.gostei ta citação da lasanha.

Comment: com base na sua resposta e sugestão leitura, encontrei os termos corretos para pesquiisar e achei uma questão na comunidade que me ajudou bastante http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63049/returning-status-codes-from-business-layer

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

- Usando validação por anotação mesmo você resolve todos os problemas de informação chegando errada da view.
- Usando try catch você trata todos os erros inesperados, podendo criar exceptions para alguma coisa mais especifica.

```js
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(VMObjeto obj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
           
              try{
                
                ... 
                //chamada do seu negocio
                ....
                
              catch (Exception ex)
               {
               
                 ... 
                 //seu tratamento de erro, usando a arquitetura que você quiser
                 
               }
              
             }
          
          }
```

Comment: valeu! imaginei que Exception era uma alternativa, polêmica, mas é uma alternativa. Sim vou fazer a validação por anotação, mas devo ter a validação na camada de negócio pois pretendo criar uma web api também.

Comment: @Murilo, apesar de não gostar da alternativa que irei te dá, você pode verificar se a chamada é [AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282190/where-is-request-isajaxrequest-in-asp-net-mvc-5) e retornar um `Json(retorno)` ao invés de `View(model)`