# O que é regra de negócio e regra de aplicação? O que define que um mecanismo é uma ou outra?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, paradigma-de-programação, regra-de-negócio

Sei que [tem pergunta sobre isso no geral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117697/101). Mas quero ir no específico.

Quando cria uma classe de negócio, um `Cliente` por exemplo, faz sentido ter partes de mecanismo, como os de `Object` (eu sei que a maioria das linguagens tem isso por padrão, a dúvida é se é um conceito correto ter algo que é mecanismo da linguagem junto do objeto de negócio)? Ou seja, por que eu posso ter `GetHashCode()`, `ToString()`, `Equals()` que não fazem parte da regra de negócio, e tem um "regrinha" dizendo que não posso misturar regra de negócio com aplicação?

Todos os chamados *design patterns* são regras de aplicação e mandam colocar em objetos que são regras de negócio.

Outro exemplo é um sistema de eventos que ele podem disparar para outros objetos, faz sentido conceitual independente da funcionalidade e utilidade dele?

Claramente estes são mecanismos da aplicação, até mesmo da linguagem. Vejo isto o tempo todo, mas vejo também que alguns dizem não poder ter coisas de persistência neste objeto porque ele é um mecanismo da aplicação e não faz parte do modelo de negócio. Porque algumas coisas de mecanismo da aplicação podem e outras não podem?

Qual a linha que define o que é cada coisa e o que pode ou não?

Mais um exemplo baseado em resposta postada: por que o número máximo de caracteres deve ser regra de aplicação? Por que não é regra de negócio? Ou é? E o mais importante, por que essas coisas ficam misturadas no mesmo objeto se elas são claramente responsabilidade? Algumas coisas ficam misturadas, mesmo que não seja  o caso deste exemplo.

Tem outros exemplos que pode demonstrar mais claramente o que é cada coisa?

Answer (score 0):

Olá,espero ser claro.
Regras de negócios dizem respeito a como o processo que o software vai implementar funciona.Por exemplo, imagine que o seu software irá automatizar o rh de um empresa qualquer, as regras de negocio seriam as regras que o rh já utiliza e poderiam ser desde como os arquivos devem ser nomeados até os direitos de acesso ao sistema e etc, no geral dizem respeito a como o processo é estruturado.

Regras de aplicação são no geral referentes a sua implementação e as limitações da mesma, podem ser definidas pela plataforma que se usa(o sistema pode aceitar apenas alguns formatos de imagem) ou pela implementação desenvolvida (numero máximo de caracteres definidos no banco).

Comment: Isto já está no link que eu postei, eu perguntei outra coisa. Não limite a ler o título da pergunta. Mas vou usar seu exemplo para ajudar o entendimento da pergunta. Editei, vê lá.

Answer (score 0):

Minha percepção é de que separar os conceitos de regra de negócio e de aplicação se torna mais simples à medida que são adicionados mais agentes ao cenário. Durante a etapa de levantamento de requisitos de um software, é natural que o analista opte pelo uso de uma API/Backend para, além de persistir as informações, coordenar o fluxo dos dados. Controle de acesso, por exemplo, é uma regra de negócio definida uma vez e imposta à todos os clientes. Se você está modelando um serviço monolítico que não prevê reusabilidade de regras entre módulos ou aplicações, os limites entre características de aplicação e negócio tendem a ser menos definidos.

---

> alguns dizem não poder ter coisas de persistência neste objeto porque ele é um mecanismo da aplicação e não faz parte do modelo de negócio.

Naturalmente, as regras de negócio são inerentes ao domínio em que está se trabalhando e estão relacionadas à processos do modelo de negócio - uma operação "cadastrar cliente" está para regra de negócio como "navegar para cadastro do cliente" está para uma operação de aplicação.

Meu entendimento sobre o conceito de regras de negócio afasta tais regras dos meios tecnológicos para implementá-las. [Esta resposta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/293892/332196) para uma pergunta semelhante à sua, porém em inglês, fala algo com o que concordo muito: "*Business logic is logic, that is created with collaboration and agreement with business experts*". Bom, o especialista em questão não se preocupa com (e provavelmente sequer conhece) problemas específicos de implementação relacionados à aplicação.

Outro aspecto é que a regra de negócio é relevante e comum para todas as aplicações que a utilizem, logo, poderia ser compartilhada entre as mesmas - como o caso de você desenvolver duas aplicações complementares (digamos um aplicativo para celular e um website) que dependam as mesmas regras de negócio. Compartilhar regras de aplicação pode não fazer tanto sentido nesse caso.

> por que o número máximo de caracteres deve ser regra de aplicação? Por que não é regra de negócio? Ou é?

Imagine um cenário de integração de sistemas, você está construindo uma aplicação cliente de um serviço governamental, digamos a Receita Federal. Sua aplicação precisa consultar dados de uma pessoa a partir do número de um documento, seja CPF. A regra de negócio diz que o CPF possui 11 dígitos numéricos, e isso é imutável. Na regra de aplicação, focando em um contexto de interface, um CPF pode ter 14 dígitos, se incluirmos a pontuação/máscara de entrada.

Respondendo a pergunta: pode ser os dois. Meu critério para separar a regra de negócio da de aplicação seria: esse limite de caracteres ainda existiria se a regra fosse implementada em outro cenário, como em papel ao invés de computadores? Se sim, então vejo como regra de negócio.

Expandindo minha própria pergunta acima: se o cenário fosse apenas outra plataforma (trocando meu banco de dados MySQL por Postgres, como exemplo), a limitação de caracteres mudaria? Se não, ponto para regra de negócio. Se sim, eu provavelmente deveria ter modelado melhor minha implementação para que a funcionalidade da aplicação não dependesse tanto de aspectos técnicos.

---

**Atualização**:

> Minha dúvida principal é o que é o limite das coisas e porque se prega separar e o tempo todo os códigos juntam essas coisas [...]

Sendo honesto, eu acho que esse é mais um caso do "faça o que eu falo mas não faça o que eu faço" do mundo do desenvolvimento de software. Sabemos quais são os padrões, as boas práticas, porém nem sempre os aplicamos, seja por falta de tempo ("você tem 2 meses para desenvolver esse sistema, porém já se passaram 6 semanas"); ou pela quantidade de boilerplate ou complexidade que essas implementações indicadas possam causar.

Como assim complexidade? Boilerplate?

Me refiro à aplicações pequenas, apesar de que o entendimento desse termo varie bastante de dev pra dev. Bom, ao adicionar um método para, citando seu comentário, "pegar um hash do objeto" (e até mesmo fazer uma validação em cima disso) me questiono: ***isso será utilizado em algum outro lugar?*** Algumas respostas possíveis nos meus projetos:

- **Não**, é relevante apenas para essa funcionalidade e não há previsão de reutilizar qualquer trecho disso. *Então implemento ali mesmo.*
- **Não, mas** esse trecho/método não pertence ao escopo que estou trabalhando (aqui já entra a separação que estamos falando). Porém é overworking criar uma camada/classe/interface para um método de 5 linhas... *Vou manter aqui, ou, com a implementação mais simples possível, colocar em outro arquivo/pacote*.
- No futuro, **talvez**. *Busco uma alternativa que não aumente significativamente a complexidade do projeto e implemento o código de maneira que possa ser reutilizado.*
- **Sim**/Sim, porquê. A partir desse momento, a única maneira de evitar a cópia-e-cola é escrevendo código reaproveitável. Neste momento, está implícita a necessidade de seguir as boas práticas, separando as responsabilidades de maneira mais clara.

A complexidade que me refiro é subjetiva e bastante opiniativa. Criar uma "camada" da aplicação para alguma programação simples apenas para "seguir o padrão" é indicado, porém o programador pode se questionar "realmente preciso criar uma interface aqui sendo que provavelmente terei apenas uma classe concreta"? Essa é uma dúvida recorrente quando estou, por exemplo, limitado ao Java 7 enquanto crio minha aplicação Android. Quantas linhas de boilerplate seriam economizadas se pudesse usar lambdas ao invés de uma classe anônima?! Talvez seja um exagero particular meu, mas por vezes minha busca por "simplificar a arquitetura" acaba pegando alguns atalhos e descartando boas práticas que seriam mais verbosas.

### **TLDR;**

Meu entendimento empírico do porquê as regras de aplicação e de negócio acabam misturadas é que os programadores têm limitações (tempo, recursos, conhecimento) que exigem tais medidas, e o software muitas vezes é visto como algo que sempre vai exigir manutenção (logo, poderá ser melhorado no futuro).

Comment: Mas monolítico ou não todo mundo usa regras de aplicação junto com de negócios, inclusive boa parte das linguagens torna impossível não fazer isto, assim como a maioria dos *frameworks* que as pessoas usam. Pegando do seu texto: "Business logic is logic, that is created with collaboration and agreement with business experts", então porque um objeto `Cliente` tem coisas como pegar um *hash* do objeto, transformar em *string*, comparar dois objetos, adicionar um *subscriber* para uma evento e dispará-lo? Esta é a questão. Isto tudo explica as diferenças, mas não porque todo código mistura ambas.

Comment: A resposta foca mais em mostrar porque é bom separar, e isto eu sei, inclusive porque *linkei* uma resposta que fala disto (ainda que nem seja minha referência para saber disto). Minha dúvida principal é o que é o limite das coisas e porque se prega separar e o tempo todo os códigos juntam essas coisas, conforme os exemplos que eu dei. A parte boa da resposta é o que diz que a regra existiria em outro cenário. Isto parece ser um critério relevante de escolha do que é cada uma, mas ainda falta porque as pessoas misturar as duas como o corre com o `Object` e o evento (Observer pattern)

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta.

Comment: Melhorou bem, mas a questão do *hash*, você não tem opção, a linguagem definiu que é assim. Ora, se a linguagem diz que é pra por ali, então as "regrinhas" de separar as regras de negócio e aplicação não é algo tão importante assim. E se é, porque ela obrigam fazer isto? O mesmo pra um sistema de eventos e diversos outros *design patterns* que as pessoas aplicam que são mecanismos da aplicação e estão lá junto do objeto que deveria ser só de negócio. No caso do *hash*, você pode até delegar a implementação, mas o contrato está lá no objeto de negócio (só pra pegar esse exemplo).

Comment: Então só não concordo com a parte que diz que seria limitação de recursos, e a pergunta é surgiu justamente porque não é o caso, existe uma determinação técnica ou regra tida como absoluta para fazer isso. Por isso cito o exemplo do mecanismo do `Object` estar em todos objetos. Tudo nele é mecanismo da aplicação, da linguagem, não é de negócio, mas está lá. E cito os eventos que em geral não é algo da linguagem, mas está em todo canto como algo a ser feito sempre desse jeito. Poderia ter falando de outros *design patterns* que as pessoas usam não porque estão sem tempo de fazer melhor.

Comment: Meu entendimento sobre a herança de `Object` é que por ser mecanismo da linguagem, não conseguimos dissociá-lo das regras de negócio (logo, é necessário para uma implementação concreta). A linha que define os limites sobre os mecanismos que podem (ou não) ser usados depende da linguagem/tecnologia (infelizmente não posso elaborar esse aspecto).

Voltando ao *hash*, vejo que seria possível abstrai-lo sem delegar sua implementação, bastando encapsular o objeto de negócio em outro, agora em uma camada da aplicação. Aí entra meu ponto sobre a complexidade: na prática, isso compensa?

Comment: Sobre "separar as regras de negócio e aplicação não é algo tão importante assim", minha visão particular é de que os padrões no geral são recomendações e servem para guiar o programador. São muito importantes para delinear o desenvolvimento, mas não são obrigações de quem escreve o código. É um aspecto particular de projeto e profissional, visto que não há padrão que atenda necessidades universais.