# Somar 2 atributos e retornar para um terceiro atributo

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, campos

Estou tentando somar dois atributos e retornar o valor para um terceiro atributo, segue exemplo, é possível e se sim o que estou fazendo de errado?

```
package testesomaatributos;

public class TesteSomaAtributos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtributosAqui o = new AtributosAqui();

        o.setN1(10);
        o.setN2(5);

        System.out.println(o.getR());
    }

}
```

---

```
package testesomaatributos;

public class AtributosAqui {
    private int n1;
    private int n2;
    private int r;

    public int getN1() {
        return n1;
    }
    public void setN1(int n1) {
        this.n1 = n1;
    }

    public int getN2() {
        return n2;
    }
    public void setN2(int n2) {
        this.n2 = n2;
    }

    public int getR() {
        return r;
    }
    public void setR() {
        this.r = this.n1 + this.n2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sim, é possível, está tendo algum problema pra fazer isso?

Comment: faltou utilizar o método setR() para que o campo r seja afetado com o resultado da soma de 10 e 5.

Comment: Se o R sempre depende dos valores de n1 e n2, não faz sentido ter um setter só para ele (ainda mais um sem parâmetros). Eu faria `public int getR() { return this.n1 + this.n2; }` - e aí nem precisa ter um campo só para o `r`. Dependendo do que precisa fazer, podem ter outras soluções melhores, mas sem mais contexto, é o que dá para sugerir...

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 6):

Vejo alguns problemas neste código, todos conceituais.

[O que você chama de atributo na verdade chama-se campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). Ei sei, tem monte de lugar ensinando errado, não é culpa sua.

Este código provavelmente deveria ter um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Tudo leva a crer que é mais adequado (com pouca informação, não posso cravar). E aí tem que [pensar se deveria ter *getters* e *setters*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101), esse é o mecanismo da moda mas que as pessoas usam sem pensar se deveriam ter isso no seu código, se ele está atendendo um motivo real e não apenas seguindo regras inventadas por aí. A coisa tá tão grave que que as pessoas dão mais valor para ele que o construtor.

Especialmente deveria pensar se um *setter* é necessário, em muitos casos não deveria poder mudar o estado depois da sua construção. Inclusive em muitos casos isso nem deveria ser uma classe, mas por enquanto Java não tem uma forma de criar um tipo sem ser desta forma, o que sempre foi uma deficiência da linguagem que "agora" será consertada.

Mas o *getter* também pode ser errado por não ser necessário para o que pretende fazer, pode ser que só queira acessar o dado direto e nunca de outra forma, então não tem porque seguir regra boaba se é isso que quer fazer. Adote a semântica correta. Se fosse proibido acessar o campo de forma direta a linguagem nem deixaria fazê-lo. Algumas pessoas se apropriaram da verdade absoluta e dizem que nunca deveria fazer isso, mesmo a linguagem, mais pragmática, permitindo. Mas em outros casos até deveria ter uma forma de acessar o dado sem o campo direto, mas seria um método que faz algo mais semântico e não um *getter* que tem uma semântica muito simples e alguns dizem que isso é conceitualmente errado.

Os nomes todos dizem nada e isso por si só é um erro conceitual, dar nomes significativos pra tudo é fundamental para o código ser legível e dar um entendimento do que ele deveria fazer.

Este é um caso aparentemente artificial que provavelmente nem deveria ser uma classe, fazer um algoritmo simples resolvia melhor. Modelar classes é sempre fazer algo que faça sentido. Se não precisa dela e faz pra "estudo" está estudando errado, porque classe não é só um mecanismo, é uma filosofia de como construir software, se faz errado aprende errado.

Mantendo a ideia geral o seu código parece fazer o que está escrito na pergunta, mas falha em executar corretamente, por um erro conceitual. Se um objeto depende de uma operação anterior para funcionar corretamente (o que mostra o comentário do MauroAlmeida) então tem algo errado nele, não é um objeto [coeso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101), e seu código faz isso. Se você não executar o método `setR()` a soma não estará disponível. Na verdade isso nem é um *setter*, embora use o mesmo nome. Um padrão de projeto chamado *setter* sempre tem um método chamado `setXXX(valor)` ou algo parecido (tem linguagens que tem uma sintaxe melhor para isto e chama isto de propriedade), portanto tem sempre que receber um valor, o seu método não recebe um e não é um *setter* (tenho certeza que acha que é um). Por isso que eu falo que precisa entender o que está usando.

Ainda que insista nesse erro, o *getter* (`getR()`), deveria dar erro se a soma não foi realizada. E sim, você precisaria criar um mecanismo para controlar isto, o que me parece um absurdo (tenho uma [pergunta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/386932/101), em outros tempos alguns usuários ativos do site já teriam respondido). Não estou sugerindo fazer isto, o mais correto é esse *getter* só dar o resultado e nem guardar algo em outro campo, assim:

```
public int getR() { return n1 + n2; }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/Getter.java).

Conforme o comentário do hkotsubo acima. A única questão é que isto eliminaria o campo `r` e a pergunta diz que quer isto. Claro, acho que é um problema XY, está querendo resolver um problema causado pelo problema criado por uma decisão errada anterior.

Não estou passando a ideia que tudo isso que eu disse que está errado não pode ser usado corretamente em outro caso ou em algum caso que seja mais claro o que quer fazer.

De nada adianta tentar programar orientado a objeto, quando o objetivo dessa técnica é fazer o código ser mais organizado e semântico, se não entender a semântica do problema ou a semântica da linguagem ou a semântica dos padrões que resolveu adotar, já está fazendo errado por definição.

Por isso que eu sempre falo que os exemplos que tem por aí desensinam a fazer correto, porque eles são receitas de bolo, em geral receitas de programa de televisão, não são feitas para produzir comidas deliciosas que qualquer um consegue fazer, é só para dar água na boca nas pessoas. Se a pessoa não dominar muito aquilo a receita serve para nada.