# Lista de Exceptions

Tags: c#, .net

Como implementar uma classe de forma que eu possa adicionar uma exception em uma lista de exception.

Essa classe seria usada para o caso abaixo, por exemplo:

No método de validação pode retornar um ou mais erros, sendo assim, cada erro encontrado vou adicionado uma exception na lista e ao final da validação disparo essa lista que cairá dentro do catch especifico do tipo dessa lista.

Comment: Não quererá usar [`AggregateException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.aggregateexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Pode criar uma `AggregateException` com uma lista de excepcoes e depois apanhar a `AggregateException` num `catch` e aceder as excepcoes atraves do `.InnerExceptions`.

Comment: Um método de validação não deveria lançar exceção. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101 http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101 http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101

Comment: @Leandro uma dica é tomar cuidado com lançar exceções com frequência , dependendo do que for sua validação ,  pois se for por exemplo validação de um cadastro e houverem erros frequentes isso pode derrubar o pool do app no IIS , mesmo que a exceção seja tratada . ( O IIS entende que isso deve acontecer se ocorrem muitas exceções )

Comment: Valeu pela dica @JohnDiego. Mas no meu caso é para Windows Form mesmo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode usar a [`AggregateException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.aggregateexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para fazer o que pretende:

```
try
{
    List<Exception> excepcoes = new List<Exception>();
    excepcoes.Add(new ArgumentException("argumento", "argumento invalido"));
    excepcoes.Add(new ArgumentNullException("argumento nulo"));
    excepcoes.Add(new InvalidCastException("operacao invalida"));

    throw new AggregateException(excepcoes);
}
catch(AggregateException aEx)
{
    foreach(var ex in aEx.InnerExceptions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}\n", ex.GetType(), ex.Message);

        // Output:

        // System.ArgumentException: argumento
        // Parameter name: argumento invalido

        // System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
        // Parameter name: argumento nulo

        // System.InvalidCastException: operacao invalida
    }
}
```

O constructor do `AggregateException` aceita uma lista de excepcoes, que pode depois ser acedida através da propriedade `.InnerExceptions`.

Veja [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VByRB6) um exemplo no dotFiddle.

Comment: Eita confundi a pergunta... li de novo ! Sua solução é a certa !

Comment: Se precisar de comunicar que ocorreram excepções, uma lista de excepções não vai funcionar. Precisa de as envolver num outro tipo de excepção que as contenha. A sua resposta funciona se tiver de aceder as excepções no local onde elas são levantadas. Mas considere que tem um método onde as excepções ocorrem e que a) precisa de acumular as excepções, b) precisa de levantar uma excepção caso haja alguma excepção e c) precisa de comunicar todas as excepções. Neste caso, uma `AggregateException` ou parecido e a alternativa viável (retornar as excepções presume que há sempre excepções).

Comment: Show!!! Não sabia que a AggregateException faz exatamente o que quero.

Answer (score 1):

Você cria a lista como qualquer outra...

Segue exemplo: [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JCsDFJ)

```
        List<Exception> le = new List<Exception>();

        try
        {
            try{
                throw new Exception(" except 1");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                le.Add(e);
                throw new Exception("except 2");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)          
        {
            le.Add(e);
        }

        foreach(var e in le)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
```

Comment: Poderia fazer isso mas nao era isso que quero, pois cada erro teria que disparar exception para depois adiciona-lo na lista dentro do catch. O exemplo do @Omni me atende perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma exception sua herdando de `Exception`, nela, você adiciona um array de `Exception` ou da sua exception, e da `throw` / `catch` nessa sua. quando dar o `catch` você pode mostrar todas as exceptions da lista, caso existam.