# É melhor ter um tipo de exceção para cada caso ou uma exceção mais geral?

Tags: java, exceção, engenharia-de-software

Um projeto da minha faculdade me foi pedido, para criar uma classe chamada `RepositorioException` que é uma subclasse de `Exception` para ser usada para tratamento de exceções nas classes de repositório, no quais são: `RepositorioMotorista`, `RepositorioViagem`, `RepositorioSolicitante`.

Logo em seguida: Desenvolver um modelo de exceções usando a classe `RepositorioException` para os repositórios, os exemplos abaixo seriam alguns que foram pedidos para serem implementados.

Exemplos:

- AdicionarDuplicadoException
- RemoverNaoExisteException
- RemoverVazioException
- RemoverVazioException
- AlterarNaoExisteException
- AlterarVazioException

Minha dúvida seria a respeito desses casos de `Exception` se eu posso criá-los na própria classe `RepositorioException` ou se teria criar cada um separadamente herdando de `Exception`.

Comment: Acredito que primeiro você deve avaliar se há mesmo necessidade para criar tantas exceções assim. Eu acho muito desnecessário sair criando um monte de exceptions pra cada ocorrencia no sistema.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida parece que seu titulo mudou um pouco o sentido da pergunta.

Comment: @diegofm É que o título anterior dava a entender que ia ser uma pergunta sobre como criar novos tipos de exceção. Ao entrar, me deparei com uma pergunta sobre melhores práticas. Não sei se o novo título ficou perfeito, mas acho que tem que ir pra esse rumo, pelo menos.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida tem razão, a pergunta não está muito clara também, mas  tende a cair mais para este lado mesmo.

Comment: @diegofm Sua suposição foi melhor que a minha. :)
Vou editar novamente.

Comment: minha dúvida é se uma Classe digamos RepositorioException que é subclasse da Exception, poderia controlar todas as exceptions que o Repositorio poderia dar Throw, e como seria feito se possível com exemplo de código.

Comment: @LaTreta Edite a pergunta e forneça mais detalhes então, a pergunta acabou gerando duvidas desnecessárias porque não está clara.

Comment: @LaTreta Essas exceções que você citou já existem? Quem está lançando RepositorioException ?

Comment: @PabloAlmeida eu tenho que criá-las para tratar cada caso, eu coloquei o link das instruções do projeto, talvez vocês consigam entender melhor, eu nunca mexi com exceptions me sinto perdido.

Comment: @LaTreta Seu problema é mais na questão da interpretação do problema. Lendo o arquivo que você me passou, me parece claro que você só tem que lançar RepositorioException e passar uma mensagem detalhada para cada caso, como te sugeri na resposta. Mas tudo bem... como você nunca mexeu com isso, é normal ter dúvidas. Vou tomar a liberdade de editar sua pergunta para deixar semelhante à minha edição inicial para ainda ser útil para os próximos visitantes. A resposta do seu exercício é essa: crie apenas RepositorioException e lance ela com mensagens diferentes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pra mim nada disso seria exceção, pelo menos pelo que o nome indica. Considero um [abuso do mecanismo lançar exceção para situações normais que podem ocorrer no código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101). Eu adotaria [outros mecanismos para informar que algo não é válido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

Mas Java tem a cultura de abusar desse mecanismo. Se vai mesmo fazer isso precisa entender porque precisa da exceção.

Ela será usada para indicar o que deu errado, certo? Então precisa ser o mais específico possível, não é verdade?

Mas tem que ver se precisa saber se as capturas precisam ser especializadas ou não. Se precisar capturar cada um desses problemas de forma isolada, não há dúvidas que precisa separação.

Se na verdade precisa capturar a exceção indicando apenas que houve uma invalidade e depois com a informação que estiver na exceção decidir o que fazer, então pode usar apenas uma exceção. É claro que nesse caso a exceção precisa ter uma estrutura capaz de fornecer informações adicionais para uso após a captura. Pode ser até mesmo que tenha várias invalidades em uma só exceção, precisa prever isso.

Um exemplo de exceção que operada desta forma é a [`SQLException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) (eu sei, é C#, mas é só para mostrar a estrutura). Ela trata os mais diversos problemas internamente. Para a aplicação importa que houve uma exceção do SQL.

A maior desvantagem desse caso é que centraliza. Se precisar criar novas formas de exceção terá que manipular essa classe. Se for seguir cegamente o que manda a orientação a objeto deveria separar em cada classe. Mas se for pragmática, e for o correto, tem a **opção** de centralizar.

A decisão não é fácil e sem ver o caso concreto não sei como ajudar muito. Esse caso para ter um requisito, mesmo que artificial, para que as exceções sejam separadas, mas esse requisito não está tão claro. Minha recomendação é tentar clarificar o requisito antes de mais nada. Se não achar que é a melhor solução, tentar negociar o requisito. Mas tem que seguir o requisito. Então vejo um dilema na pergunta porque não parece que esse caso seja para você escolher o que fazer.

Se puder escolher eu acho que iria de exceção única, mas os requisitos não são claros para eu garantir isso.

Comment: Nesse contexto me foge do controle, pois como projeto da cadeira eu sou meio que obrigado a seguir as "especificações" passadas pelo professor.
Eu entendi a referência sobre SQLException utilizei um pouco ao trabalhar com SQLite.

Comment: muito bem colocado como sempre.
A exceção gera uma pilha de informação de onde o código gerou tal situação sendo um requisito ortogonal ao proposito do sistema.

Comment: Acho que a maior desvantagem de colocar a informação de tipo numa estrutura interna não é que centraliza. Centralizar, por si só, não é um problema. O que vejo de problema aí é que você está simulando um sistema de tipos, mas sem tirar proveito das estruturas que foram feitas para isso (o sistema de tipos da linguagem, baseado em classes). Ou seja, seu código não expressa tão bem quanto poderia qual é sua intenção.

Comment: @LaTreta, seu professor não aceita justificar com boas práticas e técnicas de engenharia de software? Sei que em alguns cleros é perigoso demonstrar o que o professor está enganado, mas ele pode valorizar seu empenho em buscar a forma mais adequada de se usar tais recursos.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida centralizar é um enorme problema em alguns sistemas. Provavelmente não nesse. Não costuma ser nos meus. Eu vou pelo pragmatismo. Da mesma forma que ter tudo em um tipo só não costuma causar problemas em casos assim. Note que não estou dizendo que deva abusar disto, muito mesmo que não deve criar novas exceções, eu sou contrário a isso e acho que um dos maiores erros que programadores fazem é só usar as exceções prontas, ou só a `Exception`. como é comum. Eu sei que tem gente que pensa diferente, mas depois que se usa exceção onde não deve, pra mim qualquer coisa tá valendo...

Comment: ...já que qualquer coisa que faça já será ruim.  Eu não sei o problema em detalhes, então não posso julgar, mas em casos onde e a exceção é usada para indicar invalidade, raramente é preciso ter uma para cada invalidade, porque quem vai tratar isso é um mecanismo que trata de validações, captura e entrega pra ele ver o que tem que fazer. Pra falar a verdade eu nem sei argumentar bem com algo que já errado no fundamento. @LaTreta se está especificado, faço o que mandaram e não se preocupe.

Comment: @bigown O problema ao qual me refiro tem mais a ver com legibilidade. É claro que, quando a coisa aperta, algum sacrifício tem que ser feito, então você está certo em ser pragmático. Só quis mesmo apontar qual é o problema de colocar a informação de tipo dentro, de um ponto de vista que não vem da orientação a objetos, porque do jeito que você falou, pareceu que não havia vantagem objetiva além da (des)centralização.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida existem outras sim, e o tipo correto é uma delas,n ão só pela captura, mas também pela semântica, incluindo aí a estrutura. É verdade que a maioria das exceções só possuem uma mensagem de informação "útil personalizada", mas não precisa e em muitos casos não deveria ser assim.

Comment: Já decidi, vou utilizar o RepositorioException para tratar todos os casos de Repositorio mudando apenas a mensagem para cada um ao invés de criar várias classes e as outras classes de exception que de fato foram explicitamente pedidas para serem criadas, eu criarei.

Answer (score 3):

A decisão de se é necessário criar um monte de tipos diferentes de exceção ou criar uma só que abrange todas não é uma decisão tão simples quanto "ver se tem um monte". Essa é uma área onde tem que olhar caso a caso.

Para que vai servir a separação? Porque, se for só para exibir um erro no log ou outra coisa que ajude na depuração, uma simples mensagem de descrição na `RepositorioException` já resolve. Criar exceções mais especializadas é interessante quando você precisa diferenciá-las para tomar caminhos realmente diferentes no seu fluxo de exceção.

Portanto, minha sugestão é que você comece com uma exceção mais geral e uma mensagem de detalhes (que você ***deve*** preencher com detalhes específicos do caso, para não se perder na hora da depuração) e, ao se deparar com a necessidade de fluxos de execução separados, vá criando novas exceções que sejam especializações dessa.

Answer (score 1):

Depende. E você não precisa abrir mão de uma coisa para ter outra.

Por exemplo, numa API usada por terceiros, você certamente vai querer os possíveis cenários excepcionais bem definidos e documentados, desta forma quem for usá-la pode realizar os tratamentos como melhor convier.

Entretanto, num sistema comum, remover algo que já foi removido pode ser algo simplesmente a ser ignorado. Por exemplo, um usuário, utilizando uma tela de cadastro num sistema web, clica várias vezes no botão "Excluir" porque a internet está lenta. Como resultado várias requisições chegam excluindo o mesmo objeto. A primeira vai surtir efeito e as demais mostram o erro de que o objeto não foi encontrado. Como o usuário vê apenas o resultado da última requisição, ele pode chegar à conclusão de que tem algum problema com os sistema.

Além disso, se você achar adequado, pode ter uma exceção genérica como `ErroCadastroException` que é lançada sempre que uma operação não permitida for executada, tal como adicionar um registro duplicado ou alterar algo que não existe.

Porém, suponha que você depois vê a necessidade de incluir uma validação específica para verificar se o valor de um campo é duplicado, de forma a mostrar para o usuário exatamente qual é o problema. Neste caso, poderia criar especificamente uma exceção que estenda a outra e contenha o erro em específico. Por exemplo:

```
public class CpfJaExisteException extends ErroCadastroException { 
    ...
}
```

Desta forma, você pode mostrar uma mensagem amigável para o usuário, por exemplo informando que aquela pessoa já possui cadastro ou mesmo redirecionando para o cadastro dela.

Um ponto importante aqui é que provavelmente você pode usar tal exceção nas rotinas internas do sistema, mas irá tratá-la em algum momento para tomar a ação necessária.

Em resumo, você deve criar as exceções somente se pretende tratá-las especificamente em algum ponto, caso contrário use uma exceção genérica.

Note também que há [alternativas para exceções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/164556/227). Por exemplo, se não houver dados numa tabela, retorne uma lista vazia. Na tela, você pode verificar se existem ou não registros retornados e exibir alguma mensagem dizendo que não há registros retornados.