# Como validar um dado digitdo errado?

Tags: java, exceção

Como eu poderia criar uma exceção para caso o usuário digite alguma opção inválida, caia na `exception`, apareça uma mensagem de erro e mostre o menu novamente para o usuário.

Eu criei uma *flag* iniciando com `true`, logo depois fiz um `while` e um `try-catch`, quando não houver exceção irá ler a opção normalmente e *flag* vai ser `true`, se houver cai dentro do `catch` exibindo uma mensagem de erro, porém quando vou executar, ele mostra o menu só que em *loop* infinito.

[image: execução]

Peço que corrijam o código e me mostre:

```
public void Menu() {


            do {


                System.out.println("========= MENU ========\n"+
                "1)- Cadastrar livro\n"+
                "2)- Listar livro\n"+
                "3)- Pesquisar livro\n"+
                "4)- Excluir livro\n"+
                "5)- voltar\n"+
                "6)- sair\n"+
                "=======================\n"
                );

                System.out.println("Digite a opção desejada:");

                boolean flag=false;


                while(flag) {

                    try {
                        opc=inputNumerico.nextInt();
                        flag=true;

                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("Opção inválida, digite novamente");

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Não precisa criar uma nova pergunta com o mesmo conteúdo, caso não tenha sido solucionado, você pode criar comentários falando aonde encontrou dificuldades

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

Na minha opinião a apostila sugerida na outra resposta é um péssimo lugar para aprender, ela é uma das responsáveis por muita gente programar mal. Ensina de forma burocrática, sem estrutura e incentiva práticas ruins.

Este é um caso muito claramente que não deve existir exceção. Na verdade em Java há uma cultura de abuso de exceções, incluindo o uso delas para validação de dados e lançamentos de `Exception` indiscriminadamente quando deveria lançar algo mais específico.

Eu costumo dizer que [exceção é o mecanismo mais mal utilizado da programação hoje em dia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101) (agora depois do assincronismo). Exceção deve ser usada quando ela é o melhor recurso para aquele caso, e quase nunca é.

Não posso ajudar mais sem conhecer outros pontos do código. Nem sei de onde surgiu as variáveis deste código, me parece que elas deveriam ser locais, mas não tem como saber.

Note que eu capturei as exceções que o `nextInt()` pode lançar indicando que algo digitado não corresponde ao esperado. Nem sei se deveria capturar todas elas. E infelizmente é uma das coisas que o Java incentiva quando um erro desses deveria ser tratado com código de erro, já que não é uma situação excepcional. Mas [seria um erro capturar `Exception` porque aí até erros que não sejam digitação equivocada seriam tratados desta forma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101).

Algumas pessoas prefeririam colocar uma condição no `while`, como testar se `opc` é diferente de 6. Não vejo necessidade, acho que neste caso é mais elegante assim, embora uma lógica diferente poderia tornar a condição preferível.

```
public void Menu() {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("========= MENU ========\n"+
        "1)- Cadastrar livro\n"+
        "2)- Listar livro\n"+
        "3)- Pesquisar livro\n"+
        "4)- Excluir livro\n"+
        "5)- voltar\n"+
        "6)- sair\n"+
        "=======================\n"
        );
        System.out.println("Digite a opção desejada:");
        try {
            opc = inputNumerico.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException | NoSuchElementException | IllegalStateException e) {
            System.out.println("Digitação inválida, tente novamente");
        }
        switch (opc) {
            case 1:
                //faz aqui a chamada para o método de cadastrar
            case 2:
                //continua fazendo para cada opção
            case 6:
                return; //aqui sai do método
            default:
                System.out.println("Opção inválida, tente novamente");
        }
    }
}
```

Eu concordo com a outra resposta que deveria ler muito sobre o assunto, mas precisa entender profundamente sobre o assunto, ver várias visões, entender a mecânica da exceção, porque ela existe, onde ela é aplicada errada, coisa que quase ninguém faz, mesmo os usuários aqui no site que tem a oportunidade de ver tudo isso acabam ignorando  e continuam fazendo errado, porque parece ser o mais simples. Quando usada de forma correta a exceção é simples, quando usada de forma errada ela se torna complexa e aí como ninguém quer algo complexo usam de forma mais errada ainda para "simplificar".

Pesquise no site sobre o assunto. Tem até opiniões divergentes. Ou nem tanto, afinal é difícil argumentar que exceção deva ser um mecanismo preferencial para tratar validação de erros, o que pode existir é uma forma conveniente em certos cenários.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Validation.java).

Comment: Só adicionando que uma das formas de aumentar a performance do software é simplesmente tirar as exceptions, porque são muito custosas.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode lançar uma exceção utilizando um `throw`. Para que você aprimore seu conhecimento eu te aconselho a dar uma lida/pesquisada como funciona o tratamento de exceção um bom inicio é [aqui](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/excecoes-e-controle-de-erros/#11-2-exercicio-para-comecar-com-os-conceitos).

Para o seu problema você deve criar uma condicional para conter os casos que deseja e para lançar uma exceção quando a entrada do usuário não for desejada.Ou seja, quando o valor de `opc` não for justo, quando não for entre 1 a 6, você deve lançar uma exceção.

Exemplo de como lançar uma exceção:

- `throw new Exception();`

Mas te aconselho fortemente a ler mais sobre o assunto antes de continuar seu código, pois é um conceito que deve ter em mente. Assim como tipos de exceções para cada tipo de situação, pois é uma má pratica lançar uma exceção sem especifica-la.