# Valor nulo na soma

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-access, null, oledb

Estou com um problema na minha *query*, quando há valores na tabela a soma acontece normalmente como programado:

```
string nomeProd = item.SubItems[0].Text;
                double Quantidade = Convert.ToDouble(item.SubItems[2].Text);
                cmdQry.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(quantidadeMat) FROM tbl_EstoqueMat WHERE reservadoMat=False AND nomeMat=@nome";

                cmdQry.Parameters.Clear();
                cmdQry.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@nome", nomeProd));

                try
                {
                    //SOMA AQUI, OCORRE NORMALMENTE QUANDO HÁ DADOS NA TABELA
                    double soma = Convert.ToDouble(cmdQry.ExecuteScalar());
```

Quando não há dados na tabela, ou não estão disponíveis para soma, ocorre o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro de DBNull]

O valor é retornado nulo. Como lidar com esse tipo de problema?

Utilizo o OleDb, ou seja, Access e C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de tudo tem dois problemas no seu código. O primeiro é o [uso de `double`, isto não é adequado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). O segundo é que está convertendo algo que você não pode garantir que pode ser convertido, deveria ser algo assim:

```
if (!decimal.TryParse(item.SubItems[2].Text, out var quantidade)) //faz alguma coisa se deu erro e encerra a execução
```

Mas o problema específico é justamente o que está indicando na sua pergunta, há situação que o valor retornado é nulo, então você tem que trabalhar com essa opção e tratar esse valor adequado. O que você não deve fazer é deixar dar exceção e capturá-la para fazer alguma coisa. Quase toda captura de exceção em código está errada e é gambiarra de quem não quer consertar o erro em seu código.

Assim como eu consertei o problema acima verificado se deu dará tudo certo neste caso também teria que fazer algo parecido:

```
var resultado = cmdQry.ExecuteScalar();
if (resultado == DBNull.Value) //faz alguma coisa aqui para tratar o erro e encerra
var soma = ToDecimal(resultado);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/NullHandling.cs).

No caso eu coloquei um `using static System.Convert;` no começo do código.

Dessa forma só será feita a conversão se não for nulo.

Use uma regra: se não souber usar um mecanismo da linguagem como a exceção ou o tipo `double`, entre outros, não use. Quando você usa algo que não entende como funciona acaba entrando nesta situação:

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Comment: Ok, boa resposta, é o que eu estava procurando. Obrigado pelas dicas. E mais uma coisa: porque o uso de double é inadequado? Os valores no meu banco são double. Isso causa algum problema? E porque optar por decimal? Vejo muitos usando. Grato

Comment: Sim, causa, leia o *link* que eu postei. Inclusive não sei se deveria aceitar nulo na ciluna. E isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101 ou isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101.

Comment: Não há nulo na coluna, minha query filtra apenas dados especificados, e pode ocorrer de nenhum estar disponível, ou alguns estarem disponíveis. Muito obrigado pelas respostas e dicas, me ajudaram bastante!

Comment: Defina "não estar disponível"

Comment: Basicamente, é um sistema de estoque, e no caso do código, estou mexendo com o estoque de matérias primas. Quando uma ordem de produção é aberta, o sistema calcula a quantidade necessária de matéria prima e oferece a opção do usuário selecionar quais ele vai utilizar. Quando uma é selecionada ela é reservada, não sendo possível utilizá-la em outra produção devido aos processos de manuseio na fábrica. Esse código em que você me ajudou é para verificar a quantidade das matérias no estoque. Caso não haja disponibilidade não haverá produção ainda.

Comment: Você descreu seu software, mas não o que é "não estar disponível". Porque se isto for 0, então a soma deve ocorrer normalmente e seu problema é outro.

Comment: Não estar disponível significa que a matéria está sinalizada como "Reservada", ou seja, o código ignorará a matéria, que terá quantidade, seja "500" ou "5", mas o código não deve somar.

Comment: Entendi, aí nada entra na soma, aí dá nulo mesmo.

Comment: Mais uma coisa, agora a variável "resultado" está voltando vazia e não nula. Como devo lidar?

Comment: O que significa "vazia"?

Comment: Aqui diz que o valor é "{ }". Ao realizar o if da maneira que você colocou, ele simplesmente pula para o "else"

Comment: Eu não coloquei `else` algum. Precisa ver isso direito, porque ou você fez algo que não deveria ou então está acontecendo algo diferente do que deveria. Aí vou dizer que a pergunta não tem todos os dados que deveria. Esse dado não deveria acontecer em código correto.

Comment: Sim, você não colocou o `else`, mas o problema é que ele não lê o `resultado` como nulo. Ele não execute o `if` que você colocou.

Comment: Aí tem algo que falta na sua pergunta. Nela só mostra um erro de nulo.

Comment: Sim, mas o problema agora é outro. O seu `if` não funciona. O `resultado` não é retornado null, e a parte onde você coloca `var soma = ToDecimal(resultado);` não funciona, ele apresenta a mesma exceção, "Objeto não pode ser convertido de DBNull em outros tipos".

Comment: Experimenta trocar `null` para `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Está 100% agora.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o "catch" para tratar o erro recebido.

Ex:

```
            string nomeProd = item.SubItems[0].Text;
            double Quantidade = Convert.ToDouble(item.SubItems[2].Text);
            cmdQry.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(quantidadeMat) FROM tbl_EstoqueMat WHERE reservadoMat=False AND nomeMat=@nome";

            cmdQry.Parameters.Clear();
            cmdQry.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@nome", nomeProd));

            try
            {
                //SOMA AQUI, OCORRE NORMALMENTE QUANDO HÁ DADOS NA TABELA
                double soma = Convert.ToDouble(cmdQry.ExecuteScalar()); 

            }
            catch 
            {
              MessageBox.Show("O valor recebido é nulo");
            }
```

Comment: Isto não é correto, apesar de potencialmente funcionar.

Comment: Parabéns pela resposta, utilizarei para aprendizado @Maniero