# Ler campos em formato CSV com C#

Tags: c#, csv, console-application

Boas,
Estou neste momento a desenvolver uma applicação (console app) com o intuito de ler dados a partir de um ficheiro em formato CSV com o uso de C#.
Neste momento sou capaz de correr os campos todos sem qualquer tipo de problema e mostrar os dados todos.
De qualquer das formas estou com dificuldades em meter ler campos mais específicos a partir do ficheiro que podem ver na seguinte imagem.
[image: Ficheiro CSV]
Neste momento a minha intenção passa por fazer uma chamada a campos usando expressões condicionais.
Exemplos daquilo que pretendo que a applicação retorne incluí:
Todos os customers entre os 20 e 30 anos.
Todos os veículos registados antes de 1 de Janeiro de 2010.
Todos os veiculos com o enginesize de 1100.

Eis o código atual:

```
  public static void ReadRecord()

    {
      Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", readRecord ("1190", @"C:\CustomerInformation.csv", 9)));
       Console.ReadLine();
    }



    public static void addRecord(string CustomerID, string Forename, string DateOfBirth, string filepath)

    {
        try
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filepath, true))
            {
                file.WriteLine(CustomerID + ",                 " + Forename + ",                    " + DateOfBirth);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("This program did an oopsie :", ex);
        }
    }




    public static string[] readRecord(string searchTerm, string filepath, int positionOfSearchTerm)
    {
        positionOfSearchTerm--;
        string[] recordNotFound = { "Record not found" };

        try
        {
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@filepath);

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] fields = lines[i].Split(',');
                if (recordMatches(searchTerm, fields, positionOfSearchTerm))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Record found");
                    return fields;
                }

            }

            return recordNotFound;


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown Error");
            return recordNotFound;
            throw new ApplicationException("Unknown Error:", ex);
        }
    }

    public static bool recordMatches(string searchTerm, string[] record, int positionOfSearchTerm)

    {
        if (record[positionOfSearchTerm].Equals(searchTerm))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Atual Resultado
[image: resultado destacado em vermelho]

Naturalmente que a aplicação apenas retorna um simples valor, tenho procurado algumas técnicas e maneiras de poder voltar a retornar múltiplos valores, mas sem grande sucesso e apreciaria alguma ajuda se fosse possível.

Comment: Tem várias coisas pra melhorar aí, eu posso tentar escrever um exemplo pra você, mas precisaria de um modelo deste arquivo CSV, você consegue fazer upload de um com 10 linhas, no máximo?

Comment: Sim, claro. 
Podes sacar o ficheiro por aqui: https://gofile.io/?c=udpk4D
Agradecido pela ajuda.

Comment: Por favor, não altere sua pergunta para burlar o sistema. Assim você invalida minha resposta e, com isso, joga fora o esforço que tive para respondê-la. Tudo bem você remover o aceite, mas **não mude** o contexto da sua pergunta...

Comment: Peço desculpa, a intenção não era essa mas sim fazer a pergunta de uma forma que fosse mais compreensível de forma a evitar repetentes, uma vez que o objectivo de ambos os tópicos era o mesmo. 
Cumprimentos.

Comment: A resposta atendeu o que foi pedido? Precisa que seja adicionado mais algum detalhe?

Comment: Infelizmente não. O programa ficou longe dos standards que foram requeridos e não foi possível dispor os dados requeridos dentro da própria aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Tem algumas coisas pra arrumar no seu código e, de forma geral, a solução como um todo poderia ser um pouco melhor. Quando eu comecei a escrever a resposta pensei em propôr uma solução adaptada, mas isso mudaria muito seu código inicial e não sei se isso seria benéfico agora. Portanto, decidi apenas adaptar seu código original para atender o problema que você relata na sua publicação...

Alguns pontos que eu acho interessante citar antes de mostrar a solução:

- Não capture exceções se não for fazer algo útil com elas, se você precisa ao menos transcrever isso pra algum lugar (mesmo que seja uma caixa de mensagem) faça isso no ponto de entrada do código (no método `Main()` ou algum similar). Aqui no site tem algumas publicações que falam sobre isso, por exemplo:

  - [Melhor maneira de lidar com Exceptions](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13303/18246)
  - [Há algum inconveniente em sempre capturar Exception e não algo mais específico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/18246) - É Java, mas a ideia é a mesma
  - [É uma boa prática lançar exceção nesses casos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/18246)
  - [Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/18246)
- O retorno do método `Equals` é um `boolean`, então isso:

  ```cs
  if(record[positionOfSearchTerm].Equals(searchTerm)) 
      return true; 
  else 
      return false;
  ```

  é exatamente a mesma coisa que isto:

  ```cs
  return record[positionOfSearchTerm].Equals(searchTerm);
  ```

  e a segunda forma é muito mais enxuta e simples de ler;
- O método `readRecord` não deveria ser responsável pela mensagem "Record not found", isso deveria estar a cargo do método que o chama. Seria uma boa ideia se o `readRecord` apenas retornasse um conjunto vazio para o seu chamador quando não encontrar nenhum registro que atenda ao critério de busca;;
- Não é nenhuma uma regra, mas há uma [convenção de nomenclatura para C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions), talvez seja uma referência bacana para te guiar na escolha de nomes.

Pra resolver seu problema, você precisa:

1. Alterar a assintura do método `readRecord` para que seja possível retornar uma coleção de `string[]`;

   ```cs
   IEnumerable<string[]> ReadRecord(string searchTerm, string filepath, int positionOfSearchTerm)
   ```
2. Criar uma lista para adicionar todos os itens encontrados de acordo com o critério de busca;

   ```cs
   var retorno = new List<string[]>();
   ```
3. Ao invés de retornar o primeiro registro encontrado, adicioná-lo na lista criada;

   ```cs
   retorno.Add(fields);
   ```
4. Usar a lista como retorno do método.

Veja o método completo:

```cs
IEnumerable<string[]> ReadRecord(string searchTerm, string filepath, int positionOfSearchTerm)
{
    positionOfSearchTerm--;

    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filepath);

    var retorno = new List<string[]>(); // Lista para retornar todos itens encontrados
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] fields = lines[i].Split(',');
        if (recordMatches(searchTerm, fields, positionOfSearchTerm))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Record found");
            retorno.Add(fields); // Adicionar resultados na lista
        }
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

[Veja funcionando no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/ptso402594-codigo-original). O código também está [no GitHub](https://github.com/jfbueno/Stack-Overflow-Portugues).

Comment: Aproveito para agradecer a resposta.
De facto o uso de readRecord é provavelmente aquilo que mais problematico tem sido. De facto o a aplicação já consegue desta forma ler mais que uma linha, o que me leva ao segundo problema. 
Tendo em conta que a conta que pretendo o uso de operadores para fazer uma query por exemplo retorne uma resposta de um engineSize maior que 1100 existe alguma forma de se adaptar a este código?
Não me importo de reformular isto tudo uma vez que sei que existem certas limitações neste atual contexto e o programa é pequeno.

Comment: @Rui Eu não tenho certeza se entendi o que você quis dizer. Talvez seja um caso para [abrir uma nova pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) e explicar quais são problemas que pretende resolver... Aliás, se a resposta atendeu o contexto desta questão específica você pode marcá-la como correta usando o ✓ do lado esquerdo da publicação.

Comment: É simples, no ficheiro que foi enviado existe um campo chamado "EngineSize":
Atendendo à questão cada carro tem um tamanho relativamente ao motor.
E basicamente aquilo que gostava que o programa fizesse é que mostrasse os "Records" relativo aos carros que tem um motor igual ou maior que 1100. 
Um pouco à medida de como se faz no SQL.

Comment: @Rui Teria que adaptar bastante a solução. Como eu comentei, é o caso pra outra pergunta.