# Diferenças entre Parse() vs TryParse()

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, parse

- Existe diferença de performance entre os dois?
- Em quais situações se aplicam?
- Qual é o mais recomendado ser usado?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

De que métodos você está falando? Existem, na data que estou escrevendo esta resposta, 1383 métodos `Parse()` e 266 `TryParse()` apenas no [código fonte do .NET disponibilizado pela Microsoft](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) (Veja [também no GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet)). Claro que isto inclui todos os *overloads*.

## *Parse* de inteiros

Imagino que sejam dos métodos usados para converter uma *string* que provavelmente contém dígitos numéricos em valores numéricos de um determinado tipo. Embora existam implementações diferentes, elas são parecidas e vou me concentrar no `int.Parse` e o `int.TryParse`.

Formas de usar:

```
int value;
try {
    value = int.Parse("!123x6");
} catch(FormatException) {
    value = -1; //solução horrível mas serve para o exemplo
}
```

e

```
int value;
if (!int.TryParse("!123x6", out value)) {
    value = -1; //solução horrível mas serve para o exemplo
}
```

A segunda forma me parece mais limpa. E em C# 7 ainda pode ser mais curto:

```
if (!int.TryParse("!123x6", out var value)) {
    value = -1;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/TryParse.cs).

## Performance

Já lhe mostraram os comparativos de tempo. Mas isso não é tão importante. Lembre-se que otimização prematura não deve ser feita. Só se preocupe se existirem métricas que indiquem que um destes métodos está causando uma [lentidão prejudicial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5888/101). Mas por coincidência o mais rápido é o mais indicado, semanticamente falando.

#### Exceção X dado inválido

Você usa um destes métodos para converter um texto em número, se e somente se existir um número válido identificável pela rotina de *parse*. Se não for possível converter, isto é um **dado inválido**? Ou é uma **exceção na execução do programa**?

A resposta que você der vai determinar qual dos métodos usar. Tem que usar o que é semanticamente adequado antes de qualquer outro motivo, especialmente otimização.

Eu entendo e conheço diversos programadores experientes que entendem que na imensa maioria dos casos, o fato da conversão não ser possível indica a invalidade do texto analisado para o propósito requerido e uma invalidade de dado deve ser notificada ao programa de uma forma simples. Isto é uma informação que faz parte da "regra de negócio" e não do mecanismo de conversão. Na verdade eu não consigo ver um caso para usar o `Parse` que não esteja consertando o mecanismo errado. O `TryParse()` foi criado posteriormente porque foi identificado que o `Parse()` era o mecanismo errado.

#### Exceção degrada desempenho

A [excelente resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/150123/221800) mostra claramente que o desempenho do `Parse()` só consegue ser *comparável*, mas não melhor, se todos os dados analisados são válidos. Quanto mais dados inválidos no seu *roll*, pior fica o desempenho do `Parse()`. Até porque tratar exceções é um processo extremamente lento.

Você pode dizer que existem diversas exceções que podem ser lançadas durante o processo e você pode querer saber qual exceção é. Mas para que? O que você vai fazer com esta informação? Se o dado é inválido, você vai receber uma exceção `FormatException`. O que isto ajuda mais que um `true` ou `false`? Se for outra exceção, ela indica um erro de programação e não a invalidade do dado. Como você vai consertar um erro de programação? **Um `try-catch` não resolve problemas de programação**. Se alguém ainda acha que resolve, por favor, parem de fazer isto. Um problema de programação só deve ser manipulado antes de sair da aplicação, provavelmente fazendo um *log* e talvez melhorando a apresentação do erro para o usuário final, se o erro chegou em produção. Não dá para fazer mais nada!

#### Exceção não é fluxo normal

Ok, para tudo existe exceção (no sentido amplo da palavra, não o recurso técnico de programação), então pode existir um caso que dê para tratar, mas é raro. Geralmente quando acha um jeito de lidar com um erro de programação, provavelmente não deveria estar lidando com exceção (no sentido de `Exception`), deveria ter uma forma de interceptar isso pelo fluxo do programa. Tratamento de exceção não é fluxo normal. Tratamento de exceção deve ser feito com algo inesperado. Dado inválido é algo esperado, é algo que é normal acontecer e precisa ser tratado apropriadamente.

É preciso entender melhor como usar exceções. Trato deste assunto em outras respostas [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101) e mais amplamente [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101) (um bom lugar para começar navegar para várias outras respostas sobre o assunto).

## Pra que usar o `Parse()`?

Eu não consigo me imaginar usando o `Parse()` para nada. Mas não terei problema em usar quando perceber que ele vai ajudar algum caso específico. Talvez um caso que precise resolver um *corner case*, um *bug* do .NET, sei lá, mas em condições normais, não há porque usá-lo.

Se quiser tentar entender melhor os métodos, leia seus fontes (tem que ir navegando pelas chamadas para ver todos os caminhos, mas o UI do site ajuda): [`Parse()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs#a438016f815a35c3) e [`TryParse()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs#325507e509229dbc).

Como última nota, só não vá usar o `TryParse()` como [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16162/101). O retorno não é tratado. Se um dado estiver errado, você tem um erro de lógica invisível em seu programa. Claro que eu não sei se há garantias que o `TryParse()` nunca vá dar dado inválido com o conjunto de dados tratado ali. Mas não confiaria em nenhuma garantia. Computadores falham, humanos falham mais ainda. Neste caso um `Parse()` teria sido melhor porque pelo menos daria um erro de programação e quebraria a aplicação. Não é o ideal mas é melhor que aceitar dados inválidos (bom, taí um caso para o `Parse()`, você tem certeza que nunca falhará).

Answer (score 20):

`Parse` lança uma exceção se ele não pode analisar o valor, ao passo que `TryParse` retorna um valor *booleano* indicando se ele conseguiu.

`TryParse` não apenas é um `try/catch` internamente - o ponto principal é que ele é implementado sem exceções para que ele seja rápido. Na verdade, a forma como é mais provável é que é implementado internamente o método `Parse` chamará `TryParse` e, em seguida, lança uma exceção se ele retorna *false*.

Em poucas palavras, use `Parse`, se você tem certeza que o valor será válido. Caso contrário, use `TryParse`.

Se a *string* não pode ser convertida para um *inteiro*, então:

- `int.Parse()` irá lançar uma exceção.
- `int.TryParse()` retornará falso (*mas não lançará uma exceção*).

<sub>[**Fonte**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467613/parse-v-tryparse)</sub>

Answer (score 16):

O **Parse** lança uma *exceção* se ele não conseguir converter o valor, já o **TryParse** retorna um **bool** indicando se ele conseguiu ou não.

Exemplo:

```
int n = int.Parse(textBoxNumero.Text);
```

Para o código acima, imagine que o *textBoxNumero* receba *5*. O *parse* será feito e **n** será **5**.
Agora, se o *textBoxNumero* receber *abc* ele irá gerar uma exceção, que deverá ser tratada com **try-catch**.

```
int n = 0;
bool teste = int.TryParse(textBoxNumero.Text, out n);
```

Para o código acima, imagine que o *textBoxNumero* receba *5*. O *parse* será feito e **n** será **5** e **teste** será **true**.
Agora, se o *textBoxNumero* receber *abc*, **n** se manterá com o valor inicializado **0** e **teste** será **false** pois não conseguiu efetuar o Parse.

Sobre performance, o ideal é: use *Parse*, se você tem certeza que o valor poderá ser convertido da forma que deseja, pois é mais rápido; caso contrário, precise verificar se a conversão será possível, use *TryParse*.

Comment: Por que o `Parse` teria performance melhor?

Comment: Enquanto o Parse apenas faz a conversão da informação, o TryParse verifica se é possível converter para depois disso fazer a conversão. o TryParse nada mais é do que uma função que verifica se é possível efetuar a conversão e após caso possa, invoca o Parse.

Comment: Veja as demais respostas e os links para o SO. As evidências indicam que a performance do `TryParse` é melhor.

Answer (score 13):

A diferença, basicamente, é que `Parse` lança uma exceção, enquanto `TryParse` não.

No que se refere ao desempenho, `TryParse` é mais rápido que `Parse` pois não utiliza `try/catch`. Mas, dependendo de quantas vezes seu programa faz esse tipo de interpretação por segundo, isso pode não fazer a menor diferença no desempenho geral do seu programa (nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/150123/1623979) há um pequeno benchmark comparando os dois).

---

Há diferença clara também na forma como se utiliza as funções:

```
string str = "100a0";
int numero;

// algo do tipo
int resultado = int.TryParse(str, out numero) ? numero : 0;
```

Contra:

```
try
{
    int numero = Int32.Parse(str);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Parse Falhou");
}
```

Agora dizer qual é o melhor é um pouco complicado. Uma vantagem do `Parse` é que você (por meio da exceção) pode saber qual foi o tipo de erro que ocorreu durante a execução. Mas, tudo depende do contexto.

Answer (score 11):

Traduzido livremente [desta pergunta do Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467613/parse-v-tryparse):

> `Parse` dispara uma exceção se não conseguir converter o valor, enquanto `TryParse` retorna um `bool` indicando se obteve sucesso.
>
> `TryParse` não faz apenas um `try` / `catch` internamente - a ideia é que ele seja implementado sem exceções para ser rápido. Aliás, a maneira mais provável se estar implementado é com o método `Parse` tentando executar `TryParse` e disparar uma exceção se retornar `false`.
>
> Em resumo, use `Parse` se você tiver certeza que o valor será válido; caso contrário, use `TryParse`.

Answer (score 8):

Li todas as repostas, mas nenhuma fala especificamente sobre a performance deles.

Existe uma resposta [lá no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150114/parsing-performance-if-tryparse-try-catch/150123#150123) com uma tabela comparativa de tempos.

Existe também um [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20151215225344/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ianhu/archive/2005/12/19/505702.aspx) no blog do MSDN falando sobre isso, mas infelizmente as fotos não abriram aqui em casa.

Como experiência pessoal, posso acrescentar que `TryParse` sempre foi mais rápido que o `Parse`, assim como o `as` funciona um pouquinho mais rápido que um `type cast` convencional.

Answer (score 1):

`Parse` e `TryParse` são utilizados para converter uma String de números para um número inteiro e verificar se a conversão deu certo ou não.

Por exemplo: O usuário digita uma letra/caractere em um campo que deveria receber apenas números.

Se você utilizar o `TryParse` para verificar a informação digitada pelo usuário você elimina a necessidade de implementar um tratamento de exceção, porque o `TryParse` dará como resposta `true` para quando a conversão for realizada com sucesso e `false` para quando não for possível converter.

Porém, você tem como resposta apenas `true` e `false`, então limita o seu entendimento do que realmente ocorreu, o que o usuário digitou no campo.

Se você utilizar o `Parse` e o usuário digitar um letra/caractere no campo que deveria aceitar apenas números ocorrerá um "erro", porém você pode implementar um controle de exceções para entender o que realmente ocorreu, podendo ser:

1. Null;
2. OverFlow (Usuário digitou um dado que está fora da faixa dos
   números inteiros);
3. Exceção (Não sendo um formato válido).

Se existe a necessidade de entender o motivo do erro com base no que o usuário digitou, utilize o `Parse` com a implementação da tratativa do erro.

Se você quer saber apenas se deu certo a conversão ou não deu certo e se não existe necessidade de compreender exatamente o motivo do erro (null, overflow ou exceção), use `TryParse`.