# Como armazenar valor decimal?

Tags: c#, .net, formatação, decimal

Estou tentando pegar um valor de um textbox digitado com ponto, e salvar o mesmo com ponto em decimal, se digitarem 10.80, é para armazenar 10.8 na minha variável.

Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
decimal valorTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(hfValor.Value.Replace(".", "").Replace(",", "."), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Porém, ele ta salvando tudo junto sem o ponto.

Comment: Você não quis dizer "se digitarem 10,80 é para armazenar 10.8"? Porque de acordo com seu código, você está explicitamente removendo o "." digitado, logo o número do exemplo fica 1080.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var textBoxValor = "10.8";
decimal variavel = Decimal.Parse(textBoxValor.Replace(".", ","));
```

Deve tratar para ter apenas um ponto decimal seja ele ponto (.) ou virgula (,)

**Atenção** também quanto ao idioma, caso o idioma seja diferente de pt-BR o resultado pode ser diferente.

Comment: Deu certo, vlw...

Comment: Se alguém estiver com o mesmo problema, a única coisa que funcionou pra mim foi: <input type="number"  step="0.01">

Answer (score 3):

Não faça gambiarras e/ou coisas ineficientes, o caminho do AP estava na direção certa, apesar de ainda com erro, as respostas postadas não, apesar de funcionar, em certas situações, a forma correta de converter isso é usando o que o .NET já faz bem e está pronto para uso, usando a cultura:

```
using static System.Globalization.CultureInfo;

if (!decimal.TryParse("10.80", InvariantCulture, out var valor)) return;
System.Console.Write(valor);
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WfQa0P). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Decimal/Parse.cs).

Eu usei um valor fixo para testar mais fácil, mas como disse que é algo digitado e pode dar erro o certo é usar o [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

Answer (score 0):

Faça a formatação do valor:

```
string valor = "10.80";
string valorFormatado = double.Parse(valor).ToString("n1");
```

Retorna: **10.8**

Referência: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)