# Formatar uma string de CPF?

Tags: c#, .net, string, windows-phone

Estou com um problema, em um app o usuário digita o CPF, mas somente os números porque é muito complicado criar máscara no Windows Phone, e esse CPF será 'desenhado' em uma imagem de um cartão, e para ficar mais agradável eu preciso desenhá-lo com seu formato normal, com pontos e traço.

Então como transformo uma `string`:

```
xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Em:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx-xx
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Não conheço windows phone, mas em c# puro seria assim:

```
public string teste(string cpf)
        {
            return Convert.ToUInt64(cpf).ToString(@"000\.000\.000\-00");
        }
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, já estava pensando que ia ter que ficar cortando a string etc kk Valeu

Comment: Ok, ainda bem que funcionou. Minha preocupação seria o windows phone, se aceitaria esse tipo de máscara ou não.

Comment: Olá, Sabe porque fica aparencendo um 0 na frente dos cpf's ?
tipo 12345678910 fica 0123.456.789-10

Comment: Solução perfeita!

Answer (score 4):

```
public string teste(string cpf)
{
    return Convert.ToUInt64(cpf).ToString(@"000\.000\.000\-00");
}
```

Essa solução não funciona para quem tem o CPF iniciado com 2 zeros.
Para resolver esse problema, pode utilizar esse método:

```
//000.000.000-00
public string FormatCPF(string sender)
{
    string response = sender.Trim();
    if (response.Length == 11)
    {
        response = response.Insert(9, "-");
        response = response.Insert(6, ".");
        response = response.Insert(3, ".");
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Ué, eu testei com um CPF iniciado por 0 e mesmo assim funcionou, qual foi o CPF que tu testou que tava dando errado?

Comment: O problema é quando é iniciado com 2 zeros

Answer (score 4):

Estou respondendo porque a resposta aceita e mais votada não faz o menor sentido e está errada! Se tem uma `string` e quer continuar com ela, não deve converter para número. Jamais use uma solução assim. Ainda mais que não funciona em todas as situações, como demonstrado em outra resposta. A solução seguinte é complexa e ineficiente por fazer 4 alocações de memória. E a outra com positivos não faz o que a pergunta pede. Não tem por que usá-las, mesmo que funcione.

O caminho aí é o simples, sem inventar, só colocar da forma mais direta possível os caracteres desejados nos lugares desejados:

```
using static System.Console;

WriteLine(FormatarCpf("12345678901"));
WriteLine(FormatarCpf("00123456789"));
string FormatarCpf(string cpf) => cpf.Substring(0, 3) + "." + cpf.Substring(3, 3) + "." + cpf.Substring(6, 3) + "-" + cpf.Substring(9, 2);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CjfTeS). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U403CO). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/FormatCpf.cs).

Obviamente que precisa ter o tamanho certo e os dados estarem validados. Se for possível que o dado tenha sido entrado sem zeros no começo por alguma razão (apesar disto ser inválido) então precisaria primeiro fazer `cpf = cpf.PadLeft(11, '0');` ([documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=net-7.0)), apesar de não ser uma solução tão eficiente, o mais correto seria verificar o tamanho e mudar o primeiro [`Substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para pegar menos caracteres e adicionar a quantidade de zeros necessária. Não vou fazer o código porque nem deveria vir assim, e o ineficiente pode não ser tão problemático assim, mas é uma alocação desnecessária.

Verificar se o tamanho é 11 é uma validação. Esta função tem que formatar e validar ao mesmo tempo? Vai ferir o [SRP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101)? Se está inválido não deve formatar? E não vai avisar que não formatou por isso? Até pode fazer para ter que avisar, é assim o que faz o [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) por exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void txtCNPJ_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox t = sender as ComboBox; // ou text Box
            if (e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 57)
            {
                t.SelectionStart = t.Text.Length + 1;

                if (t.Text.Length == 2 || t.Text.Length == 6)
                    t.Text += ".";
                else if (t.Text.Length == 10)
                    t.Text += "/";
                else if (t.Text.Length == 15)
                    t.Text += "-";
                t.SelectionStart = t.Text.Length + 1;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
private void maskedTextBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // pode se usar codigo formata ou digitar diretamente na control maskTextBox so remover aspas e @
    maskedTextBox1.Mask = @"000\.000\.000\-00";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Criar string em branco
    string Salvarmask = "";

    //usar controle para gerar string
    Salvarmask = maskedTextBox1.Text;

    //para visualizar exemplo string Formatada
    label1.Text = Salvarmask.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Olá Marcio, poderia fornecer um exemplo de como fazer isso com a tal string que o autor citou? Lembre-se, ele falou "string", é ela quem precisa ser mascarada. Recomendo [edit] a resposta e fornecer um exemplo de como fazer para editar a tal mascara.

Comment: Os codigos não é para windows Phone e C# e somente exemplo