# O que é e como se usa o SRP?

Tags: design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, princípios-de-programação

Sei que SRP significa *Princípio da Responsabilidade Única*. Cada classe deve ser responsável por tal coisa.

- O que devo fazer pra detectar que estou violando o SRP?
- O que devo levar em consideração para aplicá-lo corretamente (uso com moderação)?

Uma dúvida de como exemplo:

Estou desenvolvendo o *framework*. Na parte referente à biblioteca da `view`, sempre considero esses fatores:

- carrega um arquivo para view;
- carrega os dados da view;
- possibilidade de estender essa view;
- possibilidade de criar blocos para a view;

Em cada um desses casos, devo me preocupar em criar uma classe que faça o que é pretendido (`View`, `ViewBlocks`, `ViewData`, `ViewTemplate`), ou "jogo tudo" na classe `View`.

Se considerar "jogar tudo" na classe `View`, estaria violando o SRP?

Comment: Só não vou botar outra recompensa porque tem resposta minha e também acho que não adiantaria, não sei porque essa não fez sucesso. É algo muito importante e geral, tem todos os requisitos pra ser daquelas populares.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Introdução

Ele é um **princípio** a ser seguido e não um padrão de projeto. Então aí já mostra que é difícil definir uma linha onde eles estão sendo usados corretamente ou não. A minha experiência indica que só a experiência qualificada (e não apenas quantificada) ajuda a desenvolver capacidade de definir essa linha.

A qualificação tem a ver com a quantidade e tipos de projetos que se desenvolveu, as pessoas que estavam participando, a dinâmica deles, a atitude individual da pessoa com relação ao aprendizado e evolução do seu conhecimento. E é claro que a capacidade de entendimento de problemas e de abstração é importante também. Não adianta decorar como usar ferramentas ou como codificar. Tem que ser capaz de interpretar problemas, que é algo mais difícil que interpretar textos e que é algo deficiente na maioria das pessoas. Não basta saber usar a ferramenta, tem que saber o que fazer com ela. E isso não é ensinado em livros.

## Definição

O princípio indica que um componente da aplicação deve ser responsável por apenas uma tarefa. Ter só uma funcionalidade. Ele tem a ver com [coesão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101).

Algumas pessoas consideram que isso está relacionado com OOP, mas é algo geral e que é aplicado há décadas. Havia um uso menor no passado porque sua aplicação atrapalhava um pouco a performance, o que era muito importante na época, hoje não pesa mais e muitas vezes é possível otimizar para nem ter a ínfima influência que esse princípio causa quando quebra tudo em partes menores.

## Como usá-lo

A segredo é definir o que é funcionalidade única. Se você exagerar terá uma função executando uma instrução do seu código mais ou menos equivalente à uma instrução de processador, porque esta é a responsabilidade mais única. Se não aplicar o princípio pode ter uma "linguição" que faz várias coisas.

Bom, claro que o último caso só as pessoas que sabem nada sobre o assunto ou muito teimosas escrevem algo assim (já tivemos uma pergunta aqui com uma função de 35 mil linhas). É comum elas terem dificuldade em ver tudo o que poderia.

Isso pode ser facilmente percebido aqui no SOpt nos códigos que as pessoas postam. Em geral a pessoa não consegue estruturar o que é uma classe e quais devem ser os métodos e funções, e ainda pior, o que deve ter em cada um. Fica até difícil prover o melhor encapsulamento e outras técnicas que ajudam o bom *design* da aplicação.

Mas devemos pensar em nível arquitetural também, não só de código.

Quando a pessoa descobre o princípio e o acha sensacional ela se deslumbra e começa quebrar em muitas partes pequenas demais.

A necessidade de mudança futura determina muito o que deve ser quebrado. E, na maioria das situações, não é fácil definir isso antecipadamente. A não ser que o programador já tenha experiência prévia com um problema exatamente igual. Dominar o domínio (*pun unintended* ?!? :) ) é requisito para atingir o SRP em sua plenitude. O que é raro acontecer.

O princípio tem muito a ver com administração das mudanças. Se fosse possível fazer um software que nunca precisasse de mudança (nem durante o desenvolvimento inicial) não seria necessário o SRP. Mas isso virtualmente não existe (*scripts* simples são exceções). Estamos falando de **manutibilidade**. Uma mudança deveria ter que mudar apenas um componente da aplicação. Quanto mais granulamos o que é a mudança menor deve ser este componente.

Juntar coisas arbitrariamente ferem o SRP? Até fere, mas nem sempre causa problemas. Isso ocorre muito em classes cujos membros sejam todos estáticos. Claro que o ideal é não ter agrupamento tão arbitrário assim, mas é estúpido alguém achar que não pode ter todas as principais funções matemáticas juntas em uma classe chamada `Math`. Acredite algumas pessoas acham isso porque elas decoram a regra e não olham o contexto e praticidade. Então concluímos que **decidir a granularidade é subjetivo**.

## Outros princípios que ajudam

Ele tem a ver com [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) também. Se você quebra bem as partes fica mais fácil fazer DRY. Imagine como é difícil ter uma informação (uma estrutura de dados, um algoritmo) [canônica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260464/101) quando ela carrega mais do que deve. Imagine o que aconteceria se tiver que mudá-la em algum lugar e aquilo causa um problema generalizado porque parte do que tinha junto com ela não casa mais com a mudança feita em uma parte. Sem adotar SRP o [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) fica prejudicado. E esse é o princípio mais importante para facilitar a manutenção (na minha opinião).

O quanto você precisa de flexibilidade? Vamos supor que você tenha um cálculo de imposto que existem vários passos para executar. Cada passo precisa estar em um método diferente? Em uma classe diferente? Depende do problema. Se aplicar o princípio cegamente, incorre no problema descrito no [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). Precisa ver se há necessidade real de que cada passo seja mudado independentemente.

Mas nem sempre esse é um bom critério. MVC é algo que reduz a responsabilidade e aumenta o esforço para dar manutenção (a maioria das mudanças em um modelo deve obrigar pelo menos uma mudança na visão). Aí para evitar esse problema tem que pensar em outras formas de desenvolvimento não tão óbvias para a maioria das pessoas. Outras até sabem como resolver porque aprenderam alguma receita de bolo.

Fragmentação pode atrapalhar, não só em ter que mudar em mais de um lugar, mas também ter coisas espalhadas demais. Claro que existem técnicas onde você pode fragmentar para ter tudo granular quando precisa e adicionalmente pode criar "combos" prontos para ter as coisas mais prontas mais à mão quando isso se faz necessário.

Obviamente que componentes que juntam coisas para facilitar o uso comum podem violar o SRP. E se não é necessária é ruim.

Estudar outros princípios como os citados aqui ajuda. Outro que ajuda é o [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) (sim o SRP está dentro dele, mas os outros pontos ajudam organizar desta forma). Só deve usar sem exageros.

Nunca se esqueça do YAGNI e do [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Estude [*code smells*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), [*anti-patterns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

## Técnicas que ajudam

Dar bons nomes para o que está fazendo ajuda **muito** a adotar o SRP corretamente. A maioria das pessoas têm dificuldade com isto. Se o nome for correto, ele indica o que deve fazer. Mas muitas vezes só conseguimos dar bons nomes quando sabemos bem o que aquilo faz, o que torna um paradoxo :)

> Existem apenas duas coisas difíceis em computação: invalidação de cache e nomear coisas.
>
> -- Phil Karlton

Se está difícil dar um nome é porque deve fazer mais do que uma coisa. Repense!

Olhar para o tamanho das coisas ajuda nada. Isso é um equívoco comum. O que tem que ser grande pode ser grande desde que exista um motivo para ser assim. Olha os *widgets* de uma GUI, são monstruosos.

Coleta de requisitos adequadamente é outra tarefa que as pessoas não dominam bem. E ela é fundamental. Se você não sabe **fazer as perguntas certas, interpretar as respostas, preencher as lacunas de informação que não consegue obter através de leigos da computação e juntar tudo de forma organizada** não consegue arquitetar a aplicação, não consegue definir bons nomes, não consegue fazer o SRP no nível correto.

Por isso vou repetir que **aprender codificar é a ponta do *iceberg***. Desenvolver software é resolver problemas, não é codificar. Por isso essa atividade é considerada por muitos como **engenharia** ou **arquitetura**. É um pouco **ciência**, um pouco **arte**. Ou como alguns gostam, é como **jardinagem** ou **gastronomia**. Nem conseguimos definir bem o que é :)

## Exemplo da pergunta

As respostas para o exemplo citado na pergunta só podem ser dadas com uma profunda análise do caso concreto, com todos os requisitos bem coletados. Isso só o AP tem. Obviamente pedir *code review* em casos concretos pode ajudar ganhar experiência.

## Perguntas que podem ajudar:

- A quebra vai tornar o [código mais reusável](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse) em diversas circunstâncias sem causar efeitos colaterais?
- Será mais fácil de ler o código e entender o que ele faz?
- O código poderá ser estendido facilmente?
- Ele está sendo representado de forma canônica?
- Pode ser testado independentemente?
- As informações ali contidas estão diretamente relacionadas?
- Algumas estão relacionadas demais e juntas fazem parte de outra entidade?
- Será intuitivo usar desta forma dentro dos requisitos? Como será usado?
- Será usado em quantos lugares? Isso pode ser garantido?

## Exemplos

O padrão MVC é um exemplo de caminho indutivo de SRP. Ele tenta fazer com que fique claro o modelo de dados que vai se usar (M), a maneira de apresentar estes dados (V) e como operacionalizar isso (C). Antes era comum ter um único componente que fazia tudo isso e era difícil mudar uma das partes.

Mas para demonstrar como pode ser polêmico o que é SRP ou não, o MVC parecia que quebrava as partes muito bem nesse nível arquitetural. Mas algumas pessoas discordaram e criaram não só outros modelos semelhantes mas também modelos que quebravam em mais partes, por exemplo o [MVVM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/101).

É certo que apresentação e modelo não deveriam estar juntos, mas a maioria das aplicações que vemos por aí são assim, e muitas vezes acaba funcionando.

O exemplo mais óbvio de abuso seria criar uma função onde soma dois números, existe algo pronto que faz isto.

Mas não quer dizer que nunca deva fazer assim. Por exemplo: se a função não declarar que é uma soma e isto é apenas um detalhe de implementação, então ok. Pode ser que um dia não seja uma soma simples mais, ou os tipos podem mudar, ou seja, os detalhes mudam apesar da [API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101) permanecer a mesma.

Outro exemplo onde se usa algo muito simples seria um método que apenas pega um [campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101) da classe. Muitas vezes o nome do método é mais longo que chamar o próprio campo. Parece um exagero, certo? Depende. Se o método cria uma melhor abstração pode ser interessante. Ou seja, você sabe que pra frente será outro campo a retornar ou que o campo precisará ser manipulado antes de retornar. Quebrar coisas muito simples provê melhor abstração e melhor documentação do que é aquilo. Dar nomes para certas ações ajuda muito a legibilidade de código.

Regras de negócio devem estar juntas com a persistência do dado? São duas coisas diferentes. Parece óbvio que devem, certo? É, mas muitas pessoas não fazem isso e se dão muito bem. Diminui a complexidade. É claro que não se aplica a todos os casos. Aí começamos questionar se todas as regras devem estar juntas. Ou será que só as que relacionam duas ou mais partes da entidade? Ou será que elas devem estar agrupadas por algum critério? Difícil dizer.

Note que o fato de uma classe fazer ambos não é ruim por si só. Talvez seja ruim que a implementação de tudo esteja dentro dessa classe. Saber o que é abstrato e o que é concreto ajuda definir a responsabilidade. Muitas vezes esquecemos disso. Uma interface tem uma responsabilidade abstrata. E quase sempre as pessoas acertam :) Então parece que o concreto é mais complicado definir.

Separar mecanismo e regras de negócio é importante, mas até quanto? Que preço vai pagar por isso? Quais partes separar? Onde acoplá-las?

## Conclusão

O fato é que em qualquer *design* existirão pessoas que dirão que deve ser feito de um jeito e outras que deve ser feito de outro. No fundo é algo "quase arbitrário". Com algum critério, claro, mas não deixa de ser algo que cada um terá seu jeito de fazer. E explicações em casos específicos e concretos podem convencer alguém se está certo ou não.

## Referências

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Não gosto muito do artigo, ele é limitante e segue uma fonte, *marketeira*.

[Termo que também deve ser estudado junto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

[Estudo sobre o assunto](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc838p/Design/criteria.pdf).

[Visão alternativa para a definição do Uncle Bob](https://sklivvz.com/posts/i-dont-love-the-single-responsibility-principle) que realmente é um pouco tosca.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Resumindo, deve-se saber o que se quer para fazer funcionar. Foi realmente uma boa abordagem, apesar de longa, como já seria de esperar.

Comment: Se não for longa (e acho q ficará mais :) ) não responde nada. Só chove no molhado. Ainda q eu ache q a resposta tb faz um pouco isto. Pelo menos p/ quem já entende um pouco disto. Resposta curta é boa para seguidores de receitas. Mas neste caso não tem receita. É aqui que diferencia o cozinheiro do chef.

Comment: Com base nessa parte que adicionaste, mais do que verdade não poderia ser, isso de convencer as pessoas de que um, e apenas um jeito é o certo. Uma solução simples para isso, é conhecer as diferentes implementações, de modo a criar uma opinião própria.

Answer (score 13):

## O que é SRP?

O **Single Responsibility Principle** (*"SRP"* ou *"Princípio da Responsabilidade Única"*), determina que cada componente do sistema deve ter apenas uma única responsabilidade.

Trazendo para a Orientação a Objetos (já que você falou em classe), dizemos que cada classe ou objeto deve ter uma única responsabilidade.

## O que devo fazer pra detectar que estou violando o SRP?

> Se uma classe tem uma única responsabilidade, ela tem um único motivo para mudar.

Se você precisa mexer numa classe pelos mais variados motivos (o que ocorre por exemplo [neste tipo de "classe utilitária"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90076/14584)), você está violando o princípio.

Digamos por exemplo que você não separa os conceitos do seu sistema, e faz regras de negócio, apresentação, interface e persistência na mesma classe, então:

- Quando o tamanho de um campo muda, você mexe nesta classe.
- Quando o nome de uma coluna de banco de dados muda, você mexe nesta classe.
- Quando um cálculo de negócio muda, você mexe nesta classe.
- Quando **outro** cálculo de negócio muda, você mexe nesta **mesma classe**.

Ora, esta classe tem bem mais de um motivo para mudar, então ela está violando o SRP.

## O que devo levar em consideração para aplicá-lo corretamente?

> A parte mais difícil é identificar o que é uma única responsabilidade.

Se eu fizer um sistema inteiro de controle de estoque em uma única classe e alguém me perguntar qual é a responsabilidade desta classe, eu vou dizer: *"a responsabilidade desta classe é controlar o estoque, e mudanças no controle de estoque é o único motivo que pode exigir mudança na classe"*, e pode ser difícil provar que estou errado.

Para identificar se uma classe tem mais de um motivo para mudar podemos observar a mecânica de solução do problema: **o fluxo de trabalho, as atividades ou tarefas e entidades envolvidas**.

Neste meu primeiro exemplo está fácil: para controlar o estoque eu preciso fazer inventário, registrar entrada e saída de produtos, registrar perdas, emitir relatórios, imprimir documentos, etc.

Se uma única classe tem todas estas responsabilidades, ela precisará mudar por exemplo quando houver uma mudança de requisito no inventário e também quando houver uma mudança de requisito na saída de produtos - parece bastante claro que são dois motivos distintos de mudança.

Mas o SRP é mais útil se for respeitado também em um nível muito mais baixo.

Por exemplo, uma vez eu precisei fazer um componente para exportar para arquivo texto uma mensagem recebida de uma fila de mensagens; esta mensagem vinha na forma de um objeto.

Exportar um objeto para arquivo é uma única responsabilidade? Parece que sim, então eu comecei desenhando a classe:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu comecei a escrever a exportação, observei que havia duas tarefas envolvidas: formatar os atributos no texto e salvar este texto para arquivo, e decidi separar estas tarefas em classes distintas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora eu tinha uma classe especializada em cada tarefa, e uma outra classe coordenando o trabalho, e entreguei a solução.

Pouco tempo depois, veio o requisito de formatar a mensagem de maneira ligeiramente diferente, e apenas a classe *FormatadorMensagem* precisou mudar, as outras duas não foram tocadas.

Mais tarde, veio o requisito de ter mais uma opção de formatação, mantendo ativa também a formatação anterior (seria usada ora uma formatação e ora outra). Então eu criei mais uma classe de formatação e apenas a *ExportadorMensagem* precisou ser alterada para escolher o formatador conforme a ocasião; as outras duas classes não foram tocadas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredite ou não, depois veio a necessidade de em vez de simplesmente salvar para arquivo o texto formatado, o arquivo deveria também ser enviado através da rede usando uma aplicação especializada; e então apenas a classe *ExportadorArquivo* precisou ser alterada, as outras classes não foram tocadas.

Até o fim dessa história, cada uma das classes envolvidas na exportação da mensagem teve apenas um único motivo para mudar, o que confere a cada uma a medalha de compliance com o SRP :D

É claro que esta medalha pode ser revogada a qualquer momento.

## Jogar tudo na mesma classe seria violar o SRP?

Sim, com certeza.

Se você já percebeu mais de uma responsabilidade e ainda assim implementou tudo na mesma classe, você deliberadamente violou o SRP.

A questão é: **quando violar o SRP é um problema?**

Como eu disse lá no começo, uma classe viola o SRP quando ela tem mais de um motivo para mudar.

> E se a classe, mesmo que tenha mais de uma responsabilidade, nunca precise mudar?

Então você não cometeu nenhum pecado e talvez tenha poupado trabalho.

No meu exemplo do exportador de mensagem, se eu tivesse começado com uma única classe e tivesse esperado até a primeira mudança de requisito para daí quebrar as classes, desde que esta única classe estivesse bem escrita, eu acredito que eu teria ficado ficado bem.

## Conclusão

Não separamos responsabilidades apenas porque é bonito ou porque estamos esperando determinadas mudanças.

Separamos responsabilidades porque, pelas características do projeto, sabemos que as mudanças fatalmente virão (nunca as mudanças previstas, sempre outras) e preferimos ter um design que facilite implementar estas mudanças.

Answer (score 6):

(Tradução de parte [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34755541/2241463) - aceito feedback sobre a tradução).

### Princípio da Responsabilidade Única

Jogue fora o que quer que você acredite que supõe que esse princípio significa.

Robert C. Martin define este princípio oficialmente como:

> Uma classe deve ter somente uma razão para mudar

A maior parte das pessoas definindo SRP está enganada. O SRP é tipicamente mal explicado como:

"A classe `Empregado` não deve ter `AtualizarDadosDemograficos()` e `EnviarMensagem()`, isso conta como duas responsabilidades... coloque `EnviarMensagem()` em uma classe `Mensagem`!!"

**^^ Errado**

**vv Certo**

Robert C. Martin disse

> "Uma responsabilidade não é 'algo que o código faz'". (NDC [Norwegian Developers Conference] 2012)

Robert C. Martin define SRP como:

> "Qualquer módulo deve ser responsável para com somente **uma pessoa**-[papel]." (NDC 2012)

Quando uma **Parte interessada** pede uma mudança na ordenação de dados na View, a gerência não deve se assustar e ficar preocupada que possa quebrar os algoritmos.  Isso porque **O módulo que trata da Ordenação na View só deve responsabilidade à Parte interessada**, e **O módulo que trata do algoritmo de cálculo do total somente deve responsabilidade ao analista de negócio.**  Então quando o Analista de Negócio pede para mudar o algoritmo, não devemos temer que a View possa mudar.

Portanto, qualquer mudança em **Um módulo** (singular) só deve ocorrer por uma razão: a Única Pessoa-**Papel** a quem este módulo serve solicitou uma mudança.

(**N.T.:** De onde se percebe que em português há um problema de tradução, em que o foco da palavra responsabilidade não deve ser *"qual é a responsabilidade" [responsible for]* mas *"a quem se deve responsabilidade" [responsible to]*).

**Suportam essa definição:**

[Robert C. Martin - "Who is the program responsible to?"](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html)

["[Existe uma] confusão generalizada [sobre o assunto]" - resposta da pergunta "What is the real responsibility of a class?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220292/93338)

[Resposta da pergunta "How do you determine how coarse or fine-grained a 'responsibility' should be when using the single responsibility principle?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2463221/2241463)

[Resposta da pergunta "Clarify the Single Responsibility Principle"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/17170/93338)

[Aqui](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/403351/93338) também trata da questão do inglês.