# Método com muitos if e return

Tags: c#

Acho que meu código está muito poluído com um monte de if.

```
[ValidateModelAttribute]
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody]UserDto model)
{
    try
    {
        if (model == null || model.Id != id)
            return BadRequest();
        var originalUser = context.User.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (originalUser == null)
            return NotFound();
        var updatedUser = model.MapTo<User>();
        var userBd = context.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Login == updatedUser.Login && x.Id != updatedUser.Id);
        if (userBd != null)
            return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict, userBd);
        context.Entry(originalUser).Context.Update(updatedUser);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return Ok(updatedUser);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Existe alguma forma mais elegante?

Comment: Exceto pelo abuso de exceção, mas que para fazer certo provavelmente você vai gostar menos, não vejo problemas, o que você vê de problema.

Comment: Vejo uma certa poluição no código... Olhando rapidamente não consigo dizer o que ele está fazendo. Isso não é um problema?

Comment: É, se você escreveu e não sabe o que faz, realmente pode ser. Separe em vários métodos então. Dê bons nomes para eles. Leia isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101

Comment: E o abuso de exceção, tem alguma pergunta sobre isto por aq?

Comment: Só eu respondi várias: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a101%20%5bexce%c3%a7%c3%a3o%5d. Nesse caso você está capturar qualquer problema que possa ocorrer no código, e podem ser muitos (um dos problemas da exceção é justamente não ter controle sobre tudo o que pode ocorrer) e está transformando em uma exceção que tem um significado específico. As duas coisas são abusos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- O nome `Put` não revela o que o método faz, então você poderia escrever todo o código em um novo método com um nome expressivo e chamar este novo método dentro do *Put*. Só por ter um **nome de método expressivo** você já deve notar uma melhora no código.
- Se for difícil encontrar um nome de método que revele exatamente a intenção deste bloco de código, então **o método pode estar fazendo coisas demais**, e daí você quebra o código em novos métodos - cada método precisa ter um nome revelador, e o código não deve fazer nada mais nada menos do que o indicado por seu nome.
- Você precisa mesmo transformar em *BadRequest* qualquer exceção que venha a ocorrer? Acredito que o ideal aí era **remover este tratamento de exceção**. Uma exceção não prevista aí deveria simplesmente quebrar o sistema. Um tratamento genérico de exceção, fora deste bloco código, poderia mostrar ao usuário uma mensagem genérica e registrar em log a exceção real. Uma mensagem real de uma exceção não prevista pode até revelar ao usuário mais do que você gostaria sobre a arquitetura do seu sistema.
- *"Olhando rapidamente não consigo dizer o que o código está fazendo"*. Uma parte dste problema deve ser resolvido com um bom nome de método. O nome do método deve dizer **o quê**. Já o **como** é outra parte do problema e pode ser resolvido com uma mudança de conceito: **você não tem que entender como um código funciona olhando rapidamente!** Código fonte é para ser lido - não é um desenho, é um texto.

> Esteja disposto a ler um código com dedicação, como se fosse uma redação, como se ele contasse uma história, porque é assim que ele deve ser escrito, contando uma história.

Deve ser escrito de maneira muito sucinta e evitando os detalhes técnicos que não dizem respeito à história, deve evitar desviar da história principal, deve ser curto se possível, e ainda assim deve contar uma história.

Comment: O melhor seria eu criar uma classe de Business para ter esses métodos?