# Um model de usuário deve ter todas as ações que o envolvem?

Tags: mvc, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software

Sempre que pesquiso vejo que no MVC devemos separar bem os *models* para que fique mais organizado e fácil de um próximo desenvolvedor entender o sistema.

Tenho as ações básicas como *login*, registro, *logout*. Seria correto, no padrão MVC, condensar todos estes em um *model* `User`? ou deveria separar as ações em seus respectivos *models*?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Isso não tem a ver com MVC e sim com modularização ou organização do projeto com um todo independente de ser MVC ou não. Tem até a ver com orientação a objeto.

Facilitar a manutenção é algo um pouco subjetivo.

Em geral podemos dizer que se separar tudo fica mais fácil dar manutenção, fica mais [coeso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) e mantém o [princípio da responsabilidade única.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101)

Por outro lado o código fica maior, precisa de mais elementos para unir tudo isso junto, e muitas vezes a manutenção não se beneficiará de toda essa separação.

É curioso que a orientação a objeto clássica diz que tudo referente ao objeto deve estar junto dele. Mas o que fazem na prática é o oposto disso e separa-se tudo o que não for estritamente necessário para aquele objeto.

Ninguém pode dizer o que é melhor para o seu caso, até porque ele não está bem definido. Sem boas definições não dá para decidir qualquer coisa. Um dos maiores erros dos desenvolvedores é achar que o código é mais importante que planejar o que está fazendo colhendo os requisitos de forma clara e ampla.

Precisa analisar se essas coisas funcionarão melhor para seu caso se estiverem separados ou juntos. O que pode facilitar no futuro? Se escolher um caminho porque alguém disse que deve ser assim e não fizer sentido para seu caso estará cometendo um erro. Eu sequer sei o que seriam essas partes separadas.

Não tem fórmula mágica Essas decisões dependem de experiência. Se deseja a experiência de outros precisa dar um nível de detalhamento adequado. Mesmo isso é complicado porque cada um decidirá pela sua experiência que pode não funcionar para outra pessoa.

Soluções ótimas na mão de quem não sabem manipulá-las se torna uma solução ruim. Aí é melhor uma solução mais ou menos que seja feita certa e a pessoa domine seu uso.

Por isso que sempre digo que é comum desenvolvedores quererem adotar certos paradigmas, padrões, arquiteturas, até mesmo estilo de codificação que elas não entendem porque estão fazendo aquilo e como adotá-lo de maneira certa, e acaba sendo pior. A ferramenta que domina é sempre melhor que a que não domina. Evite o *hype*.

Comment: Concordo com seu ponto de vista, porem nesse caso veio esta dúvida por o sistema ser simples, e então vem a calhar ter mais models e nisso separar mais as coisas, ficou mais lógico para mim, pois é mais fácil identificar. Porem, imaginei o mesmo tomando proporções maiores, aí eu preferiria um model ter todas as actions que envolvem ele, para não ter um excesso desnecessário de arquivos. É mais nesse ponto que quero chegar, até quando é bom abstrair essas ramificações, que de uma forma ou outra estão ligadas ao model User, e eu ainda não sei se vou tirar proveito dessa separação. Entende?

Comment: Bom, sistemas simples não precisam de muita coisa para facilitar a manutenção. Esses padrões de arquitetura complexos inventados são para sistemas complexos e que terão muita manutenção.

Comment: Certo, então nesse caso creio que uma classe seria mais apropriado em ambos casos. Aproveitando teu conhecimento, tens algum material para indicar que envolve estas áreas?

Comment: Em geral isto envolve muito estudo, muita prática, muita experimentação, muito debate. Não tem um manualzinho. Alias muito dos erros cometidos é porque as pessoas acham que pode ler alguma coisa e fazer sempre daquele jeito. Mas se for para fazer assim que seja o mais simples possível, tem menos chance de dar errado. Quanto mais complicado for o sistema, menos chance tem do simples dar certo, Mas para fazer o mais complexo tem que aprender com profundidade porque se fizer errado é pior ainda.