# def post(request): ou request.method == POST?

Tags: python, django

Estou a duvida do titulo a cima a respeito das melhores praticas de desenvolvimento em django/python.

Exemplo:

```
class Exemplo(View):

    def get(self, request):
        pass

    def post(self, request):
        pass
```

OU

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    do_something()

elif request.method == 'POST':
    do_something_else()
```

Comment: Como assim? As duas expressões fazem coisas bem diferentes. Poderia contextualizar melhor a dúvida?

Comment: adicionei exemplos. @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Já estudou sobre o [princípio da responsabilidade única](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/5878)?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss já vi alguns artigos a respeito, minha duvida é em relação ao Django, o processo de post e get sempre são gerenciados em uma mesma view, não importa o artigo ou design pattern adotado, por isso da minha duvida!

Comment: "*sempre são gerenciados em uma mesma view*", onde leu isso?

Answer (score 0):

Resposta curta: **nenhum dos dois!**

Resposta longa:

Cada framework web tem uma forma diferente de lidar com tipos diferentes de solicitação, porém, neste caso, estamos falando do **Django**. O django tem várias formas de lidar com solicitações, e cada uma tem um caso específico de uso.

**Não existe uma só forma definitiva considerada *a melhor prática* - cada forma tem seu motivo de existir e seu caso específico onde deve ser usada.**

A pergunta é ampla, e o exemplo adicionado tem um escopo genérico que não acrescenta nada sobre o contexto do código. A resposta genérica no caso do django é fazer como sugerido no [tutorial oficial do django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial04/).

Neste tutorial, é criado um formulário que usa o método POST, e a verificação na view ocorre dentro de um métodos do django:

```
selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
```

Como pode ver, o código simplesmente tenta acessar os dados do formulário através do `request.POST`, e caso estes dados estejam lá, assume-se que o formulário foi enviado através de POST.

É uma forma muito eficiente, pois com apenas uma linha de comando, verifica-se que o formulário foi enviado através de POST e com a variável correta preenchida, e que a opção selecionada realmente existe. Muito melhor do que fazer verificações separadas para cada uma dessas possíveis falhas.

Sendo assim, a forma *genérica* de fazer a verificação por POST é **não fazê-la**, de acordo com o tutorial oficial.

Existem formas específicas de verificar isso, mas devem ser usadas em casos específicos e qual a melhor forma de fazer depende dos detalhes em cada caso de uso.

Comment: Nosklo,vou contextualizar um pouco mais cheguei a ver a documentação oficial nessa parte, porém me deparo com a questão de (validação)segurança, normalmente faço a verificação de (validação) segurança tanto usando html, como na view e na model antes de ir para o banco de dados, como na documentação sugere as proteções básicas, então o contexto é o seguinte: tenho um html "na mão" com as validações por jquery e javascript e meu formulário no estilo Wizard a  2 anos adotei usar a primeira opção que eu te forneci com get() e post(), porém a cada artigo que leio existe a variação da forma usada.

Comment: @RodrigoCarvalho a pergunta continua meio obscura, a resposta é a mesma: **Não existe** uma forma padronizada de fazer a verificação porque a forma recomendada pela documentação oficial é **não fazer a verificação**; É por isso que você vê diferentes artigos com formas diferentes. Cada autor deve ter tido um motivo para usar a forma que usou.