# Existe alguma ordem correta para colocar os membros de um tipo em C#?

Tags: c#, método, estilo-de-codificação, propriedade, campos

Tem um jeito correto de posicionar campos, propriedades, construtores, métodos e outros membros em uma classe e outros tipos? Faz alguma diferença se não seguir essa ordem? Ou existe recomendação, oficial ou não?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do ponto de vista da específica da linguagem não tem ordem correta, nem mesmo se algo depende de outra coisa já que o compilador trabalha em dois passos e ele identifica tudo o que é necessário em qualquer ordem.

Do ponto de vista de estilo seria bom manter sempre uma mesma ordem, se agrupar cada tipo de membro e não ficar misturando tudo.

Algumas pessoas gostam de colocar campos relacionados com propriedades junto, eu não gosto disso, a ideia não é essa.

Existem algumas recomendações, nenhuma é absolutamente certa, mas você pode escolher uma delas e adotar.

Se usar o StyleCop pode adotar [uma das regras padrões dele sobre ordem](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1201.md):

- Fields
- Constructors
- Finalizers (Destructors)
- Delegates
- Events
- Enums
- Interfaces
- Properties
- Indexers
- Methods
- Structs
- Classes

Me parece bem pensado.

Também pode ver outras regras, por exemplo sobre [ordem dos níveis de acesso](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1202.md).

Eu já vi algumas pessoas mandando agrupar por funcionalidade. Mas se precisa fazer isso está com algo muito grande, [SRP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101) passou longe.

Com o advento de Primary Constructor fica complicado saber se campos ou construtores devem vir primeiro já que ele é as duas coisas.

Reforço que o importante é manter a consistência.

Obviamente que existem outras recomendações mais importantes, como no comentário abaixo e em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32665/101).

Comment: Poderia citar também os codings conventions que a microsoft sugere.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions