# Converter String para Decimal

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime, conversão-de-tipo

E estou tendo problemas para converter corretamente esta `string` em `decimal`.

```
decimal.Parse(txtValor.Text)=meuVen.Valor;
```

Quando coloco a conversão na frente, ele mostra erro depois do `=`. Não sei como converter a segunda parte, ou se devo mudar a segunda parte em vez da primeira.

O código do professor é:

```
private void Leitura2() 
{ 
    txtCod2.Text = dgvRegistros2.Rows[dgvRegistros2.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["codigo_servico"].Value‌​.ToString(); 
    Vendas meuVen = new Vendas(int.Parse(txtCod2.Text)); 
    txtNome.Text = meuVen.Nome; 
    decimal.Parse(txtValor.Text) = meuVen.Valor; 
    txtEntrega.Text = meuVen.Entrega.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
}
```

Comment: Você quer converter e atribuir para `meuVen.Valor`, é isso?

Comment: É que infelizmente na escola onde estou a programação esta sendo bem fraca e estas dúvidas com conversões não foram bem explicadas.O que acontece é que neste programa que estou fazendo quero que o valor que for retirado do banco de dados seja um valor que eu possa usar para cálculo, pois terei uma nota fiscal que mostrará o valor total. No banco ele já esta como decimal e nos outros form e cs ele já esta ok, o problema esta sendo neste em expecífico no qual eu possuo um botão de leitura e este botão lê os dados retirados do banco de dados e mostra em uma datagridview.

Comment: O método que o professor ensinou foi este.                                                           private void Leitura2()
        {
            txtCod2.Text = dgvRegistros2.Rows[dgvRegistros2.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["codigo_servico"].Value.ToString();

            Vendas meuVen = new Vendas(int.Parse(txtCod2.Text));
            
            txtNome.Text                    = meuVen.Nome;
            decimal.Parse(txtValor.Text)    = meuVen.Valor;
            txtEntrega.Text                 = meuVen.Entrega.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
         }

Comment: Me desculpe não sei editar o código aqui para que fique com a formatação correta.Basicamente que quero que ele leia o que aparecer na textbox e transforme em decimal para que eu possa usar este valor para uma soma. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Você talvez não tenha encontrado o método correto para fazer a conversão. Ele até funciona mas ele não costuma ser o mais indicado. Se for digitado algo inválido e a conversão gerará uma exceção. Em geral é um erro tentar capturar uma exceção só porque o valor é inválido. Então o melhor método é este:

```
decimal valorDecimal;
if (decimal.TryParse(txtValor.Text, out valorDecimal)) {
    meuVen.Valor = valorDecimal; //note que você quer atribuir o resultado a uma variável
} else {
    //faz um tratamento de erro aqui
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/Conversion.cs).

Veja a [diferença entre os dois métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) e como ele funciona.

Para atribuir um valor para uma variável ela deve estar à esquerda sempre. Então neste caso você lê ao contrário: "está atribuindo o `valorDecimal` para `meuVen.Valor`.

Nós poderíamos ter ajudado mais com um contexto maior.

A dúvida de fato é básica e isto é preocupante porque é não é pelo uso do método mas de como escrever uma atribuição. Com erro tão básico será difícil fazer coisas mais sofisticadas, como tratar o erro. E pior, identificar quando há potencial de erro, testar corretamente para garantir que o programa funciona corretamente em todas situações e não só na condição ideal.

Comment: Na verdade amigo não sabia se deveria colocar mais detalhes sobre o programa, fiquei com medo de complicar a questão em si. Mas já fiz todo o programa, é um programa para o TCC motivo pelo qual não deixei todo o código aqui. A minha dúvida realmente é bem básica, mas é só o que falta para que eu realize a soma dos meus produtos com meus serviços. Meu programa tem por base um cadastro de clientes, serviços e produtos, no qual deverei somar e mostrar em uma nota fiscal o valor total do custo do serviço e do produto usado, se for o caso. Obrigado pela sua ajuda. Se necessário coloco mais código.

Answer (score 0):

converta isto numa classe e comece a criar bibliotecas a partir de todo o código que for implementando para cada proJecto que faz. assim escusa de escrever o mesmo código várias vezes

```
public void ConvertStringDecimal(string stringVal) {
        decimal decimalVal = 0;

        try {
            decimalVal = System.Convert.ToDecimal(stringVal);
            System.Console.WriteLine(
                "The string as a decimal is {0}.", decimalVal);
        } 
        catch (System.OverflowException){
            System.Console.WriteLine(
                "The conversion from string to decimal overflowed.");
        }
        catch (System.FormatException) {
            System.Console.WriteLine(
                "The string is not formatted as a decimal.");
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentNullException) {
            System.Console.WriteLine(
                "The string is null.");
        }

        // Decimal to string conversion will not overflow.
        stringVal = System.Convert.ToString(decimalVal);
        System.Console.WriteLine(
            "The decimal as a string is {0}.", stringVal);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No final das contas, descobri que não havia a necessidade de conversão naquele form, refiz todas as "cs" e "form" para vendas e somente em uma delas com a ajuda de um botão já consegui realizar a soma.
Acabei usando o seguinte método:

```
private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal vl1, vl2, result;
        vl1 = decimal.Parse(txtValor.Text);
        vl2 = decimal.Parse(txtValProd.Text);

        result = vl1 + vl2;
        txtValtotal.Text = (result.ToString());

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   System.Convert.ToDecimal(stringVal);
```