# Buscar número da semana do ano através de uma data em C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, calendar

Estou escrevendo uma função que recebe uma *string* com uma data (formato `dd/mm/aaaa`) e ele deve retornar uma data (No mesmo formato) 4 semanas depois.

Exemplo:

```
Entrada: 07/04/2016
saída: 05/05/2016
```

Li a respeito e pensei na seguinte lógica:

Ler a data e transformar a semana correspondente em inteiro, somar 4 e fazer o processo contrário.

Segue código:

```
    //entrada 07/04/2016
    private string CalcularDataEntrega(string dataEntrada)
    {
        //regra: Data Geração + 4 Semanas;
        DateTime dataGen = DateTime.Parse(dataEntrada);
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        int semanaInicio = cal.GetWeekOfYear(dataGen); //erro
        int semanaFim = semanaInicio + 4;

        //retornar data com base na semana
        string dataSaida; //o que colocar?

        return dataSaida;
    }
```

[Neste Exemplo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear(v=vs.110).aspx) da documentação da Microsoft não ficou claro o que exatamente essa função `GetWeekOfYear` retorna (inteiro, string?).

Comment: Não sei se entendi o que deseja, mas existe algum motivo para evitar somar 28 dias?

Comment: dataGen.AddDays(28);

Comment: . . . realmente, não tinha pensado nisso, parece incrivelmente obvio. Obrigado de qualquer maneira

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta fazer isto:

```
DateTime.Parse(dataEntrada).AddDays(28).ToString()
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/NBZjdP). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OAKrDs). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/FourWeeksLater.cs).

Estou partindo do princípio que a data estará garantidamente em formato adequado. Caso isso não seja garantido, haverá uma exceção. Idealmente seria bom tratar isto de alguma forma, talvez usando um [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101). Evite trabalhar com datas armazenadas como `string` sempre que possível.

Comment: Deu para entender sim amigo, eu só preciso ver com o cliente se são 28 dias corridos mesmo ou eu desconsidero dias não úteis. mesmo assim a implementação vai servir. Obrigado

Comment: Se for dias úteis, teria que sofisticar um pouco mais e aí vem o enrosco de tratar feriados, já sai de uma solução trivial para algo relativamente complexa e que a maioria dos programadores nem se dá conta.

Answer (score 1):

A funcao que voce procura é esta mesmo GetWeekOfYear e ela te retornará um inteiro (Int32), como descrito na página.

**Return Value
Type: System.Int32
A positive integer that represents the week of the year that includes the date in the time parameter.**

Abraços,

Comment: Verdade cara, eu não tinha visto no link. Obrigado