# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, .net, string, conversão-de-tipo

Estou tentando desenvolver um código no meu jogo mas estou com este erro.

```
...

case "cpsuser":
    Console.Write("Digite o apelido do usuário: ");

    string Nickname = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Digite a quantidade de Cupons");

    string Cupons = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Digite a mensagem a ser informada para o player. Por exemplo: Parabéns você recebeu 10000 Cupons.");

    string Message = Console.ReadLine();

    GamePlayer Player = WorldMgr.GetAllPlayers()
                                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.PlayerCharacter
                                                      .NickName == Nickname);

    if (Player == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("O usuário informado não existe ou está offline!");
    }
    else
    {
        int num6 = (object)Cupons;
        foreach (GamePlayer gamePlayer in WorldMgr.GetAllPlayers())
        {
            gamePlayer.AddMoney(num6);
            gamePlayer.SendMessage("({0})", Message);

        }
    }
    break;

...
```

No caso é aqui que estou com o erro:

```
...

else
{
    int num6 = (object)Cupons;
    foreach (GamePlayer gamePlayer in WorldMgr.GetAllPlayers())
    {
        gamePlayer.AddMoney(num6);
        gamePlayer.SendMessage("({0})", Message);

        ...
```

Comment: Você está tentando colocar um object dentro de um int. Imagine que o object é pai de todos os objetos, e int é filho de object, em uma analogia você está tentando colocar o pai dentro do filho.

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer para tentar corrigir?

Comment: use o Convert.ToInt32, tem que ser um objeto que pode ser convertido para int, como por exemplo um string ou um decimal. O que esse objeto cupons tem de propriedade? De que tipo ele é?

Comment: Já resolvido obrigado.

Comment: @Vinicius na verdade não foi resolvido, eu dei uma resposta porque as respostas que tinham ensinam errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não podes fazer um cast para um formato de objecto e tentares guardar em int...
Tens de fazer assim com o `Convert.ToInt32()`

```
{
   int num6 = Convert.ToInt32(Cupons);
   foreach (GamePlayer gamePlayer in WorldMgr.GetAllPlayers())
   {
      gamePlayer.AddMoney(num6);
      gamePlayer.SendMessage("({0})", Message);
```

Comment: Agora está dando erro: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: você verificou o que sua variável ta recebendo pelo Watch? a variável esta sendo uma string vazia?

Comment: Agora já dará :)

Comment: Funcionou obrigado Pedro Luzio.

Comment: @Vinicius funcionou em um teste simples e direcionado, sem considerar que o usuário pode digitar algo errado. Na verdade esta é a resposta mais errada. O próprio comentário acima já indica algo errado. Só funciona quando a pessoa digita certo. Não é o programador que deve exigir o usuário fazer o certo, é o código que deve funcionar corretamente. Note que sua intuição foi fazer o errado. Se vai insistir em fazer errado, pelo menos coloque uma mensagem para o usuário alertando que ele não pode fazer nada errado.

Answer (score 6):

Resolvi responder porque a resposta aceita é um erro e a outra fala em boas práticas, quando é justamente o oposto. Ou funciona direito ou não funciona, não existe isso de boa prática, e só uma das soluções apresentadas funciona direito.

É importante notar que testar dentro do uso normal e dizer que funciona não é programar corretamente. O certo é fazer algo que funcione sempre. Então com dados que vêm de fontes externas que o programador não tem controle, não é possível fazer conversões diretas e considerar que isto é correto. Tem que **tentar** fazer a conversão e se der algum problema decidir que ação tomar. Por exemplo, é possível definir que se um texto inválido foi digitado, considere o número como 0 (como fiz no exemplo abaixo). Não estou dizendo que isto é o mais adequado para este código. Pode ser que seja outro número ou pode ser que o código precise ter uma outra ação, talvez avisar do problema para o usuário e solicitar outro número, depende do contexto.

Seria algo assim:

```
int num6;
num6 = int.TryParse(cupons, out num6) ? num6 : 0;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1UgjoR). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wY6v5l). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/ParseInt.cs).

Para saber se algo funciona precisa testar com todas possibilidades. Tem que testar coisas até mesmo estapafúrdias. Tem que entender todo o mecanismo que está usando e testar por todos os caminhos que ele pode executar. Tem que saber tudo o que pode retornar de um método, inclusive as exceções que ele pode lançar. Aí deve tratar cada situações adequadamente ou mudar o método escolhido se tiver outro mais adequado, como é o caso acima.

Sem ler e interpretar toda documentação do que está usando adequadamente não dá para fazer nada certo e não pode-se afirmar que algo funciona. Muito menos pode-se falar em boa prática. Acreditar em boas práticas é uma má prática e vai dar um tiro no próprio pé. Ou a coisa é certa ou errada.

[Pode testar as duas opções erradas](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IGPKQ7). Primeiro coloque uma palavra, depois tente de novo colocando um número correto e uma palavra no segundo pedido. Verá a exceção.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__).

[Outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) com mais detalhes sobre o assunto.

Comment: Poderia ainda sim, simplificar somente para `int.TryParse(cupons, out int num6);`. O `int` já tem valor padrão `0`. Claro, isso dependendo da versão do `c#` que está sendo utilizada, mas não que esteja errado.

Comment: Agora pode, na época da resposta não dava ou era muito recente pra responder isso.

Answer (score 3):

@Vinicius,
Não é uma boa prática fazer um `cast` (aka. [`unboxing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)).

Uma das melhores práticas, diz que você precisa fazer uma conversão ou parse e para fazer isso você tem algumas opções.

- [`Int32 Convert.ToInt32(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx) - Recebe uma `string` como parâmetro e tenta converter para `Int32` (que é um alias para `Int32`), se não conseguir retorna um erro
- [`Int32 Int32.Parse(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) - Faz o mesmo do item acima
- [`bool Int32.TryParse(string, out Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) - Recebe uma `string` como parâmetro e um `Int32` marcado com a `keyword` `out` (indicando que a variável passada terá um valor no final da execução do método). Caso consiga converter, a variável terá o valor convertido e o método retorna `true`; Caso contrário, retorna `false` e a variável terá o valor default para `Int32`, que é `0`.

### Na prática ficaria algo assim:

#### [`Int32 Convert.ToInt32(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int num6 = Convert.ToInt32(Cupons);
```

#### [`Int32 Int32.Parse(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int num6 = Int32.Parse(Cupons);
```

#### [`bool Int32.TryParse(string, out Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int num6;
bool converteu = Int32.TryParse(Cupons, out num6);
```

Espero ter ajudado \o/

Comment: Obrigado por ajudar :)