# Como posso fazer que um código com string trabalhe com > ou <?

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms, operadores

Aparentemente estou tendo problemas com *strings*:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int _adicionar;
    private int _retirar;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void _Random_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random num = new Random();
        _ValSorteado.Text = num.Next(Convert.ToInt32(_TextValMin.Text), Convert.ToInt32(_TextValMax.Text)).ToString();

        if (_Igual.Checked)
        {
            if (_TextValPalite.Text == _ValSorteado.Text)
            {
                _adicionar = _adicionar + 1;
                _Acerto.Text = Convert.ToString(_adicionar);
            }
            else
            {
                _retirar = _retirar + 1;
                _Errou.Text = Convert.ToString(_retirar);
            }


            if (_Maior.Checked)
            {
                if (_TextValPalite.Text > _ValSorteado.Text)
                {
                    _adicionar = _adicionar + 1;
                    _Acerto.Text = Convert.ToString(_adicionar);
                }
                else
                {
                    _retirar = _retirar + 1;
                    _Errou.Text = Convert.ToString(_retirar);
                }
            }

            if (_Menor.Checked)
            {
                if (_TextValPalite.Text < _ValSorteado.Text)
                {
                    _adicionar = _adicionar + 1;
                    _Acerto.Text = Convert.ToString(_adicionar);
                }
                else
                {
                    _retirar = _retirar + 1;
                    _Errou.Text = Convert.ToString(_retirar);
             }
            }
          }
        }
```

Para valores iguais (==) e diferentes (!=) eu consigo, mas para valores maiores (>) ou menores (<) não, ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

[image: SS]

Comment: Que tal converter pra `int`?

Comment: Eu fiz um gist para melhorar um pouco o seu código e resolver o seu problema também. Dê uma olhadela, pode ajudar a aprender algumas coisas. https://gist.github.com/brunoss/e960713775b4c35ef8f760c10bd0abe6

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 6):

> **Obs.:** A minha resposta leva em consideração que os dados digitados pelo usuário serão validados separadamente (talvez no método `Leave` do componente, ou algo semelhante) e que em nenhum caso será possível fazer com que os métodos de conversão recebam valores inválidos. Caso não tenha certeza da integridade dos valores, dê preferência pelo uso do `TryParse` como na resposta do @Maniero.

Você não pode mesmo fazer esse tipo de comparação com strings.

Você precisa converter os tipos para número.

Se sua aplicação irá usar os valores digitados mais de uma vez, a solução é usar duas variáveis `int`. Ex.:

```
int valorPalpite = Convert.ToInt32(_TextValPalite.Text);
int valorSorteado = Convert.ToInt32(_ValSorteado.Text);
```

uso:

```
if(valorPalpite < valorSorteado) { ... }
```

Eu salvaria as variáveis logo no início do evento de click e depois as usaria para fazer todas as validações e/ou cálculos que forem necessários.

Caso prefira, podes fazer a conversão na hora da verificação

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(_TextValPalite.Text) < Convert.ToInt32(_ValSorteado.Text)) { ... }
```

**Adicional**:

1. `Convert.ToInt32` não é a única forma de converter uma *string* para número, para mais detalhes você pode ver as respostas em [Qual a principal diferença entre int.Parse() e Convert.ToInt32()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90981/qual-a-principal-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-int-parse-e-convert-toint32)
2. O nome das variáveis não estão seguindo o [padrão de nomenclatura do C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx). As únicas que estão seguindo o padrão são `_adicionar` e `_retirar`, o resto não deveria ter *underscore* (`_`).

Answer (score 6):

O real problema em todo este código é que ele não está lidando bem com os dados de texto. Algo semelhante ao que ocorre na resposta colocada em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/129247/101).

Se quiser insistir em usar texto o correto é usar o método [`Compare()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Mas não aconselho.

Para converter os dados para número, já que a entrada de dados não pode ser garantidamente válida, é necessário apenas tentar fazer a conversão e tomar alguma ação se a conversão não der certo. Então todos estes campos fo formulário precisam usar um [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) para gerar uma variável com o valor numérico. Aí pode compar como quiser.

```
private void _Random_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var num = new Random();
    int valMin;
    if (int.TrypParse(_TextValMin.Text, out valMin)) {
        MessageBox.Show("valor inválido"); //obviamente isto é uma simplificação
        return;
    }
    int valMax;
    if (int.TrypParse(_TextValMax.Text, out valMax)) {
        MessageBox.Show("valor inválido"); //obviamente isto é uma simplificação
        return;
    }
    var valSorteado = num.Next(valMin, valMax);
    _ValSorteado.Text = valSorteado.ToString();
    int valPalpite;
    if (int.TrypParse(_TextValPalpite.Text, out valPalpite)) {
        MessageBox.Show("valor inválido"); //obviamente isto é uma simplificação
        return;
    }
    if (_Igual.Checked) {
        if (valPapite == valSorteado) _Acerto.Text = (++_adicionar).ToString();
        else _Errou.Text = (++_retirar).ToString();
        if (_Maior.Checked) {
            if (valPalite > valSorteado) _Acerto.Text = (++_adicionar).ToString();
            else _Errou.Text = (++_retirar).ToString();
         }
         if (_Menor.Checked) {
            if (valPalite < valSorteado) _Acerto.Text = (++_adicionar).ToString();
            else _Errou.Text = (++_retirar).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/ComparingNumbers.cs).

Dei uma melhorada, mas ainda tem mais algumas coisas que este código pode ser melhorado.

Obviamente que a solução de dar uma mensagem de erro genérica é uma gambiarra, coloque no código a ação que for mais adequada para seu código. Mas não deixe de tratar a possibilidade do usuário digitar algo errado.

Como complemento em C# 7 é possível escrever o código um pouco melhor sem precisar declarar a variável que receberá o valor antecipadamente:

```
if (int.TrypParse(_TextValMin.Text, out var valMin)) {
    //faz algo aqui
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não podes comparar duas Strings como sendo maiores ou menores, e para que o programa não dê erro quando o utilizador sem querer colocar um caracter que não seja um número, deves usar `NupericUpDown` que limita o input a números e depois usas assim:

```
if (_TextValPalite.Value > _ValSorteado.Value)
```

Ou seja, em vez de utilizares o atributo `Text`, utilizas o `Value`.

Answer (score 1):

Se apenas queres converter a tua variável para  um inteiro então só fazes isto:

```
int.Parse(_TextValPalite)
```

O convert.toint tem um problema que pode ser grave por vezes, corre um try catch por trás!