# Como transformar um bool em int?

Tags: c#, .net, operadores

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte: se o valor de palpite (`_TextValPalite`) for habilitado então ele vai checar se esse número não é diferente de um valor mínimo e um valor máximo.

Ex: entre 1 e 10 eu posso escrever 5, mas não 11.

```
if(_TextValPalite.Enabled)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(_TextValMin.Text) & Convert.ToInt32(_TextValMax.Text) != Convert.ToInt32(_TextValPalite.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Você não pode fazer isso");
                return;
            }
        }
```

Porem ele retorna esse erro:

```
Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'
```

Eu consigo fazer operações de + - * / normalmente, mas como fazer o `bool` interpretar isso? transformando ele em uma `int`? como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Você não pode entender os erros literalmente, na maioria das bvezes, o problema é outro: está usando o operador errado, o correto é o `&&` que é o `AND` lógico. O `&` é o `AND` de bits, ele é um multiplicador de bits, que não é o que deseja aí. Também falta uma parte da comparação, tem que comparar com o palpite as duas operações.

O compilador ficou "perdido" porque ele tinha um inteiro na primeira parte do operador, e um booleano na segunda, com o operador errado, ele deu essa mensagem de erro que ele conseguiu segundo certas regras. Se ambos fossem booleanos, ele teria melhor informação a dar. Uma comparação (que usa um operador relacional, como o diferente) sempre dá um booleano, faltou esta operação na primeira subexpressão.

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(_TextValMin.Text) != Convert.ToInt32(_TextValPalite.Text) && Convert.ToInt32(_TextValMax.Text) != Convert.ToInt32(_TextValPalite.Text))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/ToInt.cs).

Ainda que esse código tenha outro erro já definido em [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129410/101).

Se digitarem algo errado a aplicação vai quebrar.

Comment: Tanto && e & retornam o mesmo erro.

Comment: Eu tinha esquecido de colocar o resto da comparação.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro você deve usar dois sinais `&&` para o instrução `and`, e você também deve fazer uma verificação para cada item, veja:

```
(Convert.ToInt32(_TextValMin.Text) != Convert.ToInt32(_TextValPalite.Text)) &&
(Convert.ToInt32(_TextValMax.Text) != Convert.ToInt32(_TextValPalite.Text))
```

Mesmo assim, você ainda não terá o resultado que espera, vcê tem que comprar se os valores estão entre a mínima e máxima, apenas diferente como você fez, poderá ser qualquer valor, por exemplo:

```
valorMinimo = 1;
valorMaximo = 10;
valor = 11;
```

Fazendo um teste de mesa para esse caso com seu exemplo:

```
valor != valorMinimo ? True
valor != valorMaximo ? True
Resultado: True
```

Agora, o que você realmente precisa:

```
valor >= valorMinimo ? True
valor <= valorMaximo ? False
Resultado: False
```

Veja o exemplo em código:

```
var valorMinimo = Convert.ToInt32(_TextValMin.Text);
var valorMaximo = Convert.ToInt32(_TextValMax.Text);
var valor = Convert.ToInt32(_TextValPalite.Text);
var estaEntreIntervalo = (valor <= valorMaximo) && (valor >= valorMinimo);
if (!estaEntreIntervalo) { //Se não esta entre o intervalo
    MessageBox.Show("Você não pode fazer isso");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(_TextValPalite.Enabled)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(_TextValMin.Text) && Convert.ToInt32(_TextValMax.Text) != Convert.ToInt32(_TextValPalite.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Você não pode fazer isso");
                return;
            }
        }
```