# Erro ao comparar números e verificar se são iguais

Tags: c#, .net, console

Estou fazendo um exercício simples de C# no qual eu tenho que receber dois números, compará-los e imprimir qual é o maior ou se são iguais.

Quando inicio o programa, eu só consigo colocar o primeiro número, e antes de colocar o segundo, o programa já retorna a comparação, com números que não tem nada a ver o que eu coloquei.

Por exemplo: se eu colocar o  1 para o primeiro, o programa imprime isso:

```
 "Digite outro número: 49 é maior que 13.Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . ."
```

Estou utilizando o `Read();` da maneira errada? Qual seria outro jeito de fazer esse programa?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Digite um número: ");
        int a = Console.Read();
        Console.Write("Digite outro número: ");
        int b = Console.Read();

        if (a > b)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} é maior que {1}.", a, b);
        }
        else if (b > a)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} é maior que {1}.", b, a);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Os dois números são iguais");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

o console.Read() le unicamente um caracter. Como voçe escreve um numero e dá um enter, na variabel a ele fica com o numero que lhe deste, e na variabel b fica com o valor do enter.
Podes fazer assim:

```
 Console.Write("Digite um número: ");
        int a = Console.Read();
        Console.Read();
        Console.Write("Digite outro número: ");
        int b = Console.Read();
        Console.Read();

        if (a > b)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} é maior que {1}.", a, b);
        }
        else if (b > a)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} é maior que {1}.", b, a);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Os dois números são iguais");
        }
```

O melhor metodo a usar neste caso é

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

Ao usar o metodo, passas a ter de converter o valor que sera armazenado.

```
int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: E se o usuário digitar a letra **`A`**?

Comment: Com 'A', daria exceção!
P.S.: Limitei-me a responder-lhe a questão que ele perguntou!

Answer (score 8):

O código faz o que você manda, não o que você quer. No caso está usando o método errado. o `Read()` é para ler uma único caractere. Para ler vários é o [`ReadLine()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Console_ReadLine).

Aí você pode pensar, mas ele retorna um texto e eu quero um número. Sim, tem que fazer a conversão, provavelmente com [`TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__).

```
using static System.Console;

public static class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Write("Digite um número: ");
        if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var a)) {
            Write("Deu erro");
            return;
        }
        Write("Digite outro número: ");
        if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var b)) {
            Write("Deu erro");
            return;
        }
        if (a > b) Write($"{a} é maior que {b}.");
        else if (b > a) Write($"{b} é maior que {a}.");
        else Write("Os dois números são iguais");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xfZws8). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nG1b25). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Greather.cs).

Obviamente este código pode ser melhorado. Pode criar um método para generalizar a entrada de dados e evitar código repetitivo. Pode fazer algo melhor que só dizer que deu erro. Pode fazer um laço pedindo o dado novamente. Aí fica como exercício.

Note que modernizei o código com coisa do C# 6.

Não recomendo o uso do `Parse()`. Ele pode gerar erros se o texto não puder ser convertido. Experimente colocar um texto e veja o que acontece com este método. E veja [porque o `Tryparse()` é melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

Comment: Muito bem colocado: "o código faz o que você manda, não o que você quer!"Isso ajuda a melhorar a qualidade das perguntas!

Answer (score 3):

Mude o read para readline com parse (vai ler depois de dar enter):
Console.Write("Digite um número: ");

```
Console.Write("Digite um número: ");
int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Digite outro número: ");
int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: `int.Parse` não é cast, é conversão.

Comment: Corrigi o texto e dei um voto para o seu comentário. Obrigado pela observação.