# Lendo informações do usuario

Tags: c#, .net, console

Comecei a estudar C#, e meu primeiro programa (exceto pelo hello world hahahaha) é uma calculadora de áreas. No código abaixo, após eu digitar a opção (escolhendo qual figura eu quero) o console simplesmente fecha.

```
            Console.WriteLine("Bem vindo a calculadora de áreas!!!");
            Console.WriteLine("A seguir escolha qual figura deseja, digitando o número correspondente a figura correspondente.");
            Console.WriteLine("1 ==> Quadrado");
            Console.WriteLine("2 ==> Triângulo");
            Console.WriteLine("3 ==> Circunferência");
            int opcao = Console.Read();

            switch (opcao)
            {
                case  1:
                    int lado;
                    Console.WriteLine("Digite o valor do lado do quadrado: ");
                    lado = Console.Read();
                    lado = lado * lado;
                    Console.WriteLine("O valor da área do quadrado e: ", lado);
                    break;
                case  2:
                    int base_t, altura, resultado;
                    Console.WriteLine("Digite o valor da base do triângulo: ");
                    base_t = Console.Read();
                    Console.WriteLine("Digite o valor da altura do triângulo: ");
                    altura = Console.Read();
                    resultado = base_t * altura / 2;
                    Console.WriteLine("O valor da área do triângulo é: ", resultado);
                    break;
                case  3:
                    int raio;
                    double area;
                    Console.WriteLine("Digite o valor do raio da circunferência: ");
                    raio = Console.Read();
                    area = Math.PI * (raio * raio);
                    Console.WriteLine("O valor da área do circunferência e: ", area);
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A resposta postada resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução apresentada foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que ela é satisfatória. Também pode votar em toda e qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos). Aceitar e votar são coisas distintas.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que está pegando um caractere. Você precisa pegar um texto e converter para número para funcionar. Fiz isto para demonstrar, dei uma modernizada no código e resolvi um problema que não estava imprimindo o resultado. Obviamente à partir disto pode melhor, pode fazer um laço para perguntar de novo quando falhar, pode generalizar o código de conversão e validação.

```
using System;
using static System.Math;
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine("Bem vindo a calculadora de áreas!!!");
        WriteLine("A seguir escolha qual figura deseja, digitando o número correspondente a figura correspondente.");
        WriteLine("1 ==> Quadrado");
        WriteLine("2 ==> Triângulo");
        WriteLine("3 ==> Circunferência");
        string escolha = ReadLine();
        int opcao;
        if (!int.TryParse(escolha, out opcao)) {
            Write("Opção inválida");
            return;
        }
        switch (opcao) {
            case  1:
                int lado;
                WriteLine("Digite o valor do lado do quadrado: ");
                string texto = ReadLine();
                if (!int.TryParse(escolha, out lado)) {
                    Write("Número inválido");
                    return;
                }
                lado = lado * lado;
                WriteLine($"O valor da área do quadrado e: {lado}");
                break;
            case  2:
                int base_t, altura, resultado;
                WriteLine("Digite o valor da base do triângulo: ");
                texto = ReadLine();
                if (!int.TryParse(escolha, out base_t)) {
                    Console.Write("Número inválido");
                    return;
                }
                WriteLine("Digite o valor da altura do triângulo: ");
                texto = ReadLine();
                if (!int.TryParse(escolha, out altura)) {
                    Write("Número inválido");
                    return;
                }
                resultado = base_t * altura / 2;
                WriteLine($"O valor da área do triângulo é: {resultado}");
                break;
            case  3:
                int raio;
                double area;
                WriteLine("Digite o valor do raio da circunferência: ");
                texto = ReadLine();
                if (!int.TryParse(escolha, out raio)) {
                    Write("Número inválido");
                    return;
                }
                area = PI * (raio * raio);
                WriteLine($"O valor da área do circunferência e: {area}");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yMHfee). E [no **repl.it**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/85SWwO). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/ReadData.cs).

O [`ReadLine()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Console_ReadLine) é o método certo para ler dados mais complexos (mais que um caractere). Só que ele retorna sempre um texto.Então tem que fazer a conversão. Como você não tem certeza que foi digitado um número a conversão pode falhar. Então o método correto para converter é o `TryParse()` que tenta converter, se não der certo, ele dá um retorno indicando isto, se der certo ele colocar o valor convertido na variável que está passando. Se precisar de mais detalhes sobre isto faça uma pergunta específica sobre o assunto para não misturar.

Eu sei que pode ser um pouco pesado para alguém que está começando, mas o exemplo não pode ser feito de forma correta e simples ao mesmo tempo. De que adianta aprender fazer errado? Eu te ensinei o certo. Ainda não o totalmente certo para não complicar demais. Para exercício está bom assim.

Veja [Diferenças entre Parse vs TryParse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

Comment: Poxa, não tem como simplesmente ler números?

Comment: Não tem. Ou até tem, mas é tão mais complicado que vai preferir isto. Se até quem é experiente prefere assim, imagina quem está começando. Como eu disse tem como generalizar a função para usar em vários lugares de forma simplificada. Mas para quem está começando não é importante isto, o que importa é entender o funcionamento.

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou lendo e entendendo melhor o que cada adição que vc fez faz. Ahh, a respeito disso: Console.WriteLine("O valor da área do quadrado e: ", lado); virgula e depois variável é por causa de Java

Comment: O Java tem as mesmas dificuldades de receber números, só que oferece uma solução mais porca, na minha opinião. Ela pode até ser mais prática se tudo der certo, mas se der errado, e tem que considerar que pode dar, fica muito ruim.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, como já foi mencionado na resposta acima, o `Console.Read()` lê o próximo caractere digitado, o seu código na verdade, e para o que pretendes, precisarias de saber o equivalente desses caracteres para corresponder com as opções no teu `switch`.

```
int opcao = Console.Read();

switch(Convert.ToChar(opcao)){
      case '1':
         Console.WriteLine("Primeiro");
         // efectuar calculos aqui e imprimir o resultado
         break;
      case '2':
         Console.WriteLine("Segundo");
         // efectuar calculos aqui e imprimir o resultado
         break;
      default:
         Console.WriteLine("Opcao Invalida");
         break;
}
// caso executes o app sem o modo debug
// para evitar que a console feche automaticamente
Console.Write("Pressione qualquer tecla para sair!");
Console.Read();
```

Em alternativa podias simplesmente usar o `int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), variavel)` que é o mais comum, que retornará falso caso o valor de entrada seja algo diferente de um número e falhe na conversão, e verdadeiro caso o valor de entrada seja convertido com sucesso, sendo que o `Console.ReadLine()` retorna sempre uma `string` e pode aceitar qualquer valor de entrada.