# Switch só entra no "default"

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo, switch

Quando leio um número, convertendo ele para `Int32`, o meu `switch` simplesmente entende que é um `default` e faz o código lá descrito.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Jogador j = new Jogador(); //instancia que representa as decisões do jogador
        Jogador npc = new Jogador(); //instancia que representa o adv controlado pelo computador
        Random rdn = new Random(); // pra gerar a jogada do NPC
        int jj = 1;

        Intro();
        while (jj != 4)
        {
            Opcoes();
            int jnpc = Convert.ToInt32(rdn.Next(1, 3)); //gerando numero aleatorio da jogada do NPC
            jj = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());

            switch (jj) // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<- aqui ele le como default qualquer coisa digitada
            {
                case 1: //pedra
                    if (jj == jnpc)
                    {
                        j.Empatou();
                        npc.Empatou();
                        Console.WriteLine("EMPATE");
                    }
                    else if (jnpc == 2)
                    {
                        j.Perdeu();
                        npc.Venceu();
                        Console.WriteLine("VITÓRIA do Computador");
                    }
                    else if (jnpc == 3)
                    {
                        j.Venceu();
                        npc.Perdeu();
                        Console.WriteLine("VITÓRIA do Jogador");
                    }
                    break;
                case 2: //papel
                    if (jj == jnpc)
                    {
                        j.Empatou();
                        npc.Empatou();
                        Console.WriteLine("EMPATE");
                    }
                    else if (jnpc == 1)
                    {
                        j.Venceu();
                        npc.Perdeu();
                        Console.WriteLine("VITÓRIA do Jogador");
                    }
                    else if (jnpc == 3)
                    {
                        j.Perdeu();
                        npc.Venceu();
                        Console.WriteLine("VITÓRIA do Computador");
                    }
                    break;
                case 3: //tesoura
                    if (jj == jnpc)
                    {
                        j.Empatou();
                        npc.Empatou();
                        Console.WriteLine("EMPATE");
                    }
                    else if (jnpc == 1)
                    {
                        j.Perdeu();
                        npc.Venceu();
                        Console.WriteLine("VITÓRIA do Computador");
                    }
                    else if (jnpc == 2)
                    {
                        j.Venceu();
                        npc.Venceu();
                        Console.WriteLine("VITÓRIA do Jogador");
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:


                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Voce digitou um valor inválido, tente novamente");
                    break;
            }//fim do switch
        }//fim do while
```

Pra não perder o embalo ele também reproduz mais 3 vezes parte do `while` e depois vai pro `read` de novo. Pela situação, acredito que possa ser isso:
A minha conversão deveria ser outra pro `switch` entender o número (testei colocando um número inteiro ali e daí funcionou)

E sobre estar reproduzindo parte do código, eu não consigo entender por que, afinal ele lê o `opcoes()`, que é só um método para encurtar texto (não tem função além de escrever na tela), mas não executa o `read` que tem logo abaixo.

A imagem abaixo é o que acontece quando eu digito qualquer número.

[image: Visual Studio com o código]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso:

```
jj = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
```

Troque por isso:

```
Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

---

Caso queira usar `Console.Read()` voce precisa converte o valor para `char`.

```
jj = Console.Read();
char exemplo = Convert.ToChar(jj);
switch (exemplo.ToString)
```

Caso o usuario digite varios valores a conversao ira retorna apenas o primeiro char

---

Melhor solucao:

```
Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out jj);
```

---

Comment: Perfeito, resolveu. Pode me dizer por que?

Comment: Readline ler a string digitada, ja o read ler o caractere digitado e retorna o proximo (uma conversao de hexadecimal)

Comment: @GiovaneMachado editei, acho que da para enteder melhor com a edicao

Comment: Na verdade essa solução com `ReadLine()` ainda causará problemas, esta é a correta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/140112/101. Não tem como ler mais de um caractere com `Read()`. Isto `exemplo.ToString` não faz sentido do ponto de vista sintático e semântico.

Answer (score 6):

É só fazer isto:

```
jj = Console.Read() - 48;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/CharArithmetic.cs).

O caractere 0 é o 48, então fazendo esta conta não precisa converter nada, não complica, e funciona como o desejado.

Se quiser mais semântico pode fazer `(char)'0'` no lugar do 48.