# Como fazer o compilador reconhecer o . como separador decimal?

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatação

Fiz um código simples em C# que recebe um número real mas que só reconhece a "," como separador decimal. Quando o faço receber números que use o "." como separador ele ignora o ponto. Por exemplo, se envio "2.0", ele recebe "20".
Aqui está o código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           string r;
           double raio;
           r = Console.ReadLine();
           raio = double.Parse(r);
           Console.WriteLine(raio);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui e ele me retornou `2.0`. Seu código parece estar um pouco confuso também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O compilador já reconhece números com ponto. O que está querendo fazer é que sua aplicação faça isto.

Primeiro precisa escrever um código minimamente coerente pra pelo menos compilar. Este tem erros básicos.

Se vai ler o dado do console a conversão pode falhar por ser digitado algo inválido. Em algo simples pode deixar falhar, mas em uma aplicação real é melhor tratar isto e a melhor forma é com [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

O normal é a conversão ser feita levando em consideração a cultura especificada no sistema operacional. Se deseja uma cultura específica para sua aplicação precisa determinar isto. Tem várias maneiras de fazer. Pode ser para toda aplicação, em momentos específicos, pode escolher uma cultura pré-definida ou estabelecer uma de acordo com sua necessidade. Fiz um exemplo rápido aqui:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication4 {
    public class Program {
       public static void Main(string[] args) => WriteLine(double.Parse("2.0", new CultureInfo("en-US")));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HPyA20). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wh1CZR). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/CultureParseDouble.cs).