# Erro ao percorrer vetor

Tags: c#, .net, array

O usuário cola os valores que serão salvos dentro do vetor e depois mostra esses valores. Porém está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in vetoor.exe ".

Meu código está da seguinte forma:

```
namespace vetoor 
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] vet = new int[3];
        int i,a;


        for (i = 0; i < vet.Length;  i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Digite o numero");
            vet[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }
        for(a=0; a<4; a++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", vet[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

Você criou um vetor com 3 elementos e até começou bem no primeiro laço indo até atingir o seu tamanho, ainda que nesse caso bem específico não precisa fazer isto. Mas depois foi até 3. O vetor vai de 0 à 2. Se mudar a segunda condição para 3 vai resolver. Ou use sempre o `Length` para evitar esse problema. Talvez o ideal fosse até usar `foreach` no lugar do `for`, mas  acho que ainda não aprendeu isso.

Mas esse código pode ser mais organizado e modernizado:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace vetor {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            int[] vet = new int[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < vet.Length; i++) {
                WriteLine("Digite o numero: ");
                vet[i] = int.Parse(ReadLine());
            }
            for (int a = 0; a < vet.Length; a++) WriteLine($"{vet[a]}");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VXtBrB). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uwCfKK). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/Bounds.cs).

Note que ainda há um problema em potencial. Quando você pede para alguém digitar um valor e não tem controle sobre ele não pode usar `Parse()` porque se a digitação não puder ser convertida gerará um erro. terá que usar [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

Answer (score 2):

O segundo for itera sobre o seu vetor até o índice 3.

Ao acessar o índice vet[a] quando a é igual a 3, é lançado essa exceção. Isso significa que o vetor vet não possui o índice 3.

Isso pode ser confuso no início, mas embora você tenha declarado o vetor vet com 3 posições, o índice começa a partir do 0. Ou seja, o vetor vet possui apenas os índices 0, 1 e 2.

Answer (score 0):

a minha resposta é baseada no erro apenas.. nao sei se tinhas outras duvidas ou nao.. tens tambem uma outra alternativa a um for.. o foreach que percorre uma lista/array

```
       namespace vetoor 
     {
    class Program
      {
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] vet = new int[3];
    int i,a;


    for (i = 0; i <= vet.Length;  i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Digite o numero");
        vet[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    }
   // for(a=0; a<4; a++) -> a = 3 e a = 4 iria estar fora do vector
   // {
   //     Console.WriteLine("{0}", vet[i]);
   // }
   foreach(int num in vet){
    Console.WriteLine(num);
   }

    Console.ReadKey();
   }
 }
```