# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, string, asp.net-mvc-5

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias> aDay = new List<ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias>();
        ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias ee = new ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias();


        if (ProcessingType == 1)
        {


            ee.Dia = this.txtDay.Text;        

        }
        else
        {
            ee.Dia = this.lblDay.Text;
            ee.FromProductID = this.hdnSourceID.Value;
            ee.ToProductID = this.hdnDestinationID.Value;
        }
```

O erro está em:

```
ee.Dia = this.txtDay.Text;
```

Erro:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Eu percebo que não pode converter de `string` para `int`.

Como consigo dar a volta a isto?

Comment: Qual é o tipo de `ee.Day`? Posta o que faz `ToInt32Nullable()`. Qual é o dado que está tentando converter que dá esse erro?

Comment: O dado é int Dia, estou a tentar converter isto porque o objetivo é poder preencher o dados para depois salvar o toInt32Nullable(), esta errada, sei.. em vez de toint é text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você tem que mandar fazer a conversão. Como o dado pode não ser válido você tem que testar para ver se a conversão correu corretamente. Isso é feito com [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var aDay = new List<ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias>();
    var ee = new ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias();
    int dia;
    if (int.TryParse(this.txtDay.Text, out dia)) {
        ee.Dia = ee.Dia = dia;
    } else {
        //faz alguma coisa aqui porque deu erro na conversão.
    }
    if (ProcessingType != 1) {
        ee.FromProductID = this.hdnSourceID.Value;
        ee.ToProductID = this.hdnDestinationID.Value;
    }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/TryParse2.cs).

Em C# 7 poderá fazer apenas:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var aDay = new List<ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias>();
    var ee = new ProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias();
    if (int.TryParse(this.txtDay.Text, out var dia)) {
        ee.Dia = ee.Dia = dia;
    } else {
        //faz alguma coisa aqui porque deu erro na conversão.
    }
    if (ProcessingType != 1) {
        ee.FromProductID = this.hdnSourceID.Value;
        ee.ToProductID = this.hdnDestinationID.Value;
    }
```

Aproveitei para dar uma organizada no código.

Comment: Este funcionou! Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Usando *c#* basta usar a classe de conversão do system.

```
ee.Dia = System.Convert.ToInt32(this.lblDay.Text);
```

Detalhe: essa conversão é se `Dia`for um int. Se for um `long`, usa o `ToInt64`; se for um short, usa o `ToInt16`.

Mais em https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/1k20k614(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado.. Estou a usar ASP.NET funcionou

Comment: Se o dado for digitado errado isso dá erro.

Comment: Verdade, @bigown. Antes da conversão tem que garantir que `lblDay` contém apenas dígitos

Comment: Vai dar erro? Como assim?

Comment: se o usuário digitar no campo `lblDay` algo como "texto", vai dar erro na conversão. Vale a pena usar o tryparse (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx ) como falado em outra resposta aqui

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente seu Propriedade Dia é do tipo Int, quando você pega o valor this.lblDay.Text; o text por padrão é uma string, Então você não pode atribuir uma string a um tipo Int, teria de converter antes da seguinte forma:

```
ee.Dia =  Convert.ToInt32(this.lblDay.Text);
```

OU

```
ee.Dia =  int.Parse(this.lblDay.Text);
```

Acredito que vá funcionar, Porém é bom validar ser este campo realmente é um valor inteiro, Pode fazer isso com o int.TryParse exemplo [AQUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Se o dado for digitado errado isso dá erro.