# Como devo tratar os erros?

Tags: c#, exceção, validação

> Ler um vetor A com 12 elementos. O vetor deverá aceitar apenas a entrada de valores que sejam divisíveis por 2 ou 3. A entrada de valores no vetor deverá ser validada pelo programa e não pelo usuário. O programa deverá mostrar na tela os números inseridos no vetor.
>
> Observação:  Utilize as rotinas de tratamento de erros/exceções.

E o meu código é exatamente este:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string aux; // variavel auxiliar que ira receber o que o usuario digitar.
        int valor;
        int[] vetor = new int[12];

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            aux = Console.ReadLine();
            valor = int.Parse(aux);

            Console.WriteLine("Digite um valor para o vetor");

            while ((valor%2!=0) && (valor%3!=0))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Apenas valores divisíveis por 2 e 3!");
                aux = Console.ReadLine();
                valor = int.Parse(aux);
            }
            vetor[i] = valor;
        }

        imprimeVetor(vetor);

        Console.ReadKey();
             


      }

    static void imprimeVetor(int[] vetor)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {

  
                Console.Write(vetor[i] + " - ");
                         
            
        }

    }
```

Como trabalhar com esses tratamentos de erro. Eu não usei métodos `try-catch`, deveria? Já verifico o que é importante no meu `while`.

Comment: Não deveria, exceção deve ser uma exceção no código, a única coisa que deve mudar é usar o [`TryParse()`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101). Bom, tem algumas coisas que poderiam ser um pouco melhores, mas nada muito importante.

Comment: Do jeito que diz, eu basicamente faria isto? `while(!TryParse....) {mensagem de ero?}`
Não tinha pensado nisso ainda

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

Evite exceções tanto quanto possível. Só use quando ela fizer muito sentido. Exceção é o recurso mais mal usado da programação hoje em dia. As pessoas não sabem quando lançar, menos ainda quando capturar. Curiosamente elas abusam da exceção, mas praticamente nunca criam uma exceção própria que faria mais sentido. Ou seja, as pessoas usam algo que elas não entendem e por isso só sai coisa errada.

A única mudança que deve fazer é usar o [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) para garantir que o dados entrado é válido. Fora isto eu dei uma organizada, modernizada e simplificada no código.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var vetor = new int[12];
        var i = 0;
        while (i < 12) {
            WriteLine("Digite um valor para o vetor");
            if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var valor)) {
                WriteLine("Você digitou o caractere de forma inválida. Por favor, digite apenas númeris inteiros!");
                continue;
            }
            if (valor % 2 != 0 && valor % 3 != 0) {
                WriteLine("Apenas valores divisíveis por 2 e 3!");
                continue;
            }
            vetor[i++] = valor;
        }
        imprimeVetor(vetor);
    }
    static void imprimeVetor(int[] vetor) {
        foreach (var item in vetor) Write($"{item} - ");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VkhwUn). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iMDore). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/ValidInput.cs).

Esta versão funciona no C# 7, o código no Coding Ground funciona no C# 6, não recomendo usar versões anteriores.

Answer (score 0):

Acabei resolvendo o "problema". Achei que deveria usar uma exception customizada para tratar os numeros divisíveis. No caso, usei catch e try apenas para ter a certeza de que o usuário irá informar apenas números. Segue o trecho código:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Digite um valor para o vetor");
            try
            {
                aux = Console.ReadLine();
                valor = int.Parse(aux);

            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Você digitou o caractere de forma inválida. Por favor, digite apenas númeris inteiros!");
                aux = Console.ReadLine();
                valor = int.Parse(aux);
            }
```

Comment: Você criou um novo problema

Comment: E se o usuário digitar um valor incorreto na segunda vez? Ou seja dentro do block `catch{}`? Como @bigown disse:  "Você criou um novo problema."

Comment: Entendi! A ajuda de vocês me  esclareceu bastante!

Answer (score 0):

O facto de prevenires erros do utilizador, não significa que não possas ter erros de sintaxe por exempo.

Aqui ficava o que eu faria:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string aux; // variavel auxiliar que ira receber o que o usuario digitar.
    int valor;
    int[] vetor = new int[12];
    try{

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            aux = Console.ReadLine();
            valor = int.Parse(aux);

            Console.WriteLine("Digite um valor para o vetor");

            while ((valor%2!=0) && (valor%3!=0))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Apenas valores divisíveis por 2 e 3!");
                aux = Console.ReadLine();
                valor = int.Parse(aux);
            }
            vetor[i] = valor;
        }
        imprimeVetor(vetor);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERRO: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
    }

static void imprimeVetor(int[] vetor)
{
    try{
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
                Console.Write(vetor[i] + " - ");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERRO: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Entendi, mas eu poderia fazer sem o try catch na função imprimi vetor sem problemas, não? Basta eu colocar o código para que o usuário digite o número novamente no primeiro catch, aí eu tenho a certeza de que todos os dados do vetor estão tratados e corretos. Ou eu to viajando?

Comment: Ou eu não percebi o que quises-te dizer, ou estás mesmo viajando...
Uma coisa é tu tratares os valores que vão ser inseridos no array. Outra coisa é prevenção de bloqueios da aplicação por erros ocorridos durante a execução da mesma.
Basicamente as excepções previnem erros não permitindo que a aplicação fique bloqueada.
Quanto ao tratamento dos dados para o vector és mesmo responsabilidade do programador criar condições anti-erro...

Comment: @NunoSantos exceções não são para isto, na verdade não tem porque capturar nenhuma exceção nesse código, exceções devem ser excepcionais, não o normal do código. Exceção não é um mecanismo para tornar o código mais robusto. Na verdade da maneira como a maioria das pessoas usam ele deixa o código mais vulnerável porque as pessoas acreditam que capturando uma exceção não vai ter um erro. A maioria das exceções são erros de programação e o correto não é capturá-la e sim consertar o erro. E entrada de dados se valida, não espera dar erro. Se tentar validar com exceção a situação não é excepcional.

Comment: @bigown, foi precisamente isso que disse. No entanto e segundo é explicito no enunciado "Observação: Utilize as rotinas de tratamento de erros/exceções.". Esse o verdadeiro motivo de ter inserido as excepções.
Na realidade elas são boas para fazer debug de erros antes libertar qualquer aplicação...