# Conversão TimeSpan

Tags: c#, .net, string, timespan

Estou lendo um arquivo delimitado por ponto e vírgula e uma das informações que é a duração da ligação está vindo como "00:97:54".

Ao tentar converter para TimeSpan, obviamente dá erro

> The TimeSpan could not be parsed because at least one of the numeric components is out of range or contain too many digits

Como faço para converter esse horário?

Comment: Não use o campo de respostas para agradecer, apenas aceite a melhor resposta, como fez e vote nas respostas que lhe ajudaram. Se não sabe como veja o [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende de como você tem esse dado, se tiver certeza que o tempo vem sempre certo pode fazer assim:

```
using static System.Console;
using System;

public class Program  {
    public static void Main() {
        var time = "00:97:54".Split(':');
        WriteLine(new TimeSpan(int.Parse(time[0]), int.Parse(time[1]), int.Parse(time[2])));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/X16cZh). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FGzGnr). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/TimeSpanOverflow.cs).

[Veja o `TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) se não puder garantir o formato correto.