# A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, string, conversão-de-tipo

Ao chamar o método abaixo vem a mensagem

> a cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto

```
private void SubmitData()
        {
            try
            {
                string user = usuario.Text;
                string pass = senha.Text;

                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string postData = "username=" + user + "&password=" + pass;
                byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("url do site/auth?username=" + user + "&password=" + pass + "");


                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;

                Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                stream.Close();

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                stream = response.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                int resultado = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
                // MessageBox.Show(resultado.ToString());

                if (resultado == 1)
                {
                    Form1 segundo = new Form1();
                    this.Hide();
                    segundo.ShowDialog();



                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your time expired");

                    usuario.ResetText();
                    senha.ResetText();
                }

                sr.Close();
                stream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo de entrada que ocasiona esse erro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse é um erro comum. As pessoas acham que converter *string*  em outro tipo sempre vai dar certo. Se o dado não é controlado por você, ou seja se vem de fonte externa incerta, como digitação por exemplo, você não pode confiar no que vem, tem que tentar converter e verificar se deu certo ou não. Então precisaria mudar para:

```
var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
int resultado;
MessageBox.Show(int.TryParse(sr.ReadLine(), out resultado) ? resultado : "Deu algum erro no dado recebido");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/String2Int.cs).

Se estiver usando C# 7 pode ser assim:

```
var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
MessageBox.Show(int.TryParse(sr.ReadLine(), out var resultado) ? resultado : "Deu algum erro no dado recebido");
```

Veja mais em [Diferenças entre Parse vs TryParse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).