# Por que a conversão se realiza de forma errada?

Tags: string, vb.net, formatação

Ao realizar a conversão de um numero preciso formatá-lo, e infelizmente não está saindo da forma que preciso.

Preciso formatar um numero de 11 dígitos em CPF, mas ao colocar a formatação, na execução do programa, a formatação fica "zuada". Ao colocar "," ele formata como dinheiro ex: "00,000,000,0-00"  e se eu colocar "." ele nem formata, e coloca o - no fim do texto.

Segue o código:

```
 If Len(numcgc) = 11 Or Len(numcgc) = 14 Then

        Select Case Len(numcgc)
            Case 11
                If Not classe.CalculaCpf(numcgc) Then
                    MsgBox("ATENÇÃO! - N° do CPF inválido - Vefique")
                    TxtCgc.Select()
                    TxtCgc.Clear()
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                If IsNumeric(numcgc) Then TxtCgc.Text = Format(CLng(numcgc), "###,###,###-##")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro, o dado que você está usando é descritivo, ou seja, é um texto e não deve converter para número em hipótese alguma, ele não é um número, apenas coincidentemente o texto só tem dígitos numéricos.

E se fosse para fazer conversão não é assim que se faz em VB.NET, isso é coisa que VB antigo e não deveria mais ser usado. O jeito correto já foi respondido em diversas perguntas aqui (embora todas em C#, é a mesma coisa), [uma delas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213057/101).

Então o correto é:

```
TxtCgc.Text = numcgc.Substring(0, 3) + "." + numcgc.Substring(3, 3) + "." + numcgc.Substring(6, 3) + "-" + numcgc.Substring(9, 2)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/FormatString.vb).

De fato precisa validar mais esse dado, muita coisa pode vir errada.

Comment: Muito obrigada, sua solução funcionou perfeitamente. Não entendi muito bem quanto a referencia do vb antigo e o atual... Mas mesmo assim agradeço profundamente!

Comment: @Jaderson Não use `CLng()`.