# Método que recebe 3 valores inteiros por parâmetro e retorna-os ordenados em ordem crescente como um array

Tags: c#, .net, algoritmo

Não consigo com que o *array* preenchido retornado seja impresso

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int valor, valor2, valor3;

        Maior maior = new Maior();



        Console.WriteLine("Digite um numero");
        valor = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Digite um numero");
        valor2 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Digite um numero");
        valor3 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        int[] maiorvalor = maior.Maior1(valor, valor2, valor3);


        Console.WriteLine(maiorvalor[2]);
        Console.WriteLine(maiorvalor[1]);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

   }
}



class Maior
{
    public int[] Maior1 (int valor, int valor2, int valor3)
    {
        int[] array = new int[3];


        if (valor > valor2 && valor > valor3)
        {
            array[0] = valor;

        }

        if (valor2 > valor && valor2 > valor3)
        {
            array[1] = valor2;

        }

        if (valor3 > valor && valor3 > valor2)
        {
            array[2] = valor3;

        }


        return array;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu método `Maior1` não cobre todas as possibilidade. Melhor saída é usar uma lista ordena-lá e devoler o array:

```
public int[] Maior1 (int valor, int valor2, int valor3)
    {
        List<int> lista = new List<int>(new int[]{valor, valor2, valor3});

        lista.Sort();

        return lista.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para apenas 3 dados, apesar de mais código, o mais performático seria assim:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        foreach (var item in Maior1(2, 3, 1)) WriteLine(item);
        WriteLine();
        foreach (var item in Maior1(1, 2, 3)) WriteLine(item);
        WriteLine();
        foreach (var item in Maior1(3, 2, 1)) WriteLine(item);
        WriteLine();
        foreach (var item in Maior1(1, 3, 2)) WriteLine(item);
        WriteLine();
        foreach (var item in Maior1(2, 1, 3)) WriteLine(item);
        WriteLine();
        foreach (var item in Maior1(3, 1, 2)) WriteLine(item);
    }
    public static int[] Maior1(int v1, int v2, int v3) {
        var array = new int[3];
        if (v1 > v2 && v1 > v3) {
            array[0] = v1;
            if (v2 > v3) {
                array[1] = v2;
                array[2] = v3;
            } else {
                array[1] = v3;
                array[2] = v2;
            }
        } else if (v2 > v1 && v2 > v3) {
            array[0] = v2;
            if (v1 > v3) {
                array[1] = v1;
                array[2] = v3;
            } else {
                array[1] = v3;
                array[2] = v1;
            }
        } else {
            array[0] = v3;
            if (v1 > v2) {
                array[1] = v1;
                array[2] = v2;
            } else {
                array[1] = v2;
                array[2] = v1;
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/81cNjA). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/09LTnb). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Sorting3Ints.cs).

Mas o maior motivo de eu ter respondido é para evitar uma alocação de uma lista sem necessidade alguma.

Além disto [não use o `Parse()` onde usou, o correto é o `TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101). [Veja como seria](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213057/101).