# Somar os dados randômicos

Tags: c#, .net, random

Tenho um código para um rolador de dados. Então a pessoa digitará no campo a quantidade de dados que rolará e após isso o programa rodará a quantidade de dados e somar.

Então fiz um *array* para receber esses dados mas não estou conseguindo somá-los...

```
Random rnd = new Random();

int dado6lado;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int d6 = Convert.ToInt32(qtdD6.Text);
    int[] qtd6 = new int[d6];
    int soma = 0;

    //aqui a função vai pegar a quantidade de dados em qtd6.Lenght, rolar e somar na variavel soma e após isso exibir o valor na ultima linha
    for (int i = 0; i < qtd6.Length; i++ ) {
         //Dado
         dado6lados = rnd.Next(1, 7);

         soma = dado6lados + qtd6[i] ;

         resultadoD6.Text = soma.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pode comentar linha a linha o que o seu `for` deveria fazer? Aliás, monte o teste de mesa que encontrará o erro rapidamente.

Comment: Qual é o problema? Não sei se faz o que quer, mas olhando por cima não vi erro, exceto o fato que se alguém digitar algo errado vai estourar e não ter valor algum no *array*, o que deveria ter ali?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

acho que deveria estar assim:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

int dado6lado;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int d6 = Convert.ToInt32(qtdD6.Text);
    int[] dados = new int[d6];
    int soma = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dados.Length; i++ ) {
        dados[i] = rnd.Next(1, 7);
        soma += dados[i];
    }

    resultadoD6.Text = soma.ToString();
 }
```

em nenhum momento você atribiu valor a `qtd6[i]` que eu renomeei para `dados[i]`

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo!
Estou aprendendo ainda a linguagem e fazia tempo que não práticava a logica.

Comment: Não esquece de marcar como resposta! Por nada

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta é um pouco confusa, mas dada a resposta aceita tem um jeito bem simples de resolver isto. O *array* não tem função alguma nesse algoritmo, então é só matá-lo. Também tem variável demais:

```
int soma = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(qtdD6.Text); i++) {
    soma += rnd.Next(1, 7);
}
resultadoD6.Text = soma.ToString();
```

Isto tem um problema. Se alguém digitar algo inválido para converter para número vai quebrar a aplicação. O [mais correto seria usar um `TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

Não é exatamente a mesma coisa, mas nem o laço precisaria ser criado. Haverá uma certa mudança de probabilidades, mas pode fazer assim:

```
var qtde = Convert.ToInt32(qtdD6.Text)
resultadoD6.Text = (rnd.Next(qtde, qtde * 6 + 1)).ToString();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/SumRandom.cs).

Comment: Hmm, muito obrigado bigown. 
Irei estudar essa forma, parece ser muito mais simples mesmo

Como falei estou aprendendo agora, por isso essa foi a forma que encontrei pra resolver a aplicação.