# Variável não designada

Tags: c#, .net, variáveis, loop, do-while

Dá-me erro dizendo que a variável `remainder` não foi designada. Há várias partes do código que eu não percebo e gostaria de explicação.

> 3. Write a program that continually reads in integer values until a four digit number in the range 111 to 9999 is entered. Display the number vertically i.e. each digit on a separate line.
>
> Example:
> Input: 1234
> Output:
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int number, remainder;
        string s = "";

        //Reading a 4-digit number between 1111 and 9999
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1111 and 9999: ");
            number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        } while (number < 1111 || number > 9999);/*Por que tenho que pôr esta condição*/

        //Breaking number and formatting it vertically in a string

        while (number > 0)
            remainder = number % 10;
            s = remainder + "\n" + s;
            number = number / 10;
```

// Não percebi nada das 4 linhas acima, o que fazem?

```
        //Displaying number vertically
        Console.WriteLine(s); // porquê visualizar a variável s?
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Este código está muito confuso e falta uma parte. Em que linha dá o erro? O resto parece ser só uma questão de interpretaação de texto.

Comment: É obrigatório o uso desse `while (number > 0)`? Seria melhor usar o `foreach`.

Comment: @Francisco como usar um `foreach` se nem uma coleção existe?

Comment: Se eu entendi a pergunta da maneira certa, converte o `number` para string e faz `foreach (char in string)`. Funcionaria @bigown?

Comment: É possível, mas me parece não ser o que  ele deseja, ele quer fazer matematicamente.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

O código está bem confuso, não consegui reproduzir o problema do título, acho até estranho. Na verdade essa variável nem precisa existir.

Vou deixar pra lá os possíveis erros que podem ocorrer em circunstâncias fora do que se espera, comentei de forma simples. Se quiser veja sobre o [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

procure declarar as variáveis mais próximo de onde vai usar. Isto dá mais legibilidade. Também use nomes que identifique o que é a variável.

A condição no primeiro laço está fazendo o que o exercício pede, fica pedindo um novo número até que se digite um número na faixa que é permitida. Se o número está fora dela, repete o pedido.

Mandou imprimir a variável de texto, que chamava `s` no original porque o exercício manda imprimir, tem que mostrar na tela.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        int number;
        do {
            WriteLine("Enter a number between 1111 and 9999: ");
            number = int.Parse(ReadLine()); //isto dá erro se digitar algo errado, deveria usar TryParse()
        } while (number < 1111 || number > 9999);
        var texto = "";
        while (number > 0) {
            texto = number % 10 + "\n" + texto; //o uso de \n pode não ser o ideal sempre
            number /= 10;
        }
        WriteLine(texto);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yrEkAj). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hyBlfO). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/PrintVertical.cs).